# Elegant operations on matrix rows and columns

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation, faq

### Question

The Mathematica tutorial has a section 'Basic Matrix Operations', describing operations like transpose, inverse and determinant. These operations all work on entire matrices. I am missing a section on basic operations on matrix rows / columns.

For example:

2. Extracting a row from a matrix
3. Inserting a row into a matrix
4. Adding two rows within a matrix together
5. Swapping two rows
6. Multiplying a row with a number

And similar for columns.

What is the most elegant way to implementation of these operations? Speed is not important for me, but simplicity is.

### Summary

Here I summarize my personal taste. I will update it whenever someone suggests a way I like more.

```
m = Range@12 ~Partition~ 3;
m // MatrixForm
```

$\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 2 & 3 \\
 4 & 5 & 6 \\
 7 & 8 & 9 \\
 10 & 11 & 12
\end{pmatrix}$

Insert a column at position 2:

```
v = Range[21, 24];
Insert[m // Transpose, v, 2] // Transpose // MatrixForm
```

$\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 21 & 2 & 3 \\
 4 & 22 & 5 & 6 \\
 7 & 23 & 8 & 9 \\
 10 & 24& 11 & 12
\end{pmatrix}$

#### Extract row / column

Extract row 2:

```
m[[2]]
```

$(4,5,6)$

Extract column 2

```
m[[All, 2]] // MatrixForm
```

$\begin{pmatrix}2\\5\\8\\11\end{pmatrix}$

#### Insert a row / column

Insert a row at position 2:

```
v = Range[13, 15];
Insert[m, v, 2] // MatrixForm
```

$\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 2 & 3 \\
 13 & 14 & 15 \\
 4 & 5 & 6 \\
 7 & 8 & 9 \\
 10 & 11 & 12
\end{pmatrix}$

#### Adding two rows / columns

column 3 = column 3 + column 1:

```
m2 = m;  
m2[[All, 3]] += m2[[All, 1]];
m2 // MatrixForm
```

$\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 2 & 4 \\
 4 & 5 & 10 \\
 7 & 8 & 16 \\
 10 & 11 & 22
\end{pmatrix}$

row 2 = row 2 + row 3:

```
m2 = m;
m2[[2]] += m2[[3]];
m2 // MatrixForm
```

$\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 2 & 3 \\
 11 & 13 & 15 \\
 7 & 8 & 9 \\
 10 & 11 & 12
\end{pmatrix}$

#### Swapping rows / columns

Swap row 1 and row 3:

```
m2 = m;
m2[[{1, 3}]] = m2[[{3, 1}]];
m2 // MatrixForm
```

$\begin{pmatrix}
 7 & 8 & 9 \\
 4 & 5 & 6 \\
 1 & 2 & 3 \\
 10 & 11 & 12
\end{pmatrix}$

Swap column 1 and 3:

```
m2[[All, {1, 3}]] = m2[[All, {3, 1}]];
m2 // MatrixForm
```

$\begin{pmatrix}
 3 & 2 & 1 \\
 6 & 5 & 4 \\
 9 & 8 & 7 \\
 12 & 11 & 10
\end{pmatrix}$

#### Multiplying rows / columns

Multiply row 2 with 2:

```
m*{1, 2, 1, 1} // MatrixForm
```

$\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 2 & 3 \\
 8 & 10 & 12 \\
 7 & 8 & 9 \\
 10 & 11 & 12
\end{pmatrix}$

Multiply column 1 with 5:

```
 ((m // Transpose)*{5, 1, 1}) // Transpose // MatrixForm
```

$\begin{pmatrix}
 5 & 2 & 3 \\
 20 & 5 & 6 \\
 35 & 8 & 9 \\
 50 & 11 & 12
\end{pmatrix}$

### References

- [What is the most efficient way to add rows and columns to a matrix?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/189/)
- Thanks to nikie for suggesting 
  [Matrix and Tensor Operations tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/LinearAlgebraMatrixAndTensorOperations.html)
- Chris Degnen pointed out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537401/how-to-insert-a-column-into-a-matrix-the-correct-mathematica-way

Comment: you don`t need `All` to get a row. `m[[2]]` and `m[[2,All]]` both give the second row of `m`.

Comment: What about a partial column, say column one and first three rows, say using your example to get 1, 4, 7? I tried mat[[{1, 3}, 1]] // MatrixForm -> {1},{7}, but I want {1},{4},{7}?

Comment: ok got it, need to Transpose, Flatten, Take as in:  Take[Flatten[Transpose[mat]], {1, 3}] -> {1,4,7}, unless there are betters way to do so?

Comment: How about deleting a row or column?

Comment: @Hirek, you'll want to look up `Drop[]` and `Delete[]`.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I like to use `Part` even when I don't want to modify the original matrix.  This of course requires making a copy but it keeps syntax more consistent.

#### adding column one to column three:

```
m = Range@12 ~Partition~ 3;
m // MatrixForm
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 2 & 3 \\
 4 & 5 & 6 \\
 7 & 8 & 9 \\
 10 & 11 & 12
\end{array}
\right)$

```
m2 = m;

m2[[All, 3]] += m2[[All, 1]];

m2 // MatrixForm
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 2 & 4 \\
 4 & 5 & 10 \\
 7 & 8 & 16 \\
 10 & 11 & 22
\end{array}
\right)$

With an external vector:

```
v = {-1, -2, -3, -4};

m2 = m;

m2[[All, 3]] += v;

m2 // MatrixForm
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 2 & 2 \\
 4 & 5 & 4 \\
 7 & 8 & 6 \\
 10 & 11 & 8
\end{array}
\right)$

#### swapping rows and columns:

```
m2 = m;

m2[[{1, 3}]] = m2[[{3, 1}]];

m2 // MatrixForm
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 7 & 8 & 9 \\
 4 & 5 & 6 \\
 1 & 2 & 3 \\
 10 & 11 & 12
\end{array}
\right)$

```
m2 = m;

m2[[All, {1, 3}]] = m2[[All, {3, 1}]];

m2 // MatrixForm
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 3 & 2 & 1 \\
 6 & 5 & 4 \\
 9 & 8 & 7 \\
 12 & 11 & 10
\end{array}
\right)$

---

#### Simultaneous row-and-column operations

Part is capable of working with rows and columns simultaneously<sup>[(1)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20231/121)</sup>.

We can operate on (or replace) a contiguous sub-array:

```
m2 = m;

m2[[3 ;;, 2 ;;]] /= 5;

m2 // MatrixForm
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 2 & 3 \\
 4 & 5 & 6 \\
 7 & \frac{8}{5} & \frac{9}{5} \\
 10 & \frac{11}{5} & \frac{12}{5} \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Or a disjoint specification:

```
m2 = m;

m2[[{1, 2, 4}, {1, 3}]] = 0;

m2 // MatrixForm
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 2 & 0 \\
 0 & 5 & 0 \\
 7 & 8 & 9 \\
 0 & 11 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Or construct a new array from constituent parts in arbitrary order:

```
mx = BoxMatrix[2] - 1;

mx[[{1, 2, 5, 4}, {4, 5, 1}]] = m;

mx // MatrixForm
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 3 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
 6 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 5 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 12 & 0 & 0 & 10 & 11 \\
 9 & 0 & 0 & 7 & 8 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Comment: +1.  Agreed: part is just so flexible and convenient it's often the nicest way to go about these.

Comment: Just ask: Why won't the code `m2[[All, {1, 3}]] = m2[[All, {3, 1}]];` just give column 1 and 3 indentical? First you assign column 3 to column 1, then you assign column 1 to column 3, which has already become the original column 3...

Comment: @buzhidao I don't know if I can explain this clearly for you since it seems I failed the first time.  There is only a single assignment in that expression, and only a single reversal of columns.   It might be translated to "let columns 1 and 3 be set to columns 3 and 1".  A simpler example without columns is `a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};` then `a[[{1, 3}]] = a[[{3, 1}]];` after which `a` is `{3, 2, 1, 4, 5}`.

Comment: @buzhidao Help on `WhenEvent` discusses something alike: sequential actions modify variables in turn, e.g. `{x[t] -> y[t], y[t] -> x[t]}`, while simultaneous actions swap, e.g. `{x[t], y[t]} -> {y[t], x[t]}`. I think this is idiomatic to the system.

Answer (score 38):

#### Interchanging rows

This'll swap rows 1 and 3.

```
Permute[mat, Cycles[{{1, 3}}]]
```

To swap columns, you can convert the permutation to a permutation list,

```
permList = PermutationList[Cycles[{{1, 3}}], Last@Dimensions[mat]]
```

then use

```
mat[[All, permList]]
```

#### Multiplying rows

This'll multiply the 3rd row by 5:

```
MapAt[5 # &, mat, 3]
```

This'll change the matrix permanently:

```
mat[[3]] *= 5
```

Comment: I believe one would need to take care to keep the length of the permutation list the same. As `PermutationList[Cycles[{{m,n}}]]` will range from `1` to `Max[{m,n}]`. And so `mat[[All, permList]]` would perhaps give a smaller matrix than intended.

Comment: @Kvothe Thanks, updated.

Answer (score 28):

For small matrices, using simple indexing might be more readable:

**Interchanging rows**:

```
m[[{1, 3, 2}]]
```

**Multiplying rows**:

```
m * {1,2,1}
```

**Adding rows**

```
m + {0,v,0}
```

For large matrices, you could use `SparseArray` to generate the second matrix (less readable, but works for any matrix size and might be faster, too):

```
m * SparseArray[2 -> 2, Length[m], 1]
m + SparseArray[2 -> v, Length[m], 0]
```

**Insert a row into a matrix**

```
Insert[m, v, 2]
```

You might want to look at the [Matrix and Tensor Operations tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/LinearAlgebraMatrixAndTensorOperations.html), too

Comment: For multiplying and adding rows---I agree it's likely the most efficient way.   Can you show your preferred way to generate those vectors (`{1,2,1}` and `{0,v,0}`) if the matrix is large?  I miss a way equivalent to `mat[[2]] *= 2` which returns a copy instead of modifying the matrix.

Comment: @Szabolcs: Isn't `m * {1,2,1}` the functional equivalent to `mat[[2]] *= 2`?

Comment: If it's a 10 by 10 matrix, and you want the 7th elements, you have to write `{1,1,1,1,1,1,3,1,1,1}` and make sure that you inserted `3` in the correct position.  This is tedious and error prone.  This is why I asked how you prefer to generate that vector.

Answer (score 26):

These are ancient routines I have been using a long time ago. As a matter of fact, it's been so long that I do not even remember if I wrote them or simply shamelessly took them from some other source. Back at the time the only sources I had at my disposal where The Mathematical Journal (prior to 1998 or 1999), Bahder's wonderful book (which is the most likely source, at least of inspiration, given the style), Mathematica By Example (first edition) by Abell and Braselton and... Matlab for Engineers (LOL, I'm not kidding) by Biran and Breiner.
The reason I am not sure to be the author myself is because these procedures appear too smart for me to have conceived them :-). If someone can trace the original source, I will give it due credit.

Main procedures:

> ```
> row[A_,n_]:=A[[n]]
> col[A_,n_]:=#[[n]]& /@ A
> Col[A_,n_]:={#[[n]]}& /@ A
> ```

`col` returns the column in the form `{x1,x2,...}` 
`Col` returns it as `{{x1},{x2},...}` ("vertical" vector)

Smart applying:

> ```
> row /: (row[A_,n_]=r_):=(A[[n]]=r)
> col /: (col[A_,n_]=c_):=(A[[ Range[Dimensions[A][[1]]],{n} ]]=(List /@ c)) 
> Col /: (Col[A_,n_]=c_):=(A[[ Range[Dimensions[A][[1]]],{n} ]]=c) 
> row /: (row[A_,n_]:=r_):=(A[[n]]:=r)
> col /: (col[A_,n_]:=c_):=(A[[ Range[Dimensions[A][[1]]],{n} ]]:=(List /@ c))
> Col /: (Col[A_,n_]:=c_):=(A[[ Range[Dimensions[A][[1]]],{n} ]]:=c)
> ```

Now... here is how to use them. Let's start with a matrix

```
A={
{1,2,3}, 
{4,5,6}, 
{7,8,9}
};
```

Suppose you want to replace the second column of `A` with 100 times its value. All you need to do is to tell Mathematica what is the new value of the column, for example 100 times its current value:

```
col[A,2]=100*col[A,2]
```

> {200,500,800}

The side effect of `col` is to show the new value of the column, but its primary and intended effect is to change the original matrix `A` accordingly:

```
A
```

> {
>       {1,200,3}, 
>       {4,500,6}, 
>       {7,800,9}
>       }

`row` can be used in the same way. Suppose we want to substitute the first row with a linear combination of all three rows of `A`

```
row[A, 1] = row[A, 1] + 2 row[A, 2] - row[A, 3]
```

> {2, 400, 6}

The original matrix `A` is changed accordingly.

```
A
```

> {
>       {2,400,6}, 
>       {4,500,6}, 
>       {7,800,9}
>       }

Basically these procedures allow one to do all the operations he or she wishes on rows and columns of a matrix. Extracting, defining, substituting with linear combinations or whatever comes to one's mind.
As mentioned before, if one desires to extract a column in the form `{{a},{b},{c}}`, he should use `Col` instead of `col`.

Pretty `col`, uh?

EDIT: I just found a more elaborate notebook with "the making of" written by me where I refer to "Thomas Bahder's MMA for Scientists and Engineers", "Bruce Ikenaga'a Matrix Operations" and "me" as sources. So perhaps I was the author of the wrappers... 
Later this week I will add the procedures for joining, inserting, appending and swapping rows and columns and I will try to ascertain who wrote what.

Answer (score 20):

Not as simple as the other solutions, but the linear-algebraic treatment might be convenient in some applications:

```
m = Partition[Range[12], 3];
```

Add column 2 and column 3, and store result in column 3:

```
m.SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> 1, {1, 3} -> 1}, ConstantArray[Last[Dimensions[m]], 2]]
```

Add row 2 and row 3, and store result in row 2:

```
SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> 1, {2, 3} -> 1}, ConstantArray[First[Dimensions[m]], 2]].m
```

Multiply second row by 2:

```
ReplacePart[IdentityMatrix[First[Dimensions[m]]], {2, 2} -> 2].m
```

Multiply first column by 5:

```
m.ReplacePart[IdentityMatrix[Last[Dimensions[m]]], {1, 1} -> 5]
```

Answer (score 19):

Inserting columns (recycling answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537401/how-to-insert-a-column-into-a-matrix-the-correct-mathematica-way)).

```
m = Range@12~Partition~3;
m // MatrixForm
v = Range[21, 24];

MapThread[Insert, {m, v, Table[2, {Length[v]}]}] // MatrixForm

Table[Insert[m[[i]], v[[i]], 2], {i, Length[v]}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: How to put this numbers in index, for example A1,A2,A3,A4..A12? m = Range@12 ~Partition~ 3; m // MatrixForm

Comment: Do you mean like this? `Clear[A]; Print[
 MatrixForm[m = Outer[A, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3}]]]; v = 
 Range[21, 24]; 
MapThread[Insert, {m, v, Table[2, {Length[v]}]}] // MatrixForm`

Comment: Or perhaps like this: `Print[MatrixForm[m = Range@12~Partition~3]]; Clear[A]; Print[
 v = Array[A, 4]]; 
MapThread[Insert, {m, v, Table[2, {Length[v]}]}] // MatrixForm`

Comment: Do we have to build `Table[2, {Length[v]}]`? IMO `MapThread[Insert[#1, #2, 2] &, {m, v}]` is cleaner.

Comment: It's just an alternative form.  I prefer `MapThread` too, although now I have seen another method from Kuba: [Efficient method for Inserting arrays into arrays](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/44466/363).

Answer (score 19):

There are some internal, undocumented functions for row and columns operations:

```
(* in-place(!) transformation of the matrix *)
Statistics`Library`MatrixRowTranslate[matrix, vector]
Statistics`Library`MatrixRowTimes[matrix, vector]
Statistics`Library`MatrixRowAffineTransform[matrix, vector, vector] (* mat, times, xlate *)
Statistics`Library`MatrixRowAffineTransform[matrix, scalar, vector]
(* returns vector *)
Statistics`Library`MatrixColumnSum[matrix]
Statistics`Library`MatrixRowSum[matrix]
```

The first four have the inelegance, admittedly, of modifying the argument `matrix` in place, and so are not well-suited for functional programming.  On the other hand, all six are efficient, especially on numeric arrays, packed or unpacked.  Perhaps the OP's original scope does not comprise all these operations, although it is somewhat open-ended; however, I thought that since they are strongly related, it would be better to have them all here than in a separate Q&A.

Note that a `vector` argument can easily be a row or column of `matrix`, but the whole matrix will be transformed in those cases.

#### Examples

```
mm = {
   {a, b, c},
   {d, e, f},
   {g, h, i},
   {j, k, l}
  };
```

**Add a vector to each row:**

```
Module[{res = mm},
  Statistics`Library`MatrixRowTranslate[res, {u, v, w}];
  res] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Multiply each row by a vector:**
It's elementwise scalar multiplication, the same as `row * vector`, for each row in the matrix.

```
Module[{res = mm},
  Statistics`Library`MatrixRowTimes[res, {x, y, z}];
  res] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Multiply each column by a vector:**
`Times` already does what the missing `MatrixColumnTimes[]` would do:

```
mm*{w, x, y, z} // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Affine transformation of the rows:**
The `MatrixRowAffineTransform` can be viewed as multiplying the row by `{x, y, z}]` and adding the second vector `{u, v, w}`, or as operating on the columns threading the components of the vectors.

```
Module[{res = mm},
  Statistics`Library`MatrixRowAffineTransform[res, {x, y, z}, {u, v, w}];
  res] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`MatrixRowAffineTransform` allows the scaling argument to be a scalar.

```
Module[{res = mm},
  Statistics`Library`MatrixRowAffineTransform[res, x, {u, v, w}];
  res] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Affine transformation of the columns:**
Again, `Times` and `Plus` supply the missing `MatrixColumnAffineTransform[]`:

```
mm * {w, x, y, z} + {p, q, r, s} // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Summing rows or columns:**

```
Statistics`Library`MatrixColumnSum[mm]
(*  {a + d + g + j, b + e + h + k, c + f + i + l}  *)

Statistics`Library`MatrixRowSum[mm]
(*  {a + b + c, d + e + f, g + h + i, j + k + l}  *)
```

Timings of the sums can be found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/149506/4999).  Since the OP explicitly said speed was not an issue, I didn't want to clutter this post with timings.  Nonetheless, these are, as I mentioned, fast on numeric arrays.

Comment: (+1) In which version these functions were introduced? They aren't present in version 8.0.4. (Also you forgot to add the link in the last paragraph.)

Comment: I think in V10.  I don't have access to all past versions, but they're in V10.4.1.

Answer (score 16):

This "replace" methods work **only if there are no repeated rows** (or columns if you will generalize) - see comments. For more general approach see @Szabolcs solution.

```
m = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
m // MatrixForm
```

[image]

**Adding rows**

```
m /. m[[2]] -> m[[2]] + m[[3]] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

**Interchanging rows**

```
m /. {m[[2]] -> m[[3]], m[[3]] -> m[[2]]} // MatrixForm
```

[image]

**Multiplying row**

```
m /. {m[[2]] -> 3 m[[2]]} // MatrixForm
```

[image]

**Subtracting columns**

```
Transpose@m /. {m[[All, 2]] -> m[[All, 2]] - m[[All, 1]]} 
//Transpose // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: With adding rows, I mean adding the numbers of one row to an existing row

Comment: What if the matrix has two rows that are the same?  The `Replace` approach will affect both.

Comment: @sjdh I see - added an example.

Comment: These `ReplaceAll` methods are dangerous because a matrix may contain repeated rows or columns.

Comment: @Szabolcs (and Mr.Wizard and nikie ;-) ) Very true - I'll add a comment at the top.

Comment: +1 nice idea. But what happens if the matrix contains two rows `{4 5 6}`?

Comment: @Vitaliy the key insight I was missing is that you can address row i with m[[i]]. This is clear, thanks. Can you give an example for columns? Adding two columns, for example?

Comment: @sjdh I just did. But please be aware of the warning I posted at the beginning in bold - and read all comments here.

Comment: What If I want to use your method to multiply a column? I tried this m /. {m[[All, 3]] -> 3 m[[All, 3]]} // MatrixForm  in order to multiply 3rd column by 3 but doen't work. Am I missing something in your logic?

Answer (score 12):

As matrix multiplication is highly optimized (see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/147531/106)), [Dot](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot.html) and [Inner](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inner.html) (the general form of Dot) are often very efficient methods for column manipulation.

All of the following examples somewhere make use of [Dot](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot.html) or [Inner](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inner.html)

*Matrix and vector definition*

```
(m = Array[Subscript[a, ##] &, {2, 3}]) // MatrixForm
 v = Table[Subscript[x, i], {i, 1, 3}]
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & a_{1,3} \\
 a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & a_{2,3} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

$$\left\{x_1,x_2,x_3\right\}$$

**Multiply a Matrix by a Vector**

(See this SE question:  [Multiplying columns with factor](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/96286/106))

Often it is not the dot product that is of interest,

```
m.v // MatrixForm
```

$$\left\{x_1 a_{1,1}+x_2 a_{1,2}+x_3 a_{1,3},x_1 a_{2,1}+x_2 a_{2,2}+x_3 a_{2,3}\right\}$$

but

```
(m.DiagonalMatrix[v])//MatrixForm
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 x_1 a_{1,1} & x_2 a_{1,2} & x_3 a_{1,3} \\
 x_1 a_{2,1} & x_2 a_{2,2} & x_3 a_{2,3} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

[Inner](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inner.html)  gives the same result:

```
Inner[Times, m, DiagonalMatrix[v]]
```

In the general form,  `Inner[f,list1,list2,g]` , '*f* plays the role of multiplication and *g* of addition' ([Inner](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inner.html)), and the result may also be obtained with:

```
Inner[Times, m, v, List]
```

That is:

```
m.DiagonalMatrix[v] == Inner[Times, m, DiagonalMatrix[v]] == Inner[Times, m, v, List]
```

**Multiply a Column by a Factor**

(See [Change entire column of matrix using its own elements for calculations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/121683/change-entire-column-of-matrix-using-its-own-elements-for-calculations))

*Multiply column-4 by 10*

```
m.DiagonalMatrix[{1, 1, 10}] // MatrixForm
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & 10 a_{1,3} \\
 a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & 10 a_{2,3} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

The diagonal matrix may be generated more efficiently with [SparseArray](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray.html). This gives the same result:

```
m.SparseArray[{{3, 3} -> 10, Band[{1, 1}] ->1}, Dimensions[m][[2]]]
```

Using [Inner](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inner.html):

```
 Inner[Times, m, SparseArray[{{3, 3} -> 10, Band[{1, 1}] -> 1}, Dimensions[m][[2]]]]
```

*or*:

```
 Inner[Times, m, {1, 1, 10}, List]
```

**Replace Column Entries with Zero**

(see [Replacing columns of a matrix with zeros](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/61219/106))

```
m.DiagonalMatrix[{1, 0, 0}] // MatrixForm
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 a_{1,1} & 0 & 0 \\
 a_{2,1} & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Alternatively:

```
Inner[Times, m, {1, 0, 0}, List] // MatrixForm
```

**Add Column-3 to Column-1**

```
m.SparseArray[{{3, 1} -> 1, Band[{1, 1}] -> 1}, Dimensions[m][[2]]] // MatrixForm
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 a_{1,1}+a_{1,3} & a_{1,2} & a_{1,3} \\
 a_{2,1}+a_{2,3} & a_{2,2} & a_{2,3} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

For clarity:

```
SparseArray[{{3, 1} -> 1, Band[{1, 1}] -> 1}, Dimensions[m][[2]]] // MatrixForm
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Subtract Column-3 from Column-2**

```
m // #.SparseArray[{{3, 2} -> -1, Band[{1, 1}] -> 1}, Dimensions[#][[2]]] & // MatrixForm
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 a_{1,1} & a_{1,2}-a_{1,3} & a_{1,3} \\
 a_{2,1} & a_{2,2}-a_{2,3} & a_{2,3} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Subtract Column-1 from all other Columns**

See [the answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/147531/106) by [Carl Woll](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/45431/carl-woll) to [Subtracting elements in a nested list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/147529/106)

```
m // #.(SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> 1, {1, _} -> -1}, Dimensions[#][[2]]]) & // MatrixForm
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 a_{1,1} & a_{1,2}-a_{1,1} & a_{1,3}-a_{1,1} \\
 a_{2,1} & a_{2,2}-a_{2,1} & a_{2,3}-a_{2,1} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 4):

```
m = {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {g, h, i}, {j, k, l}};
```

**1. Threaded** (since V 13.1)

Add a vector to each row:

```
m + Threaded[{u, v, w}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Multiply each row by a vector:

```
m * Threaded[{u, v, w}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

**2. Query**

Apply a function to all elements of a column:

```
Query[All, {2 -> x}] @ m // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Apply functions to elements of several columns:

```
Query[All, {2 -> x, 3 -> y}] @ m // MatrixForm
```

[image]

**3. ApplyTo** (since V 12.2)

```
m =
 {{Pi/2, (3 Pi)/4, Pi, (5 Pi)/4},
  {(3 Pi)/4, Pi, (5 Pi)/4, (3 Pi)/2},
  {Pi, (5 Pi)/4, (3 Pi)/2, (7 Pi)/4},
  {(5 Pi)/4, (3 Pi)/2, (7 Pi)/4, 2 Pi}};
```

Apply `Sin` to  2nd matrix column and reset `m` to the result (from the documentation):

```
m[[All, 2]] //= Sin;

m // MatrixForm
```

[image]

**4. ArrayReduce** (since V 12.2)

Apply a function to all columns:

```
m = {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {g, h, i}, {j, k, l}};

ArrayReduce[f, m, 1]
```

{f[{a, d, g, j}], f[{b, e, h, k}], f[{c, f, i, l}]}

**5. CreateDataStructure** (since V 12.1)

There are countless possibilities, for example:

```
ds = CreateDataStructure["LinkedList"];

Scan[ds["Append", #] &, m]
```

Swap rows 2 and 3

```
ds["SwapPart", 2, 3];
```

{{a, b, c}, {g, h, i}, {d, e, f}, {j, k, l}}

**6. Partition**

```
Partition[m, {2, 2}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: `CreateDataStructure`  looks very useful. Thanks for posting

Comment: Exploring it is much fun - and once you have set up a structure, many operations are very fast

Answer (score 4):

#### Applying functions to deeply nested matrices with AggregationLayer

`AggregationLayer` was introduced with `V 11.1` and has received several updates since.

According to the `Documentation` it "*aggregates an array of arbitrary rank into a vector*", using any of the following functions:

Times, Total, Min, Max, Mean, Median, Variance, StandardDeviation, MeanDeviation and InterquartileRange.

```
m =
  {{{{10, 5, 10, 6}, {9, 8, 10, 5}, {9, 9, 2, 8}},
     {{10, 3, 1, 9}, {2, 7, 3, 4}, {7, 5, 6, 6}}}};

m // MatrixForm
```

[image]

#### All levels

`AggregationLayer[Max, {1, 2, 3, 4}][m]`

10.

#### Columns

```
AggregationLayer[Max, {1, 3}][m]
```

{{10., 9., 10., 8.}, {10., 7., 6., 9.}}

#### Rows

```
AggregationLayer[Max, {1, 4}][m]
```

{{10., 10., 9.}, {10., 7., 7.}}

#### Aggregated Columns

```
AggregationLayer[Max, {1, 2, 3}][m]
```

{10., 9., 10., 9.}

#### Aggregated Rows

```
AggregationLayer[Max, {1, 2, 4}][m]
```

{10., 10., 9.}

#### Submatrices

```
AggregationLayer[Min, {1, 3, 4}][m]
```

{2., 1.}

#### Submatrices per element

```
AggregationLayer[Min, {1, 2}][m]
```

{{10., 3., 1., 6.}, {2., 7., 3., 4.}, {7., 5., 2., 6.}}

Comment: It would be useful for users if you could add one or two lines of explanation for each command. It is difficult to understand the type of operations performed.

Answer (score 3):

**Mapping across rows AND columns**

```
list = Partition[Range[12], 3];

list // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
Map[Accumulate, list, {0, 1}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
Map[MovingAverage[#, 2] &, list, {0, 1}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Swapping rows and columns**

```
m =
  {{"a", "b", "c"},
   {"d", "e", "f"},
   {"g", "h", "i"},
   {"j", "k", "l"}};
```

**1. Rows**

Swap rows 1 and 2

```
SubsetMap[RotateRight, m, {1, 2}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

**2. Columns**

To swap columns we can use `Query`

```
Query[All, SubsetMap[RotateRight, #, {2, 3}] &] @ m // MatrixForm
```

or `ArrayReduce` (new in 12.2)

```
ArrayReduce[SubsetMap[RotateRight, #, {2, 3}] &, m, 2]
```

Both give

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## Apply functions with Query

### 1. Apply functions to  row or column elements

#### 1.1 Rows

```
m =
  {{"a", "b", "c"},
   {"d", "e", "f"},
   {"g", "h", "i"},
   {"j", "k", "l"}};
```

Apply one function to one row

```
Query[{2 -> Map[Boole @* LetterQ]}] @ m // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Apply two functions to two rows

```
Query[{2 -> Map[LetterQ], -1 -> Map[DigitQ]}] @ m // MatrixForm
```

[image]

#### 1.2 Columns

Apply two functions to two columns

```
Query[All, {1 -> LetterQ, 3 -> DigitQ}] @ m // MatrixForm
```

[image]

### 2. Apply functions to entire rows or columns

#### 2.1 Rows

Apply one function to one row

```
Query[{1 -> Reverse}] @ m // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Apply two functions to two rows

```
Query[{1 -> Reverse, 3 -> RotateRight}] @ m // MatrixForm
```

[image]

#### 2.2 Columns

Apply one function to one column

```
Query[{1 -> Reverse}][m\[Transpose]]\[Transpose] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Apply two functions to two columns

```
Query[{1 -> Reverse, 3 -> RotateRight}][m\[Transpose]]\[Transpose] // MatrixForm
```

[image]