# Part extraction vs functions like First, Last?

Tags: list-manipulation, coding-style, function-comparison

There are many ways to extract different parts of lists in Mathematica. For example, the first part of a list `v` can be accessed either as `v[[1]]` or `First[v]` or `Take[v,1]`. Likewise the last element can be accessed as `v[[-1]]`, `Last[v]`  or `Take[v,-1]`. Similarly `v[[2;;]]` is equivalent to `Rest[v]` and to `Drop[v,1]`, and `v[[;;-2]]` is equivalent to `Most[v]` and `Drop[v,-1]`.

The more specialized functions `First`, `Last`, `Rest` and `Most` are marginally more efficient. On the other hand, it makes sense to use the more general `Part` (`[[ ]]`) or `Take`/`Drop` if it is part of a calculation that also requires parts to be accessed that do not have a specialist function.

Beyond these considerations, are there any reasons to prefer `Part` over `Take`/`Drop` or the more specialized functions, other than personal preferences over coding style?

Answer (score 21):

You cannot make assignments to `First`, `Last`, `Rest`, or `Most` the way you can with `Part`.  Therefore, there is greater consistency in using `Part` for all operations.  See [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3077/121) for an example of and argument for this consistency.

Also, you must change functions if you need to update your code to index a different element or change an element to a `Span`.  By using `Part` from the beginning you have the greatest flexibility without changing functions.  This can make comparing different code revisions easier.  It can also make a user defined function more flexible, e.g.: `f[x_, part__ : 1] := foo @ x[[part]]`

Less importantly `x[[1]]` is more terse than `First@x`, especially in the FrontEnd using `〚 〛`, and I am a fan of terse coding.

Comment: +1, for discussing the maintenance cost.

Comment: In a sea of brackets, x[[1]] is less comprehensible than First@x and as a result probably less maintainable, albeit one character longer :) But whilst developing x[[1]] is easier to modify. Conclusion, develop with Part and deploy with First.

Comment: Am the only one with Second, Third, Fourth, Fifth and Sixth defined too? :)

Comment: @image_doctor I find that using `\[LeftDoubleBracket]` and `\[RightDoubleBracket]` greatly helps readability compared to `[[` and `]]` in the frontend

Comment: @acl thanks,  that's definitely more compact and visually distinctive

Comment: @image_doctor as acl said, always use the specialized characters.  I also take the controversial measure of avoiding many brackets by heavily using prefix (`func @ arg`) and infix (`a ~func~ b`).

Comment: @acl useful, but too many characters for my taste.

Comment: @rcollyer you're going to confuse the newbies. :-P  (newbies:  `\[LeftDoubleBracket]` formats to `〚` in the FrontEnd; it can be entered with `Esc`[[`Esc`.)

Comment: `First`/`Last` are so elitist. Why not `FirstAmongEquals` and `LastButNotLeast`?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard even with `Esc` - `[[` - `Esc` it still requires four key strokes to two. Definitely inefficient. :)

Comment: @rcollyer Oh.  I thought you were joking about having to type out/see the `FullForm` of those characters.

Comment: @rcollyer I have them assigned to ctrl-[ and ctrl-] (and  the caps lock key is ctrl on my keyboards)

Comment: @acl In addition to `Ctrl`+`[`/`]` I use Ctrl+Alt+Shift+] for inserting `〚 〛` and placing the cursor in the middle.  Do you?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard there's also a Rain Man joke in there.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard No, but I should try. I just never set it up.

Comment: @acl actually the key combination is Ctrl+Alt+] but I've been mashing shift needlessly, though it's not really more difficult.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/7327476/618728

Comment: @Mr.Wizard wrote: "... and I am a fan of terse coding... " we hadn't noticed. ;-)

Comment: @ndroock1 Nuts! I'll redouble my efforts.

Answer (score 8):

Putting aside any minor performance differences, the specialized functions look cleaner and clear in intent in cases where you *know for sure* that you will not be needing any arbitrary part. Some examples that come to mind are

```
1: expression//Timing//First            (* Get only the timing *)
2: (... Sow[x]...)//Reap//Last          (* Get only sowed values *)
3: Most@#/Last@#&@CoefficientList[poly] (* normalize by coefficient of highest degree term *)
4: Rest@#/First@#&@Eigenvalues[matrix]  (* normalize by largest eigenvalue *)
5: Most@#/Rest@#&@list                  (* divide each element by the next *)
```

I'm not very into golfing, but I do like minimizing my keystrokes that are spent doing nothing (and avoid the mouse). If I'm at the end of a long expression and I need to take the first element, I'd simply use `Part` to extract it rather than move the cursor all the way back to insert a `First@`. In other words:

```
something + (insert very long expression here)[[1]]
```

instead of

```
something + First@(insert very long expression here)
```

If I change my mind and decide I need a different element, I have the flexibility to do so and also include all elements with `[[;;]]`. In such cases, you can't simply stick in a `//First` at the end, because of the very low precedence of `Postfix` — the expression returned might not be what you intended to get.

Comment: In the case of `something + (insert very long expression here)` (already bracketed as shown) you can avoid the mouse or excessive left-cursor-key by pressing: `Ctrl` + `.` + `.` and then `left-cursor` a single time.  Four keystrokes total.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Not a very big fan of Ctrl+. — never been able to wrap my head around what it's going to select next. Of course, that might be just due to unconventional learning and a reluctance to use it, but I might get around to taming it like I did for `Infix` :)