# Difference between Sort and SortBy

Tags: sorting

I was playing with Sort. All examples I have come across so far, i.e

```
Sort[{1, -1, 3, -3, 2, 5}, Abs[#1]<Abs[#2]&]
```

can expressed in a shorter fashion using SortBy

```
SortBy[{1, -1, 3, -3, 2, 5}, Abs]
```

Surely, they wouldn't put in a completely redundant function, so what are the preferred use cases for Sort?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In general SortBy can do pretty much anything that Sort does; in some cases, possibly better or faster. You can find many comparisons on this site if you just search for both function names.

I also disagree with @user21382 that his task could not be expressed elegantly in `SortBy` form: not only can it be done, I would actually argue that it could be done even *more* readably with `SortBy` than with `Sort`.

User21382 set the task to sort the following data, presented as an association, first by ascending age, then by descending alphabetical order. This can be accomplished using the fact that `SortBy` **can take a *list* of functions that are applied in sequence to break ties**:

```
data = {
  <|"Name"->"Jill", "Age" -> 23|>,
  <|"Name"->"Jack", "Age" -> 55|>,
  <|"Name"->"Jen", "Age" -> 55|>,
  <|"Name"->"Joe", "Age" -> 23|>
};

SortBy[data, 
  {
  (#["Age"]&), (* by age, ascending *)
  (Total@ ToCharacterCode@ ToUpperCase@ #["Name"]&) (* by alpha order, descending *)
  }
]

(* Out:
{
<|"Name" -> "Joe", "Age" -> 23|>,
<|"Name" -> "Jill", "Age" -> 23|>,
<|"Name" -> "Jen", "Age" -> 55|>,
<|"Name" -> "Jack", "Age" -> 55|>
}
*)
```

Here I take advantage of the fact that higher character codes correspond to letters further down in alphabetical order, so ordering by increasing character code effectively gives reverse alphabetical order.

`SortBy` also has an *operator* syntax, i.e. the following two usages are equivalent:

```
SortBy[data, sortingfunction] == SortBy[sortingfunction] [data]
```

I find the latter form *very* readable and highly expressive.

Another interesting property of `SortBy` is the fact that it gives ready access to a [**stable sort**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Stable_sorts) function, i.e. a sorting algorithm that maintains the relative order of records with equal values, by using the following syntax:

```
SortBy[ data, {sortingfunction} ]
```

In this case, no tie-breaking function is provided, so tied values will be left in the original order. This has been showcased multiple times on the site already, so I will just link to this [older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304632/stable-sorting-ie-minimally-disruptive-sorting/3332690#3332690) from StackOverflow that explains the point very nicely.

Comment: I wish I could +2 for mentioning stable sort and even linking to the best origin post for it.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thank you! That's very kind.

Answer (score 11):

No one has mentioned the difference in performance:

```
SeedRandom[0];
data = RandomInteger[{-10000, 10000}, 10^5];

sdata = Sort[data, Abs[#1] < Abs[#2] &]; // AccurateTiming
sbdata = SortBy[data, Abs]; // AccurateTiming
sbstable = SortBy[data, {Abs}]; // AccurateTiming
(*
  1.86124
  0.0222057
  0.00999333
*)
```

As mentioned by [MarcoB](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/27951/marcob), the results are not always equivalent, since the second `SortBy` does a stable sort and apparently `Sort` and `SortBy` do different tie-breaks:

```
sdata[[10 ;; 20]]
sbdata[[10 ;; 20]]
sbstable[[10 ;; 20]]
(*
  {-1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1}
  {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}
  {-1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1}
*)
```

Comment: I would include a `BenchMarkPlot` but it's not working this morning -- emits `SymbolName::sym` errors.  Is this a known problem in V10.1 (Mac OS, if that's important)?

Comment: FYI I did mention the difference in performance, and I also linked to an answer of mine with a graph.  I forgot to include the stable performance however though [I have written about it before.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/31926/121) +1 for the order differences however.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I misunderstood your reference. Perhaps because it was late. Sorry about that.  Thanks for the upvote, in any case.

Answer (score 10):

I commented on this a bit here: [What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/78183#78183)

Since [`SortBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SortBy.html) was introduced in *Mathematica* 6 it is preferred where applicable over `Sort` with a custom comparator.  This is because `SortBy` uses vector application of its second argument over the sort expression then the fast internal sort/ordering function, whereas `Sort` results in high-level application to pairs of values.  Not all `Sort` operations can be practically converted into `SortBy` ones however.  (As far as I know.)

To highlight the behavior of `Sort` consider:

```
Sort[Range[7], (Print[{#, #2}]; #2 - # >= 3) &]
```

> {1,2}
>
> {1,3}
>
> {2,3}
>
> {4,5}
>
> {6,7}
>
> {4,7}
>
> {1,5}
>
> ```
> {3, 2, 1, 5, 4, 7, 6}
> ```

Individual pairs of elements are compared and blocks of elements are reordered if a test returns `False`.  This is simply not the way that `SortBy` uses its second parameter.  Admittedly I struggle to think of examples where this behavior of `Sort` is needed.

Comment: I have a matrix of numbers and want to sort it using 4th or 5th  column, not `First` or `Last` column. I cannot find an easy way to just sort the matrix by 4th column. For example, something like `SortBy[matrix, Fourth]`.

Comment: @TugrulTemel Use `SortBy[m, #[[4]] &]` or `SortBy[m, Extract[4]]`.

Answer (score 5):

SortBy is usually a more concise form of Sort, yes, but at times, you may have data that cannot be expressed, or cannot be expressed elegantly, using SortBy. For example, let's suppose that we want to sort the following by age, ascending, then by name, descending:

```
data = {
  <|"Name"->"Jill", "Age" -> 23|>,
  <|"Name"->"Jack", "Age" -> 55|>,
  <|"Name"->"Jen", "Age" -> 55|>,
  <|"Name"->"Joe", "Age" -> 23|>};
Sort[
  data,
  Function@Or[
    #1["Age"] < #2["Age"],
    #1["Age"] == #2["Age"] && OrderedQ[{#2["Name"], #1["Name"]}]]]
```

> {<|"Name" -> "Joe", "Age" -> 23|>, <|"Name" -> "Jill", 
>     "Age" -> 23|>, <|"Name" -> "Jen", "Age" -> 55|>, <|"Name" -> "Jack",
>      "Age" -> 55|>}

Admittedly, I almost never use Sort unless I can just call Sort[data], but it has its uses on occasion.

Comment: It should be noted that SortBy was new in v6 and has an operator form, while Sort doesn't, and is older.