# Sort by returning positions

Tags: sorting

How can I computationally efficiently sort a list so as to return the positions and not the actual values at those positions (which `SortBy` does)?

Comment: Are you talking about `Ordering`?

Comment: yes, I didn't notice that function. Confused with R. Thanks!

Comment: @Kuba I guess, rather about `OrderingBy` (which does not yet exist as built-in).

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, What functionality can you get from `SortBy` that you can't from `Sort` using the right sorting function?

Comment: @JasonB Speed. The way Mathematica evaluator works, `SortBy` is often vastly faster. The reason is a bit long to explain, but here is [one place to look at](http://mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node291.html), and [here is another](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2009/Jul/msg00057.html). It could've been discussed also here on this site, but I can't recall where.

Comment: [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/82964/9490). I can see that `SortBy` is faster, and so a true implementation of `OrderingBy` probably would be faster than `Ordering` as written below.

Comment: On an unrelated note. Does `SortBy` or `Ordering` parallelize automatically?

Comment: @AlGuy No they don't.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There were comments about the lack of an `OrderingBy` function, and for this I'll quote Szabolcs

> I think that OrderingBy is not necessary.  It it were to be analogous to SortBy then `OrderingBy[list, f]` would give exactly the same output as `Ordering[f /@ list]`, which can even be changed to

So we can just write

```
orderingBy[list_, f_] := Ordering[f /@ list];
orderingBy[f_] := Ordering[f /@ #] &;
```

and apply it to a list,

```
orderingBy[{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 1}, {3, 1, 2}, {2, 2}}, Total]
orderingBy[{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 1}, {3, 1, 2}, {2, 2}}, Rest]
orderingBy[{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 1}, {3, 1, 2}, {2, 2}}, Last]
(* {4, 1, 2, 3} *)
(* {4, 3, 1, 2} *)
(* {2, 3, 4, 1} *)
```

or use it in the operator form

```
orderingBy[Last]@{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 1}, {3, 1, 2}, {2, 2}}
(* {2, 3, 4, 1} *)
```

Comment: To save the next person who tries this solution some time: This function does not sort for tie breakers as would be the expected behavior for such a orderingBy function (Compare to the behavior of SortBy). So please read the answer by Mr. Wizard before applying this solution. Of course a perfect solution is also already given by Leonid Shifrin at the linked question.

Answer (score 5):

I think this should be marked as a duplicate of:

- [Retaining and reusing a one-to-one mapping from a sort](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19300/retaining-and-reusing-a-one-to-one-mapping-from-a-sor)

The method Jason posted is not equivalent to [`SortBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SortBy.html) unless one is using [the stable form](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3332690/618728), because no tie-breaking using the original expression is performed.  Consider:

```
a = {{1, 7, 0}, {1, 4}, {1, 2}, {2}};

b = SortBy[a, First]
Ordering[First /@ a]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2}, {1, 4}, {1, 7, 0}, {2}}
>
> {1, 2, 3, 4}
> ```

Jason's method indicates that the elements are already in order, but `SortBy` reorders significantly.  To match the default behavior of `SortBy` we could instead use an explicit `Identity` with [*my* `orderingBy` function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21453/121):

```
orderingBy[a, {First, Identity}]
a[[%]] === b
```

> ```
> {3, 2, 1, 4}
>
> True
> ```

To handle the default tie-break implicitly we could add a definition:

```
orderingBy[lst_List, sfn_] := orderingBy[lst, {sfn, Identity}]
```

And in v10 fashion an operator form:

```
orderingBy[fns_][lst_List] := orderingBy[lst, fns]
```

Now:

```
a // orderingBy[First]
```

> ```
> {3, 2, 1, 4}
> ```

Comment: Right you are, I think that makes my answer just plain wrong. Thanks for pointing it out, it isn't letting me delete the answer though

Comment: @Jason That is probably because it is the Accepted answer.  I don't think your answer is wrong really, just incomplete.  Your method is elegant where applicable and I did not intend to denigrate it.  Rather I wanted to make the case that this question is a duplicate of the one referenced, and I think I was successful as four people joined me in voting that way.