# Sorting a list based only on a certain property of the first element of sublists

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting

Suppose I have a list called `roster`. Each element in `roster` is a list containing two strings: (i) the species of animal and (ii) the animal's name.

```
roster = {
   {"cat", "Garfield"},
   {"cat", "Cheshire"},
   {"dog", "Pongo"},
   {"dog", "Lassie"},
   {"elephant", "Horton"},
   {"elephant", "Babar"}
  };
```

I want to sort `roster` in descending order by species size: elephants are largest, dogs are smaller, and cats are smallest. However, in doing the sort, I want to keep the order of names *unchanged*.

One way to do this is to apply an ordering list to `roster`:

```
roster[[{5, 6, 3, 4, 1, 2}]]
```

> `{{"elephant", "Horton"}, {"elephant", "Babar"}, {"dog", "Pongo"}, {"dog", "Lassie"}, {"cat", "Garfield"}, {"cat", "Cheshire"}}`

which is the desired output.

However, I'd like to achieve this result more programmatically.

I've considered using [`SortBy`[*list*, *f*]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SortBy.html), which according to the documentation, "sorts the elements of *list* in the order defined by applying *f* to each of them." I've tried the following:

```
(* Sort in decending order by size: elephant (largest), dog, cat (smallest) *)
sortFunc[animals_List] := Which[#[[1]] == "elephant", 1, #[[2]] == "dog", 2, #[[3]] == "cat", 3] &;
SortBy[roster, sortFunc]
```

which gives the correct species order, but **also** sorts the elements so the animal *names* are in canonical order, which is ***not*** what I want. I want the names to appear in whatever order they are given in `roster`. How can I do this?

I would like the method to be usable in *Mathematica* 9.0+, so please do not use [`Association`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html)s or other "new" built-in features (with "new" being features implemented in Mathematica within the past 8-10 years).

Additionally, I would like the method to be generalizable to nonconsecutive species in `roster`. For example, the following

```
roster = {
   {"cat", "Garfield"},
   {"cat", "Cheshire"},
   {"dog", "Pongo"},
   {"dog", "Lassie"},
   {"elephant", "Horton"},
   {"elephant", "Babar"},
   {"dog", "Perdita"},
   {"dog", "Snowy"},
   {"dog", "Odie"}
  };
```

should be sorted as the following (*i.e.*, leaving the order of names unchanged within each species):

```
{
   {"elephant", "Horton"},
   {"elephant", "Babar"},
   {"dog", "Pongo"},
   {"dog", "Lassie"},
   {"dog", "Perdita"},
   {"dog", "Snowy"},
   {"dog", "Odie"},
   {"cat", "Garfield"},
   {"cat", "Cheshire"}
}
```

Comment: In addition, using the `sortFunc` given by @Bob Hanlon, compare `SortBy[roster, {sortFunc}]` (giving a _stable sort_) with `SortBy[roster, sortFunc]`.  As I understand things from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/82964/106), `SortBy[list, {fn}]` gives a stable sort (ties are _not sorted_) whereas `SortBy[list, fn]` will sort ties

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Change `sortFunc` to

```
sortFunc := 
  Which[#[[1]] == "elephant", 1, #[[1]] == "dog", 2, #[[1]] == "cat", 
     3, True, 4] &;
```

Use the alternate syntax for [`SortBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SortBy.html)

```
SortBy[{{"elephant", "Horton"}, {"elephant", "Babar"}, {"dog", 
   "Pongo"}, {"dog", "Lassie"}, {"cat", "Garfield"}, {"cat", 
   "Cheshire"}}, {sortFunc, First}]

(* {{"elephant", "Horton"}, {"elephant", "Babar"}, {"dog", "Pongo"}, {"dog", 
  "Lassie"}, {"cat", "Garfield"}, {"cat", "Cheshire"}} *)
```

Checking against stated desired output

```
% === {{"elephant", "Horton"}, {"elephant", "Babar"}, {"dog", 
   "Pongo"}, {"dog", "Lassie"}, {"cat", "Garfield"}, {"cat", "Cheshire"}}

(* True *)
```

Answer (score 5):

One can use

```
mySortBy[list_,f_] := list[[Ordering[Map[f,list]]]];
```

**Example.**

```
roster = {
   {"cat", "Garfield"},
   {"cat", "Cheshire"},
   {"dog", "Pongo"},
   {"dog", "Lassie"},
   {"elephant", "Horton"},
   {"elephant", "Babar"},
   {"dog", "Perdita"},
   {"dog", "Snowy"},
   {"dog", "Odie"}
  };

sortFunc[{animal_,_}] := Switch[animal,
   "elephant",1,
   "dog",2,
   "cat",3];

mySortBy[roster,sortFunc]
(* {{elephant,Horton},
    {elephant,Babar},
    {dog,Pongo},
    {dog,Lassie},
    {dog,Perdita},
    {dog,Snowy},
    {dog,Odie},
    {cat,Garfield},
    {cat,Cheshire}} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

To make it more general, `Interpreter` functionality can be utilized:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
animals = {"elephant", "dog", "cat", "mouse", "goat", "horse", 
   "Horse"};
f[a_String] := 
 Mean@First@First@Interpreter["Animal"][ToLowerCase@a]["Weight"]
Transpose[{#, f@#}] & /@ animals
```

> {{"elephant", 4.1*10^6}, {"dog", 3.7*10^4}, {"cat", 4750.}, {"mouse",
> 26.}, {"goat", 6.4*10^4}, {"horse", 5.8*10^5}, {"Horse", 5.8*10^5}}

Notice capitalization on "Horse". `ToLowerCase` had to be added to the function to allow proper sorting. Such a case may appear in the input.

I have taken the liberty to add a few entries to the data in the OP:

```
roster = {{"cat", "Garfield"}, {"mouse", "Dodgy"}, {"cat", 
    "Cheshire"}, {"dog", "Pongo"}, {"dog", "Lassie"}, {"goat", 
    "Tod"}, {"horse", "Cruiser"}, {"mouse", "Cheesy"}, {"elephant", 
    "Horton"}, {"Horse", "Forge"}, {"elephant", "Babar"}, {"dog", 
    "Perdita"}, {"dog", "Snowy"}, {"dog", "Odie"}, {"goat", 
    "Caper"}, {"dog", "Pearl"}
   };

(Column /@ {roster, ReverseSortBy[{f@First@# &}][roster]})
```

[image]