# Optimal Solution for OddsBeforeEvens Wolfram Challenge

Tags: list-manipulation, challenge-community

Odds before Evens
Given a list of integers, rearrange them so that all of the odd integers appear before all of the even integers, without otherwise changing the order.

An obvious solution is

```
OddBeforeEven[data_List]:= Join[Cases[data, _?OddQ], Cases[data, _?EvenQ]]
```

But this isn't particularly efficient, so maybe we can try

```
OddBeforeEven[data_List]:= Join[Select[data, OddQ], Select[data, EvenQ]]
```

Now, an innovative solution could also be something like

```
OddBeforeEven[data_List]:= Flatten@GatherBy[data, OddQ]
```

But I can't seem to improve it further.

Can we optimize OddQ and EvenQ using Bit operations?

[image]

Comment: I think it should be better to add at least an example input list of integers together with the corresponding desired result.

Comment: Added to the post

Comment: Just a nit... The GatherBy solution doesn't actually work in all cases.

Comment: @lericr I know. An Alternative that I found was `With[{split = GroupBy[x, OddQ]}, Join[split[True], split[False]]]`. It's quite annoying that the GatherBy solution doesnt work (because Wolfram sorts the association according to the number of elements in each Key)— it's very efficient and does things in a single pass.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. GatherBy doesn't produce an association, and the lists that it does produce aren't sorted (explicitly anyway). The result of GatherBy is "sorted" according the the order in which each element was encountered. So, if the first element was odd, then the odds come first. If the first was even, then the evens come first. So, if GatherBy is your favorite, then a final pass over the results that puts the odds first before flattening would do it.

Comment: You're correct! I was confusing GroupBy and GatherBy. GatherBy is indeed my favorite

Answer (score 6):

```
f[x_]:=x[[Join@@Lookup[PositionIndex@BitAnd[x,1],{1,0},{}]]]

f[x_]:=x[[Join@@KeySortBy[PositionIndex@BitAnd[x,1],-#&]]]
```

Update:

```
Clear["`*"]
f1[x_]:=x[[Join@@Lookup[PositionIndex@BitAnd[x,1],{1,0},{}]]]
f2[x_]:=x[[Join@@KeySortBy[PositionIndex@BitAnd[x,1],-#&]]]
f3[x_]:=Join[Select[x,OddQ],Select[x,EvenQ]]
f4[x_]:=With[{split=GroupBy[x,OddQ]},Join[split[True],split[False]]]
a=RandomInteger[100,10^7];
r1=f1@a;//RepeatedTiming
r2=f2@a;//RepeatedTiming
r3=f3@a;//RepeatedTiming
r4=f4@a;//RepeatedTiming
r1==r2==r3==r4
```

> {0.194022, Null}

> {0.19214, Null}

> {2.79629, Null}

> {2.01458, Null}

> True

Update 2:

```
ClearAll["`*"]
f={x|->x[[Join@@Lookup[PositionIndex@BitAnd[x,1],{1,0},{}]]],
x|->x[[Join@@KeySortBy[PositionIndex@BitAnd[x,1],-#&]]],
x|->Join[Select[x,OddQ],Select[x,EvenQ]],
x|->With[{split=GroupBy[x,OddQ]},Join[split[True],split[False]]]};
n=10^Range[7];
t=Outer[RepeatedTiming[#1@#2;][[1]]&,f,RandomInteger[100,#]&/@n,1];
ListLogLogPlot[Inner[{#2,#1}&,t,n,List],
PlotLegends->Placed[LineLegend[ToString[#,TraditionalForm]&/@f,
LegendLayout->"Column"],Below],PlotRange->All,Joined->True,
PlotMarkers->{Automatic,Small},AxesLabel->{"n","Time(s)"}]
```

[image]

```
$Version
```

> 14.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 1, 2023)

Comment: Thanks! This is a unique solution, but it's not as fast as `Join[Select[list, OddQ], Select[list, EvenQ]]` or the most recent addition `With[{split = GroupBy[list, OddQ]}, Join[split[True], split[False]]]`

Comment: @Navvye Updated.

Comment: Very interesting! I used the benchmark set by Wolfram Challenges, and the SpeedScore was ~47 compared to 51 and 52 respectively by the abovementioned solutions. I think that the performance of your solution is best when utilized on large lists, whereas something like my solution is better for smaller lists. What do you think?

Comment: @Navvye Updated. f1 is faster on lists ranging in length from 10 to 10^7.

Comment: could you submit your solution on Wolfram Challenges and see what the SpeedScore is? It's showing 37 for me, which is an order of magnitude less than other solutions.. Very weird!?

Comment: @Navvye ~47.5, I don’t know exactly how the speedscore is derived, but the GroupBy one is slower than f1 on Wolfram Cloud(0.026 vs 0.36 for RandomInteger[10,10^6])

Answer (score 3):

Just a few alternatives. Nevertheless, the performance may vary depending on the list size.

```
l = {-1, 2, 8, -9, -2, -3, -6, -10, -8, 5, 7, 9, 7};

SortBy[{EvenQ}][l]

l[[Ordering[-BitAnd[l, 1]]]]
```

Result:

> `{-1, -9, -3, 5, 7, 9, 7, 2, 8, -2, -6, -10, -8}`

Answer (score 2):

Another, Another Edit: Taking inspiration from the solution of @vindobona, I wrote

`OddBeforeEven[list_]:= ReverseSortBy[{OddQ}][list]`

which has a speedscore of `56.3211`

Another Edit: Using Catenate is apparently faster than either Flatten or Join@@, so the fastest that I could achieve was `53.17`

`OddBeforeEven[list_]:= Catenate@Lookup[GroupBy[list, EvenQ], {False, True}]`

Edit: Here's another one, which achieves `52.7` using GatherBy and other manipulation.

`OddBeforeEven[list_]:= Flatten[Lookup[GroupBy[list,OddQ], {True, False}]]`

Here's a relatively fast solution, which achieves a SpeedScore of `51.9` (the record, is `60.17`)

```
OddBeforeEven[list_List]:= 
With[{split = GroupBy[list, OddQ]}, Join[split[True], split[False]]]
```

Comment: (+1) It might be useful for future visitors to point out that the braces surrounding the argument to `ReverseSortBy` (and `SortBy`) give a [stable sort](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/82964/106)?

Comment: @user1066 Great idea!

Answer (score 1):

The following code scored a respectable `54.96` in the speed test (the current highest is `60.17`),

```
OddBeforeEven[list : {__Integer}] := 
 Block[{x = OddQ[list]}, Join[Pick[list, x], Pick[list, x, False]]]
```

out-performing the following (with a speed score of `51.5`), which uses `Mod` instead of `OddQ`:

```
OddBeforeEven[list:{__Integer}]:=
  Block[{x = Mod[list, 2]}, Join[Pick[list, x, 1], Pick[list, x, 0]]]
```

and the following (with a score of `51.5`), which uses `BitAnd` instead of `OddQ`:

```
OddBeforeEven[list:{__Integer}]:=
  Block[{x = BitAnd[list, 1]}, Join[Pick[list, x, 1], Pick[list, x, 0]]]
```

---

For comparison, the neat solution using `Select`, posted by @Navvye (in a comment), scores `51.9`

```
OddBeforeEven[list:{__Integer}]:=
  Join[Select[list, OddQ], Select[list, EvenQ]]
```

---

Comment: Using Catenate, we can improve the speed a little bit more! 

`Catenate[{Pick[list, #], Pick[list, #, False]} &@OddQ[list]]`

gives a SpeedScore of `55.07`