# Exercise using Sort

Tags: sorting, homework

I have to order the following list according to the sum of the powers of each element of the list, using the function [`Sort`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sort.html).

```
mylist = Table[x^(i)^3 + 3 x^(i^2 - 6 i + 5) + i, {i, -6, 6}]
```

I can do it using [`Ordering`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ordering.html):

```
mylist[[Ordering[Total[Exponent[mylist, x, List], {2}]]]]
```

but I don't know how to do it using [`Sort`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sort.html). All my attempts failed. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is more of an extended comment to the OP's question and [`halirutan`'s answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/94182/29734), although there is the extra solution below that uses `SortBy` rather than `Sort`, and I find the syntax of `SortBy` easier to understand than `Sort`. In any case, note the following:

```
sortFunc[expr_] := Total[Exponent[expr, x, List]];
order[0] = mylist[[Ordering[Total[Exponent[mylist, x, List], {2}]]]];
order[1] = Sort[mylist, sortFunc[#1] < sortFunc[#2] &];
order[2] = Sort[mylist, sortFunc[#1] <= sortFunc[#2] &];
order[3] = SortBy[mylist, sortFunc];
Outer[SameQ, #, #, 1, 1]&@Array[order, 4, 0]
(* { {True, False, True, False}
     , {False, True, False, False}
     , {True, False, True, False}
     , {False, False, False, True} } *)
```

In other words, three of these four ways of doing things return different results! `halirutan`s way, using `<` gives a slightly different ordering than the OP's way, but changing `<` to `<=` gets back the OP's ordering.

Of course, this isn't entirely surprising:

```
sortFunc /@ mylist
(* {-139, -65, -19, 5, 13, 11, 5, 1, 5, 23, 61, 125, 221} *)
```

So there are three terms with the total of the exponents being five. `Ordering` keeps the order of the elements that are the same:

```
Flatten@Position[sortFunc /@ mylist, 5]
Ordering[sortFunc /@ mylist]
(* {4, 7, 9} *)
(* {1, 2, 3, 8, 4, 7, 9, 6, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13} *)
```

Note the `4, 7, 9` in `Sequence` inside the `Ordering` list. On the other hand, `SortBy` yields a different ordering:

```
Position[mylist, #] & /@ order[3] // Flatten
(* {1, 2, 3, 8, 7, 9, 4, 6, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13} *)
```

Here, it's `7, 9, 4` instead of `4, 7, 9`. This is because we know that

> If some of the `f[e[i]]` are the same, then the canonical order of the corresponding `e[i]` is used.

from the documentation of `SortBy`. This could go either way, I guess: I can see how it would be reasonable to keep the ordering intact if the elements are "equal" in the ordering sense, but I also like the idea that `SortBy` respects *Mathematica*'s implicit sorting. I suppose both ways can be useful in different situations.

*Mathematica*'s sorting algorithm for expressions is something of a mystery to me, but note that

```
Ordering[mylist]
(* {8, 7, 9, 6, 5, 10, 4, 3, 2, 11, 1, 12, 13} *)
```

We can see that the order is `7, 9, 4`, although of course some other elements of the list come between some of them.

---

Finally, as noted by Mr. Wizard, one can reproduce the `Ordering` solution with `SortBy` using

```
SortBy[mylist, {sortFunc}]
```

Comment: `SortBy[mylist, {sortFunc}]` will provide a stable sort matching the result of `Ordering`.  References: [(3332690)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3332690/),
[(7687)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7687/121),
[(27323)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/27323/121),
[(31926)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/31926/121)

Answer (score 7):

Using your code, let me make it clear by introducing an auxiliary function that sums the exponents in an expression

```
sortFunc[expr_] := Total[Exponent[expr, x, List]]
```

Now you can go with

```
Sort[mylist, sortFunc[#1] < sortFunc[#2] &]
```