# How to extract and replace submatrix of a doubly-periodic matrix?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, replacement

How can I effectively extract and replace a rectangular subpart of a toroidal matrix, i.e. one where boundaries are connected at opposite ends? Since the submatrix can overhang the edges, a simple `Take` won't work, as the submatrix cannot be extracted if it is not continuous. At present, I construct a table of positions that are extracted/replaced via `ReplacePart`, but I feel there must be more elegant and faster solutions. Such answers could add to the usefulness of [Elegant operations on matrix rows and columns](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3069/89). Consider the following example:

```
n = 8; (* matrix edge length *)
m = 4; (* submatrix edge length *)

matrix = Table[0, {n}, {n}];
sub = RandomReal[{.2, 1}, {m, m}]; (* random submatrix *)
pos = {6, 7}; (* position of sub assuming bottom left corner as origo *)

subPos = Table[{i, j}, {i, m}, {j, m}];
repPos = Map[Mod[# + pos - 1, n, 1] &, subPos, {2}]; (* list of positions to extract *)

new = ReplacePart[ReplacePart[matrix, Flatten@MapThread[Rule, {repPos, sub}, 2]], pos -> 2];
  (* Replace the explicit list of positions with the elements of sub *)

ArrayPlot[Reverse@Transpose@new, 
 ColorRules -> {2 -> Pink, 0 -> White}, Mesh -> All, ImageSize -> 300]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Pink cell indicates the origin of the submatrix.

**Question**: Can the extraction/replacement done faster, assuming that `matrix` and `sub` could be huge (e.g. 10 000x10 000 and 50x50, respectively)?

Comment: +1 Excellently presented question. I wish we had many more of those.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
 n = 8; m = 4;
 origin ={6,7};
 matrix = Table[0, {n}, {n}];
 sub2 = Array[s, {m, m}];
 sub3 = RandomReal[{.2, 1}, {m, m}];
 sub3[[1,1]]=2;


{dimmat, dimsub} = Dimensions /@ {matrix, sub2};
(* using Istvan's suggestion for generating row and column indices of the part to be replaced:*)
{rows, columns} =  Mod[Range @@@ Transpose@{origin, origin + dimsub - 1}, dimmat, 1];
matrix[[rows, columns]] = sub2;
matrix // Grid
```

[image]

```
matrix[[rows, columns]] = sub3;
matrix // Grid
```

[image]

```
ArrayPlot[Reverse@Transpose@matrix, 
     ColorRules -> {2 -> Pink, 0 -> White}, Mesh -> All, ImageSize -> 300]
```

[image]

Note: Finding the row and column indices takes almost no time. For random 10,000x10,000 `matrix`s and random 50 by 50 submatrices, with random origins in the last 100x100 block, it takes less than a second to replace the parts of the matrix.

Comment: Thanks, I always forget about this way of part extraction and reassignment! However, I still would prefer the modulo: `{rows, columns} = 
 Mod[Range @@@ Transpose@{origin, origin + m - 1}, n, 1]`.

Comment: Istvan, thanks for the accept. I also prefer your `Mod[...]`.