# How to get a sub range of a larger matrix?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

This should be an easy question but I only found a partial solution using `All`.

Say I have a matrix A = 1000 x 5, how to get only a part of that matrix, say B = *n* x 5, where *n* can be any positive integer that's less than 1000 or the original matrix A row?

Comment: Please have a good long look at `Part` (preferrably in conjunction with `Span`).

Comment: Could you please consider accepting some answers [`by clicking the checkmark sign`](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)` ?

Comment: You might find this Q/A useful: [How to extract and replace submatrix...](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10947/89).

Answer (score 4):

You can make good use of `Span` in multiple dimensions:

```
m = Table[{y, x}, {y, 1, 5}, {x, 1, 10}];

m[[2 ;; 3, 5 ;; 6]]
```

> {{{2, 5}, {2, 6}}, {{3, 5}, {3, 6}}}

(verbatim @J.M.)...`Take[]` works nicely as well:

```
Take[m, {2, 3}, {5, 6}]
```

> {{{2, 5}, {2, 6}}, {{3, 5}, {3, 6}}}

Comment: `Take[]` works nicely as well: `Take[m, {2, 3}, {5, 6}]`

Comment: @J.M. another answer? Strangely, I almost never use `Take` in my code... so much for cerebral plasticity.

Comment: I'd prefer that you just append it to your answer... :)

Comment: @J.M. Ta(l)king about low-hanging fruit :-)

Answer (score 0):

I guess this should work, if I need the second and third rows of a matrix :

```
{{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {g, h, i}}[[2 ;; 3]]
```