# Correct way to remove matrix columns?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I start off with `m = 1000 x 5` matrix, and I would like to remove first column to get `1000 x 4` matrix and repeat again for `1000 x 3` and so on. Is there an efficient way to do this? I see Insert to add columns or rows but don't see command for removing? I see maybe use the extract but is this only for a single vector extraction?

Comment: Have you tried `Most`?

Comment: Seems like Drop works too:  (tmp = {{11, 12, 13}, {21, 22, 23}, {31, 32, 33}}) // MatrixForm  and then (Drop[tmp, None, 1]) // MatrixForm

Comment: Take[m, All, 2 ;;]

Answer (score 18):

As has been shown there are a number of ways to do this.  To summarize:

```
m = RandomInteger[9, {6, 4}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

All of these:

```
Drop[m, 0, 1]

Rest /@ m

m[[All, 2 ;;]]

{##2} & @@@ m
```

Produce:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Each has a place.  For the specific operation `Rest` is especially clear.  `Drop` can easily drop columns besides the first, e.g. `Drop[m, 0, {3}]`, and it is very fast.  `Part` is also usually very fast, and [allows assignments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3077/121) which is both flexible and efficient (when applicable).  `SlotSequence` is simply fun and can be quite useful when you also want to do something with the elements.

Timings with larger matrix:

```
m = RandomInteger[9, {15000, 100}];

Drop[m, 0, 1]  // timeAvg
Rest /@ m      // timeAvg
m[[All, 2 ;;]] // timeAvg
{##2} & @@@ m  // timeAvg
```

> 0.0010224
>
> 0.004496
>
> 0.0011728
>
> 0.03992

(The `timeAvg` function has been repeatedly posted before.  Use Search.)

Comment: I believe the currently documented syntax is `Drop[m,None,1]` rather than `Drop[m,0,1]`.  If so, I'm wondering if that means the use of a `0` instead is guaranteed to work (lookin forward).

Comment: @Alan This has worked for a long time and I wouldn't expect it to go away.  Unfortunately the *Mathematica* documentation is *not* rigorous and one must fill in the gaps with experimentation and inference.  I would say that `Drop[m, 0, 1]` is pseudo-documented by "n (is)  elements 1 through n" and the convention with other functions that "one through zero" is an empty set, i.e. `Range[0]` returns `{}`.  Note that `Drop[m, {}, 1]` also works.  If you are hoping to see all of this specified explicitly in the documentation for `Drop` I am afraid you will be disappointed. :-/

Answer (score 7):

I am not sure this deserves a full blown answer but...

```
 a = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {15, 5}];

 Rest /@ a // Dimensions


 (* {15,4} *)
```

And to operate recursively

```
 Dimensions /@ NestList[Rest /@ # &, a, 3]

 (* 
  15    5
  15    4
  15    3
  15    2
  *)
```

**EDIT**

Replaced `Most` by `Rest` since as noticed by Mr Wizard this was actually the OP question!

Comment: In truth, this is one of those canonical questions that has several approaches.

Comment: Why not continue the process? `NestList[Most /@ # &, a, 5]` Then look at `Dimensions /@ NestList[Most /@ # &, a, 5]`, whose output is `{{15, 5}, {15, 4}, {15, 3}, {15, 2}, {15, 1}, {15, 0}}`, as expected. But look at: `MatrixForm /@ NestList[Most /@ # &, a, 5]`. I find the final entry in the output of that surprising: I would expect to see just the big 15-row brackets with nothing inside them; instead, I see an empty list `{}` in each of the 15 rows.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a way to do it with `Table`:

```
mat = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {3, 5}]
Table[mat = mat[[All, 2 ;; -1]], {Dimensions[mat][[2]] - 1}];

MatrixForm /@ %
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: +1 for an efficient mutable method.  Of note is that one can use the slightly shorter `mat[[All, 2 ;;]]`.