# How to use "Drop" function to drop matrix' rows and columns in an arbitrary way?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

The built-in function "Drop" can delete a Matrix's row and column.
Typical syntax for "Drop" is as follows:

```
Drop[list,seq1,seq2...]
```

But what if I want to drop a matrix in a way that the indices of the columns  to be deleted is not a well ordered sequence?

For example the matrix is 10x10, And I want to drop 3,4,7,9 rows and columns in a single time, then how to do it quickly?

Comment: Try `matrix[[All, Complement[Range[10], {3, 4, 7, 9}]]]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Will a one-line answer OK? I mean I'm right now in a condition not able to type too many words..

Comment: @Mr.Wizard +1. Much better than just one line :)

Comment: @Silvia In the future go ahead and post the one line answer, *if* it does in fact answer the question.  Sometimes I'll flesh out such answers when I see them; I would have in this case.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Got it. Sometimes there will be very interesting answers to those at-first-sight basic questions, so I liked to put simple direct answer in comments.

Comment: Related, simpler question: [(17002)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17002), and extension to ragged arrays: [(43785)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43785)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'm sure this question is a duplicate but I cannot find it; I think it may only be duplicated on StackOverflow (I know one duplicate is there).

#### Basic idea

A key statement in your question is:

> I want to drop 3,4,7,9 rows and columns in a single time, then how to do it quickly?

I believe this calls for `Part` which can extract (and by inverse, drop) rows and columns *at the same time*.  You must extract the parts you *don't* want to drop so use `Complement`.

```
m = Partition[Range@100, 10];

ranges = Complement[Range@#, {3, 4, 7, 9}] & /@ Dimensions[m]

new = m[[##]] & @@ ranges;

new // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### As a self-contained function

This is written to handle arrays of arbitrary depth.

```
drop[m_, parts__List] /; Length@{parts} <= ArrayDepth[m] :=
 m[[##]] & @@ MapThread[Complement, {Range @ Dimensions[m, Length @ {parts}], {parts}}]

drop[m, {3, 4, 7, 9}, {4, 5, 6}] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

### Timings

user asked how to test the performance of the solutions presented.  Here is a very basic series of tests that one might start with.  First a custom timing function based on code from Timo:

```
SetAttributes[timeAvg, HoldFirst]
timeAvg[func_] := Do[If[# > 0.3, Return[#/5^i]] & @@ Timing@Do[func, {5^i}], {i, 0, 15}]
```

Then the functions to test:

```
dropCarlos[m_, rows_, cols_] /; ArrayDepth[m] > 1 :=
 Delete[Delete[m, List /@ rows]\[Transpose], List /@ cols]\[Transpose]

(* copy drop from above *)
```

Then a test function with three parameters.  (The parameters are the number of randomly selected rows and columns to drop and dimensions of the array.)

```
test[n_, r_, c_] :=
 With[{
    a = RandomReal[9, {r, c}],
    rows = RandomSample[Range@r, n],
    cols = RandomSample[Range@c, n]
    },
  {#, timeAvg @ #[a, rows, cols]} & /@ {dropCarlos, drop}
 ] // TableForm
```

We can now probe a few shapes and sizes of data. (Another option would be plotting these tests but that's best left to a separate question if there is interest.)

```
test[5, 1000, 1000] (* delete only 5 rows and columns from a 1000x1000 array *)
```

> ```
> dropCarlos    0.006608
> drop          0.001248
> ```

```
test[900, 1000, 1000] (* delete all but 100 rows and columns from a 1000x1000 array *)
```

> ```
> dropCarlos    0.00047904
> drop          0.00017472
> ```

```
test[50, 10000, 100] (* delete 50 from a very tall array *)
```

> ```
> dropCarlos    0.005368
> drop          0.001072
> ```

```
test[50, 100, 10000] (* delete 50 from a very wide array *)
```

> ```
> dropCarlos    0.002496
> drop          0.0008992
> ```

These tests cover a variety of cases to see if the relative performance of the functions under test change significantly; if they do a method may have hidden strengths or weaknesses.

A final test that must be included in the suite is using *non*-packed data (all the test above were with packed arrays).  This is because there are often *significant* internal optimizations for packed arrays that cannot be used on unpacked data.  Because of this a function that is fast on packed arrays might become suddenly slow elsewhere.  For this test replace the expression `RandomReal[9, {r, c}]` with `RandomChoice["a" ~CharacterRange~ "z", {r, c}]` in the definition of `test`.  This creates an array of strings which cannot be packed.  Now run another `test`:

```
test[250, 1000, 1000]  (* this time with an unpacked String array *)
```

> ```
> dropCarlos    0.009232
> drop          0.00424
> ```

Notice that while my function is still faster it is not *as much* faster; this is because `Part` is particularly well optimized for packed arrays.

Comment: Thank you, Seems very powerful. But I need time to understand those lines with #,@,&.... , I wish I could read these codes just like reading novels...

Comment: @user15964 I'm happy to explain any part of it you don't understand.  I prefer not to make my answers needlessly long (and take the time to do that) unless someone asks for an explanation.  A few points:  `f @ x` is the same as `f[x]`.  `f /@ {1, 2, 3}` creates `{f[1], f[2], f[3]}`.  `f @@ {1, 2, 3}` creates `f[1, 2, 3]`.  `Range` has attribute `Listable` therefore: `Range @ {1, 2, 3}` creates `{{1}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}}`. Also look up `Slot` and `SlotSequence` in the help.

Comment: A question: Carlos gives a rather easy and understandable method to do this using "Delete", but it involves "Transpose". I am intersted about the efficiency of the two method, yours or Carlos'?

Comment: @user15964 usually the best thing to do it run timings in your own application, which can be assisted by [this function.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4199042/618728)  I'll also run a couple of `Timing` passes and tell you the result.  By the way, one difference is that I set up my `drop` function to extend to arrays of greater depth; doing the same thing with `Transpose` (manually that is) would end up difficult I believe.

Comment: Yeah, yours is more general! I got it.

Comment: @user15964 On a packed array of 1000x1000 Reals (`RandomReal[9, {1000, 1000}]`) my method is about six times faster than the double `Delete`/`Transpose` for the same operation.  I can add timing code to my answer if this will help you.

Comment: I would appreciate it, if you can show me how to test code efficiency. I only hope that it will not bother you too much.

Comment: @user15964 I would be glad to, but I have something to ask of you: would you please pick a different nickname besides "user___" -- it would make it a lot easier on me than having to review your list of posts when I wish to remember *which* "user___" I'm talking to.

Comment: @Mr.Wiard I've changed my name.

Comment: @matheorem Thanks.  Fairly extensive timing code added.  That took longer to type than I expected, but I hope it helps!

Comment: Finally, I understand all the codes in your answer . I learned a lot! God bless and Thank you very much, Mr.Wizard!

Answer (score 9):

I would use [`Delete[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Delete.html) for the purpose of deleting selected rows:

```
Delete[Array[C, {4, 4}], {{2}, {3}}]
(* {{C[1, 1], C[1, 2], C[1, 3], C[1, 4]}, {C[4, 1], C[4, 2], C[4, 3], C[4, 4]}} *)
```

To delete columns, you could do a preliminary transposition first...

Answer (score 2):

Using `ReplacePart` to drop rows and columns at the same time.

```
m = Partition[Range @ 100, 10];
p = Alternatives @@ {3, 4, 7, 9};

ReplacePart[{{_, p}, p} -> Nothing] @ m // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) Your solution seems better to me, since the elimination of rows and columns is more flexible. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Using the eldo's data:

```
m = Partition[Range @ 100, 10];
```

An alternative is to use `TakeDrop`:

```
dropRowsCols[m_, rows : {_, _}, cols : {_, _}] := 
  Part[
    TakeDrop[
        Transpose[
            Part[
            TakeDrop[
                Transpose @ m, rows
                    ], 2
                ]], cols
            ],
        2
   ];

dropRowsCols[m, {2, 6}, {2, 3}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]