# Is there documentation on the comparative performance of Mathematica functions?

Tags: functions, performance-tuning, reference-request

Recently I have been solving some Project Euler problems. I find there are always several ways to do the same thing. For example, one could join two lists like this:

```
a = {2, 1};
b = {2, 3};
Union[a, b]
Join[a, b]
```

Which gives

> {1, 2, 3}
>   {2, 1, 2, 3}

So the `Union` function sorts the element and deletes duplicates. I guess the `Join` function will be faster, but how much faster? In a loop, would it be more efficient to use `Join` and `DeleteDuplicates` at each 100th step?

Is there documentation of the comparative performance of *Mathematica* functions? Because heuristics as above could be totally wrong, and I don't know how much experimenting it would take to form a good understanding of the complexity of functions.

Comment: Performance tuning in Mathematica is more complicated than that. Start a fresh kernel and try `{Timing[Prime[10000000000]][[1]], Timing[Prime[10000000000]][[1]]}`. Also, many of the algorithms use heuristics to switch between strategies when appropriate.

Comment: Your specific question is so highly specialized that I doubt you will find an answer no matter how much performance documentation might exist.  To get an accurate answer, you will need to do a quick timing study in your particular circumstance.

Comment: Here's one way to tell in any particular case which of two (or more) functions is faster: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22419/benchmarking-expressions/22420#22420