# Find the slope between adjacent points in a list

Tags: list-manipulation, pure-function

I have a list of two dimensional points that are ordered by their x-coordinate.

I would like to calculate the slope between all adjacent points.

I'm familiar with the use of pure functions in Sort for example that can compare adjacent elements.  Is there a way to perform a function on all adjacent elements in a list?

Comment: Use a pure function to calculate the slope for two points and use it on `Partition[list, 2, 1]`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is one possibility to compute the slope between each pair of adjacent points. I create a list of random points first and use the `Sort` function sort them by their x-coordinate (`First`):

```
list = SortBy[RandomReal[{0, 10}, {20, 2}], First]
```

> ```
>   {{0.0612793, 5.82737}, {0.171386, 6.8975}, {0.704354, 
>   8.53224}, {0.798152, 6.39703}, {0.967127, 8.35358}, {1.75119, 
>   6.73572}, {3.35177, 6.91908}, {3.81578, 7.8129}, {4.19851, 
>   2.66794}, {4.73162, 3.37847}, {5.65875, 4.22096}, {5.80131, 
>   8.62895}, {5.8604, 6.61611}, {6.24086, 3.4343}, {7.01985, 
>   9.76974}, {7.76579, 1.96783}, {7.90587, 8.20642}, {8.65277, 
>   2.30016}, {9.06088, 5.22962}, {9.98638, 6.34865}}
> ```

Then, the list of points is partitioned into lists of pairs using `Partition` with an offset of 1. Now we can use a pure function to compute the slope and use `Apply` to apply it to the list of pairs.

```
(Last[#2] - Last[#1])/(First[#2] - First[#1]) & @@@ Partition[list, 2, 1]
```

> ```
> {9.71896, 3.06724, -22.7637, 11.5789, -2.06344, 0.114559, 1.92631,
> -13.4428, 1.33282, 0.908702, 30.9207, -34.0611, -8.36311, 8.13291,
> -10.4592, 44.5349, -7.90772, 7.1782, 1.20911}
> ```

This can also be done using the `Map` function and indexing:

```
(#[[2, 2]] - #[[1, 2]])/(#[[2, 1]] - #[[1, 1]]) & /@ Partition[list, 2, 1]
```

> ```
> {9.71896, 3.06724, -22.7637, 11.5789, -2.06344, 0.114559, 1.92631,
> -13.4428, 1.33282, 0.908702, 30.9207, -34.0611, -8.36311, 8.13291,
> -10.4592, 44.5349, -7.90772, 7.1782, 1.20911}
> ```

**EDIT: a much faster version using `Transpose`, `Differences` and `Apply`**

For sure there are several ways of dealing with this question. Here's much a faster version to compute the slope between adjacent points in a list using the functions `Differences`, `Transpose` and `Apply`:

```
#2/#1 & @@ Transpose@Differences[list]
```

> ```
> {9.71896, 3.06724, -22.7637, 11.5789, -2.06344, 0.114559, 1.92631,
> -13.4428, 1.33282, 0.908702, 30.9207, -34.0611, -8.36311, 8.13291,
> -10.4592, 44.5349, -7.90772, 7.1782, 1.20911}
> ```

When i apply this to a list of 10^6 pairs in list I get similar timings as the approach presented by [Anon](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/731/anon). When applied to 10^7 pairs in the list the first approach seems to be a bit faster compared to [Anon](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/731/anon)'s approach in most of the runs:

```
list = SortBy[RandomReal[{0, 10}, {10^6, 2}], First];
{Timing[#2/#1 & @@ Transpose@Differences[list]][[1]], 
Timing[Flatten[Ratios[Differences[list], {0, 1}]]][[1]]}
```

> ```
> {0.046800, 0.078001}
> ```

```
list = SortBy[RandomReal[{0, 10}, {10^7, 2}], First];
{Mean@Table[Timing[#2/#1 & @@ Transpose@Differences[list]][[1]], {i, 1, 25}],
Mean@Table[Timing[Flatten[Ratios[Differences[list], {0, 1}]]][[1]], {i, 1, 25}]}
```

> ```
> {0.557860, 0.630868}
> ```

Comment: Yes, the edited one is nice.  I had slightly different timings.  See my update.

Answer (score 12):

What rm-rf suggested is this:

```
#[[2]]/#[[1]] & /@ (#[[2]] - #[[1]] & /@ Partition[data, 2, 1])
```

Or some version of it (see [g3kk0](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/2024/g3kk0)'s answer). This can also be written using `Differences`:

```
#[[2]]/#[[1]] & /@ Differences[data]
```

If the slope is calculated using the standard $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$ formula.

But we don't have to use an anonymous function unless we want to. This is also equivalent to the ones above:

```
Flatten[Ratios /@ Differences[data]]
```

**EDIT:** Here's another way which I find to be the most elegant of them all:

```
Flatten[Ratios[Differences[list], {0, 1}]]
```

Answer (score 10):

Two new methods and a comparison of performance.  Conceptually I like my second one, but it's slow; similarly I like [Anon](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/731)'s second `Ratios` one, but it's not as fast as the pure function version.  The first solution, Anon's fourth, and [g3kko](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/2024)'s edit are worth looking at if you want to take advantage of *Mathematica*'s efficiencies with [vectorized functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29349/performance-tuning-in-mathematica/29351#29351) and [packed arrays](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/what-is-a-mathematica-packed-array).  The two slowest ones are slow in part because they unpack `list`.

```
SeedRandom[1];
list = SortBy[RandomReal[1, {1000000, 2}], First];

(dlist1 = Divide @@ Reverse @ Transpose @ Differences @ list) // Timing // First
(* 0.087723 *)

(dlist2 = Module[{f},
       f = Interpolation[list, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
       Rest[f'["ValuesOnGrid"]]
     ]) // Timing // First
(* 3.926643 *)

(g3kk0 = (Last[#2] - Last[#1])/(First[#2] - First[#1]) & @@@ 
     Partition[list, 2, 1]) // Timing // First
(* 5.146319 *)

(anon2 = #[[2]]/#[[1]] & /@ Differences[list]) // Timing // First
(* 0.254574 *)

(anon3 = Flatten[Ratios /@ Differences[list]]) // Timing // First
(* 0.427240 *)
```

Check:

```
dlist1 == dlist2 == g3kk0 == anon2 == anon3
(* True *)
```

---

This variation on [Anon](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/731)'s is a little faster:

```
#[[All, 2]] / #[[All, 1]] &@ Differences[list] // Timing // First
(* 0.104045 *)
```

[g3kko](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/2024)'s update:

```
(g3kk03 = #2/#1 & @@ Transpose@Differences[list]) // Timing // First
(* 0.088209 *)
```

[Anon](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/731)'s update is best so far:

```
(anon4 = Flatten[Ratios[Differences[list], {0, 1}]]) // Timing // First
(* 0.069120 *)
```

---

**Edit: A note on timings**

[g3kko](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/2024) reports a faster time relative to the others.  I've a remarkable variation in the timings of Anon's and g3kko's depending on the version of *Mathematica*.  I ran the following variation of g3kko's test for `n = 6, 7`; if a `1/0` error occured, I reran the trial.

```
m = 6 (* 7 *);
Mean@Table[
  list = SortBy[RandomReal[{0, 10}, {10^n, 2}], First];
  {Timing[#2/#1 & @@ Transpose@Differences[list]][[1]], 
   Timing[Flatten[Ratios[Differences[list], {0, 1}]]][[1]]},
 {i, 1, 25}]
```

> ```
>                -- n = 6 --          -- n = 7 --
>              g3kko     Anon       g3kk0     Anon
> V8.0.4    0.0875985  0.158488   0.904362  0.557465
> V9.0.1    0.073255   0.096305   0.975468  0.604091
> ```

Kind of odd, if you study it.  But `Timing` each individual computation increases the error.

Here the computations are aggregated and I used `AbsoluteTiming` in place of `Timing`. (I also reduced the number of trials for `n = 7` because I was running out of coffee. :)

```
n = 6 (* 7 *);
trials = 25 (* 10 *);
SeedRandom[2];
lists = Table[SortBy[RandomReal[{0, 10}, {10^n, 2}], First], {i, trials}];
{AbsoluteTiming[
   Do[#2/#1 & @@ Transpose@Differences[lists[[i]]], {i, trials}]][[1]] / trials,
 AbsoluteTiming[
   Do[Flatten[Ratios[Differences[lists[[i]]], {0, 1}]], {i, trials}]][[1]] / trials}
```

> ```
>                -- n = 6 --            -- n = 7 --
>              g3kko     Anon         g3kk0     Anon
> V8.0.4    0.0577675  0.0478107   0.6060478  0.5632528
> V9.0.1    0.0514788  0.0461873   0.6073914  0.5819507
> ```

(I probably should have started out with [timeAvg](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22419/benchmarking-expressions/22427#22427), but that's life. :/ )

Comment: Added a new version using `Ratios` that is the fastest of them all on my computer, 0.050135. :)

Comment: @Michael E2: Nice comparison of the different approaches.

Comment: @Anon Cool!  Elegant *and* fast! I didn't pay attention to the second argument of `Ratios`.  Not quite as fast on my machine, but still the winner: 0.069120 :D

Comment: @MichaelE2: I added another fast version and looked at the timings for 10^7 pairs. It seems to be even a bit faster, but like all possibilites that take less than a coffee break ;)

Comment: That seems to be a somewhat strange behaviour. I tested it several times and the Apply version was always a bit faster. Whatever, the problem is more than just solved :)

Comment: @g3kko Clearly they're nearly equivalent.  Perhaps there's a slight system dependency (I'm on Mac 10.8.4 2.7GHz i7).

Answer (score 2):

```
list = RandomReal[{0, 10}, {20, 2}]
1/Divide @@ Subtract @@@ Transpose@# & /@ Partition[list, 2, 1]
1/Divide @@@ Differences[list]
#2/#1 & @@@ Differences[list]
```

Answer (score 0):

My two cents. Without using Differences, but a slower replacement rule. I believe subtracting the rotated list can be much faster then mapping function on list itself.

```
list - RotateLeft[list, 1] /. {dx_, dy_} -> dy/dx // Most
```

The replacement, though, takes its toll on the timings.

Comment: Two points: `RotateLeft[list]` is equivalent to `RotateLeft[list, 1]`, and you should use `:>` to localize `dx` and `dy`.