# Efficient lazy weak compositions

Tags: performance-tuning, memory, combinatorics, partitions, lazy-computations

In *Mathematica* all weak `k`-compositions of integer `n` can be generated using permutations of integer partitions:

```
ClearAll[weakCompositionsPermPart]
weakCompositionsPermPart[n_Integer, k_Integer?NonNegative] :=
    Join @@ Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[n, {k}, Range[0, n]]
```

But since their number grow very rapidly as `Binomial[n + k - 1, n]` we can easily run out of memory when trying to use weak compositions of large numbers.

Problem of lack of memory could be solved if we could generate weak compositions in chunks. So here's my question.

**How can we generate weak k-compositions in chunks of given length?**

---

## What have I tried

`IntegerPartitions` accepts fourth argument with standard sequence specification, using it we can get partitions in chunks.
Combining this with [`` Streaming` `` module](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85336/14303) we can easily create lazy integer partitions:

```
Needs["Streaming`"]

ClearAll[lazyIntegerPartitions]
lazyIntegerPartitions[
    n_Integer, kspec_:All, sspec_:All, chunkSize:_Integer?Positive:100000
] :=
    Module[{ctr = 0, active = False},
        Check[
            Quiet[
                IntegerPartitions[n, kspec, sspec, {1}],
                IntegerPartitions::take
            ],
            Return[$Failed, Module]
        ];
        LazyListCreate[
            IteratorCreate[
                ListIterator,
                (active = True) &,
                With[
                    {taken = 
                        Quiet[
                            IntegerPartitions[
                                n, kspec, sspec, {ctr + 1, ctr + chunkSize}
                            ],
                            IntegerPartitions::take
                        ]
                    }
                    ,
                    ctr += Length[taken];
                    taken
                ] &,
                TrueQ[active] &,
                Remove[active, ctr] &
            ],
            chunkSize
        ]
    ]
```

Basic usage. Lazy list of partitions of 10 to, up to 7, elements containing only 1, 3, 5 and 7, taken in chunks of length 3:

```
lazyIntegerPartitions[10, 7, {1, 3, 5, 7}, 3]
(* « LazyList[{7,3},{7,1,1,1},{5,5},...] » *)

Scan[Print, %]
(* {7,3}
   {7,1,1,1}
   {5,5}
   {5,3,1,1}
   {5,1,1,1,1,1}
   {3,3,3,1}
   {3,3,1,1,1,1} *)

%% // Normal
(* {{7, 3}, {7, 1, 1, 1}, {5, 5}, {5, 3, 1, 1}, {5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
    {3, 3, 3, 1}, {3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1}} *)
```

Some basic tests that whole lazy lists are the same as non-lazy lists of integer partitions:

```
And @@ Table[
    SameQ[
        lazyIntegerPartitions[n] // Normal, 
        IntegerPartitions[n]
    ],
    {n, 30}
]
(* True *)

And @@ Table[
    SameQ[
        lazyIntegerPartitions[n, {2, 3}] // Normal, 
        IntegerPartitions[n, {2, 3}]
    ],
    {n, 30}
]
(* True *)

And @@ Table[
    SameQ[
        lazyIntegerPartitions[n, All, {1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 12}, 5] // Normal,
        IntegerPartitions[n, All, {1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 12}]
    ],
    {n, 30}
]
(* True *)
```

Now we can map `Permutations` over lazy list.

```
lazyIntegerPartitions[5, {3}, Range[0, 5]]
(* « LazyList[{5,0,0},{4,1,0},{3,2,0},{3,1,1},{2,2,1},...] » *)

Permutations /@ %
(* « LazyList[{{5,0,0},{0,5,0},{0,0,5}},{{4,1,0},{4,0,1},{1,4,0},{1,0,4},{0,4,1},{0,1,4}},{{3,2,0},{3,0,2},{2,3,0},{2,0,3},{0,3,2},{0,2,3}},{{3,1,1},{1,3,1},{1,1,3}},{{2,2,1},{2,1,2},{1,2,2}},...] » *)

Scan[Print, %]
(* {{5,0,0},{0,5,0},{0,0,5}}
   {{4,1,0},{4,0,1},{1,4,0},{1,0,4},{0,4,1},{0,1,4}}
   {{3,2,0},{3,0,2},{2,3,0},{2,0,3},{0,3,2},{0,2,3}}
   {{3,1,1},{1,3,1},{1,1,3}}
   {{2,2,1},{2,1,2},{1,2,2}} *)
```

And it works, but since `Permutations` don't accept sequence specification as argument we must generate all permutations at once.
So even if we generate integer partitions in chunks of length 1, we still need to store, at once, in memory *all* permutations of single partition, which quickly becomes to large to fit my memory.

For example in partitions of 12 to 17 elements:

```
lazyIntegerPartitions[12, {17}, Range[0, 12], 1]
(* « LazyList[{12,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},...] » *)
```

Although there are only 77 partitions, which we take one by one:

```
% // Length
(* 77 *)
```

One of them has `4 084 080` permutations, that need to be stored in memory at once:

```
Length /@ Permutations /@ %% // Max
(* 4 084 080 *)
```

That's why for large numbers this solution is not sufficient.

Clean up cache after playing with `` Streaming` ``:

```
Scan[LazyListDestroy, LazyLists[]]
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

## Chunks of weak compositions

Here is slightly modified version of algorithm used in `` Combinatorica`NextComposition `` converted to a `LibraryFunction`.

```
Needs["CCompilerDriver`"]
"
#include \"WolframLibrary.h\"

DLLEXPORT mint WolframLibrary_getVersion() {
    return WolframLibraryVersion;
}
DLLEXPORT int WolframLibrary_initialize(WolframLibraryData libData) {
    return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
}
DLLEXPORT void WolframLibrary_uninitialize(WolframLibraryData libData) {}

DLLEXPORT int nextWeakCompositionsChunk(
        WolframLibraryData libData, mint Argc, MArgument *Args, MArgument Res
) {
    // number which compositions are calculated
    mint n = MArgument_getInteger(Args[0]);

    // length of composition
    mint k = MArgument_getInteger(Args[1]);

    // \" current \" composition tensor
    MTensor compositionT = MArgument_getMTensor(Args[2]);
    // actual data of \" current \" composition
    mint* composition = libData->MTensor_getIntegerData(compositionT);

    // one-dimentional, one-element tensor holding index of last non-zero 
    // element in \"current\" composition
    MTensor lastNonZeroIndexT = MArgument_getMTensor(Args[3]);
    // pointer to index of last non-zero element in \"current\" composition
    mint* lastNonZeroIndex = libData->MTensor_getIntegerData(lastNonZeroIndexT);

    // number of compositions in returned chunk
    mint chunkSize = MArgument_getInteger(Args[4]);

    // dimensions of returned chunk tensor
    mint chunkDims[2] = {chunkSize, k};
    // 2 dimentional tensor with chunk of compositions to be returned
    MTensor chunkT;
    libData->MTensor_new(MType_Integer, 2, chunkDims, &chunkT);
    // actual data of the chunk tensor
    mint* chunk = libData->MTensor_getIntegerData(chunkT);

    // index enumerating compositions in chunk
    mint i;
    // index enumerating elements of composition
    mint j;

    for (i = 0; i < chunkSize; i++) {
        // Moving to next composition does basically this:
        // {..., x, y} -> {..., x+1, y-1} if last element is non-zero,
        // {..., x, y, 0, ..., 0} -> {..., x+1, 0, 0, ..., y-1}
        // if last element is zero and y is last non-zero element.

        ++(composition[*lastNonZeroIndex - 1]);

        if (*lastNonZeroIndex == k -1) {
            --(composition[*lastNonZeroIndex]);
        } else {
            composition[k - 1] = composition[*lastNonZeroIndex] - 1;
            composition[*lastNonZeroIndex] = 0;
        }

        // If last element is zero it means we moved last non-zero element to
        // the left. If last element is non zero, then, obviously, it is the
        // last non-zero element.
        if (composition[k - 1] == 0) {
            --(*lastNonZeroIndex);
        } else {
            *lastNonZeroIndex = k - 1;
        }

        // Copy \"current\" composition to i-th row of chunk.
        for (j = 0; j < k; j++) {
            chunk[i*k + j] = composition[j];
        }
    }

    // Return control over composition and lastNonZeroIndex tensors back to
    // Wolfram Language.
    libData->MTensor_disown(lastNonZeroIndexT);
    libData->MTensor_disown(compositionT);

    // Set chunk tensor as returned value of LibraryFunction.
    MArgument_setMTensor(Res, chunkT);

    return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
}
";
CreateLibrary[%, "weakCompositions"]

ClearAll[nextWeakCompositionsChunk]
nextWeakCompositionsChunk = 
    LibraryFunctionLoad[
        %%, 
        "nextWeakCompositionsChunk",
        {Integer, Integer, {Integer, 1, "Shared"}, {Integer, 1, "Shared"}, Integer},
        {Integer, 2}
    ]
```

It returns chunk of weak `k`-compositions of `n`, in lexicographic order starting from composition after given one.
It accepts 5 arguments: numbers `n` and `k`, list of integers representing "previous" composition, list containing one integer being index (in C sense i.e. starting from 0) of last non-zero element in "previous" composition, last argument is number of compositions in returned chunk.

Besides returning chunk of compositions `nextWeakCompositionsChunk` has a side effect.
"Previous" composition and list containing index of last non-zero element are passed as "Shared" tensors.
They are modified inside `nextWeakCompositionsChunk` function and they stay modified.
For example get 3 weak 4-compositions of 5 starting from one after `{1, 3, 0, 1}`:

```
ClearAll[currentComposition, lastNonZeroIndex]
currentComposition = {1, 3, 0, 1} // Developer`ToPackedArray;
lastNonZeroIndex = {3} // Developer`ToPackedArray;
nextWeakCompositionsChunk[5, 4, currentComposition, lastNonZeroIndex, 3]
(* {{1, 3, 1, 0}, {1, 4, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0, 3}} *)
currentComposition
(* {2, 0, 0, 3} *)
lastNonZeroIndex
(* {3} *)
```

To get first composition we need to pass a fake composition that implemented algorithm will change to the first one.
This "fake one before first composition" is always of form `{0, ..., 0, -1, n+1}`.
For example to get all 10 weak 3-compositions of 3 we use:

```
ClearAll[currentComposition, lastNonZeroIndex]
currentComposition = {0, -1, 4} // Developer`ToPackedArray;
lastNonZeroIndex = {2} // Developer`ToPackedArray;
nextWeakCompositionsChunk[3, 3, currentComposition, lastNonZeroIndex, 10]
(* {{0, 0, 3}, {0, 1, 2}, {0, 2, 1}, {0, 3, 0}, {1, 0, 2}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 0}, {2, 0, 1}, {2, 1, 0}, {3, 0, 0}} *)
currentComposition
(* {3, 0, 0} *)
lastNonZeroIndex
(* {0} *)
```

This is a "low level" function (in package it would be private) that does no tests of consistency of given arguments.
It is intended to be used only through functions defined in next sections.
Passing wrong arguments can result in kernel crash.

## All weak compositions

Using our low level function we can define a function that returns all weak compositions.

```
ClearAll[weakCompositions]
weakCompositions[n_Integer?NonNegative, 0] := {}
weakCompositions[n_Integer?NonNegative, 1] := {{n}}
weakCompositions[n_Integer?NonNegative, k_Integer /; k >= 2] :=
    nextWeakCompositionsChunk[
        n,
        k,
        Join[ConstantArray[0, k - 2], {-1, n + 1}] // Developer`ToPackedArray,
        {k - 1} // Developer`ToPackedArray,
        Binomial[n + k - 1, n]
    ]
```

For example get all weak 3-compositions of 2:

```
weakCompositions[2, 3]
(* {{0, 0, 2}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 2, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0}, {2, 0, 0}} *)
```

Test that we get same output as sorted `Permutations` of `IntegerPartitions`:

```
And @@ Flatten @ Table[
    SameQ[
        weakCompositions[n, k],
        weakCompositionsPermPart[n, k] // Sort
    ],
    {n, 12}, {k, 12}
]
(* True *)
```

`weakCompositions` is faster and more memory efficient than combination of built-ins.

Below are some benchmarks to prove it.

Since `Join`ing of permutations of partitions can double memory usage, and in some cases is not needed, here we use function that doesn't join them.

```
ClearAll[weakCompositionsPermPartNonJoined]
weakCompositionsPermPartNonJoined[n_, k_] :=
    Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[n, {k}, Range[0, n]]
```

Some helper functions:

```
ClearAll[$functionsList, fixedNFunctionsList, fixedKFunctionsList]
$functionsList = {weakCompositionsPermPartNonJoined, weakCompositions};
fixedNFunctionsList[n_] := Function[func, func[n, #] &] /@ $functionsList
fixedKFunctionsList[k_] := Function[func, func[#, k] &] /@ $functionsList
```

We're benchmarking both time and memory usage using my [`timeAndMemoryBenchmarkPlots` function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/90034/14303).

Fixed `n`, variable `k`:

```
timeAndMemoryBenchmarkPlots[fixedNFunctionsList[2], Identity, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 11, 15, 21, 29, 41, 58, 81, 114, 160, 225, 315, 442, 620, 870}, TimeConstraint -> Infinity]
timeAndMemoryBenchmarkPlots[fixedNFunctionsList[8], Identity, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25}, TimeConstraint -> Infinity]
timeAndMemoryBenchmarkPlots[fixedNFunctionsList[32], Identity, Range[8], TimeConstraint -> Infinity]
```

[image: benchmarks weakCompositions fixed n]

Fixed `k`, variable `n`:

```
timeAndMemoryBenchmarkPlots[fixedKFunctionsList[2], Identity, {1, 2, 4, 7, 13, 25, 47, 90, 171, 324, 617, 1172, 2229, 4237, 8054, 15312, 29109, 55338, 105203, 200000}, TimeConstraint -> Infinity]
timeAndMemoryBenchmarkPlots[fixedKFunctionsList[8], Identity, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 22, 25, 28, 32, 36}, TimeConstraint -> Infinity]
timeAndMemoryBenchmarkPlots[fixedKFunctionsList[32], Identity, Range[6], TimeConstraint -> Infinity]
```

[image: benchmarks weakCompositions fixed k]

## Lazy weak compositions

And now the lazy approach:

```
Needs["Streaming`"]

ClearAll[lazyWeakCompositions]

lazyWeakCompositions[
    n_Integer?NonNegative, 0, chunkSize : _Integer?Positive : 10^5,
    opts : OptionsPattern[]
] :=
    LazyListCreate[{}, chunkSize, opts]

lazyWeakCompositions[
    n_Integer?NonNegative, 1, chunkSize : _Integer?Positive : 10^5,
    opts : OptionsPattern[]
] :=
    LazyListCreate[{{n}}, chunkSize, opts]

lazyWeakCompositions[
    n_Integer?NonNegative, k_Integer /; k >= 2,
    chunkSize : _Integer?Positive : 10^5, opts : OptionsPattern[]
] :=
    With[{length = Binomial[n + k - 1, n]},
        Module[
            {
                active = False,
                compositionsLeft = length,
                prevComposition = 
                    Join[ConstantArray[0, k - 2], {-1, n + 1}] // 
                        Developer`ToPackedArray,
                lastNonZeroIndex = {k - 1} // Developer`ToPackedArray
            }
            ,
            LazyListCreate[
                IteratorCreate[
                    ListIterator,
                    (active = True) &,
                    With[{realChunkSize = Min[chunkSize, compositionsLeft]},
                        If[realChunkSize === 0,
                            {}
                        ,(* else *)
                            compositionsLeft -= realChunkSize;
                            nextWeakCompositionsChunk[
                                n, k, prevComposition, lastNonZeroIndex,
                                realChunkSize
                            ]
                        ]
                    ] &,
                    TrueQ[active] &,
                    Remove[
                        active, compositionsLeft,
                        prevComposition, lastNonZeroIndex
                    ] &
                ],
                chunkSize,
                opts,
                "Length" -> length,
                "FiniteList" -> True
            ]
        ]
    ]
```

Again all weak 3-compositions of 2, but this time taken in chunks of 2:

```
lazyWeakCompositions[2, 3, 2]
(* « LazyList[{0,0,2},{0,1,1},...] » *)
Scan[Print, %]
(* {0,0,2}
   {0,1,1}
   {0,2,0}
   {1,0,1}
   {1,1,0}
   {2,0,0} *)
```

Test that `Normal`ized lazy compositions are the same as sorted `Permutations` of `IntegerPartitions`:

```
And @@ Flatten @ Table[
    SameQ[
        lazyWeakCompositions[n, k] // Normal,
        weakCompositionsPermPart[n, k] // Sort
    ],
    {n, 12}, {k, 12}
]
(* True *)
```

We will benchmark scanning of all weak compositions in three ways:

1. All compositions generated at once:

   ```
   ClearAll[scanWeakCompositionsPermPartNonJoined]
   scanWeakCompositionsPermPartNonJoined[n_, k_] :=
       LazyListBlock@Scan[Identity, weakCompositionsPermPartNonJoined[n, k], {2}]
   ```
2. Compositions generated by permuting lazy partitions.
   Partitions are taken one by one, so in single chunk we have all permutations of given partition.

   ```
   ClearAll[lazyWeakCompositionsPermPart, scanLazyWeakCompositionsPermPart]
   lazyWeakCompositionsPermPart[n_, k_] := 
       Permutations /@ lazyIntegerPartitions[n, {k}, Range[0, n], 1]

   scanLazyWeakCompositionsPermPart[n_, k_] :=
       LazyListBlock@Scan[Scan[Identity], lazyWeakCompositionsPermPart[n, k]]
   ```
3. Compositions generated using our `lazyWeakCompositions` function in chunks of default length: 10^5.

   ```
   ClearAll[scanLazyWeakCompositions]
   scanLazyWeakCompositions[n_, k_, chunkSize_: 10^5] :=
       LazyListBlock@Scan[Identity, lazyWeakCompositions[n, k, chunkSize]]
   ```

Since lazy lists cache their values and benchmark measures running time multiple times, we clear cache after each usage, using `LazyListBlock` (as per [comment by Leonid](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/92647/efficient-lazy-weak-compositions/#comment-251966)).

```
$functionsList = {scanWeakCompositionsPermPartNonJoined, scanLazyWeakCompositionsPermPart, scanLazyWeakCompositions};
timeAndMemoryBenchmarkPlots[fixedKFunctionsList[8], Identity, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 14, 16, 18, 21, 24, 28, 32, 37, 42}, TimeConstraint -> Infinity, MemoryConstraint -> 2^31]
timeAndMemoryBenchmarkPlots[fixedKFunctionsList[16], Identity, Range[16], TimeConstraint -> Infinity, MemoryConstraint -> 2^31]
timeAndMemoryBenchmarkPlots[fixedKFunctionsList[32], Identity, Range[8], TimeConstraint -> Infinity, MemoryConstraint -> 2^31]
```

[image: benchmarks lazyWeakCompositions fixed k]

We see that speed for large values is comparable.
Memory usage when generating all compositions at once grows fast.
When using lazy integer partitions memory usage grows slower, but still grows with number of permutations.
When using `lazyWeakCompositions` memory usage grows until it reaches size of one chunk, then it's (almost) constant.

For `k=8` number of permutations per partition is relatively small, so `scanLazyWeakCompositionsPermPart` uses a lot of relatively small chunks, in tested range of `n`. That's why it's considerably slower and it's memory usage increases slowly with `n`.

## C-free version

For those who don't have C compiler here's version using `CompiledFunction` instead of `LibraryFunction`.
It can be compiled to virtual machine.
`weakCompositions` and `lazyWeakCompositions` functions work exactly as above, but are slower and less memory efficient.

```
ClearAll[nextWeakCompositionsChunk]
nextWeakCompositionsChunk = 
    Compile[{{n, _Integer}, {k, _Integer}, {prevComposition, _Integer, 1}, {chunkSize, _Integer}},
        Module[{lastNonZeroPosition = k, composition = prevComposition},
            While[composition[[lastNonZeroPosition]] == 0, --lastNonZeroPosition];
            Table[
                ++composition[[lastNonZeroPosition - 1]];
                If[lastNonZeroPosition == k,
                    --composition[[-1]]
                ,(* else *)
                    composition[[-1]] = composition[[lastNonZeroPosition]] - 1;
                    composition[[lastNonZeroPosition]] = 0
                ];
                If[composition[[-1]] == 0,
                    --lastNonZeroPosition
                ,(* else *)
                    lastNonZeroPosition = k
                ];
                composition
                ,
                chunkSize
            ]
        ],
        RuntimeOptions -> "Speed",
        CompilationTarget -> "WVM"
    ];

ClearAll[weakCompositions]
weakCompositions[n_Integer?NonNegative, 0] := {}
weakCompositions[n_Integer?NonNegative, 1] := {{n}}
weakCompositions[n_Integer?NonNegative, k_Integer /; k >= 2] :=
    nextWeakCompositionsChunk[n, k, Join[ConstantArray[0, k - 2], {-1, n + 1}], Binomial[n + k - 1, n]]


Needs["Streaming`"]

ClearAll[lazyWeakCompositions]
lazyWeakCompositions[n_Integer?NonNegative, 0, chunkSize : _Integer?Positive : 10^5, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := LazyListCreate[{}, chunkSize, opts]
lazyWeakCompositions[n_Integer?NonNegative, 1, chunkSize : _Integer?Positive : 10^5, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := LazyListCreate[{{n}}, chunkSize, opts]
lazyWeakCompositions[n_Integer?NonNegative, k_Integer /; k >= 2, chunkSize : _Integer?Positive : 10^5, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
    With[{length = Binomial[n + k - 1, n]},
        Module[{active = False, compositionsLeft = length, prevComposition = Join[ConstantArray[0, k - 2], {-1, n + 1}]},
            LazyListCreate[
                IteratorCreate[
                    ListIterator,
                    (active = True) &,
                    With[{realChunkSize = Min[chunkSize, compositionsLeft]},
                        If[realChunkSize === 0,
                            {}
                        ,(*else*)
                            compositionsLeft -= realChunkSize;
                            With[{taken = nextWeakCompositionsChunk[n, k, prevComposition, realChunkSize]},
                                prevComposition = Last[taken];
                                taken
                            ]
                        ]
                    ] &,
                    TrueQ[active] &,
                    Remove[active, compositionsLeft, prevComposition] &
                ],
                chunkSize,
                opts,
                "Length" -> length,
                "FiniteList" -> True
            ]
        ]
    ]
```

Comment: Wow. I am impressed. Really. It will take me some time to absorb that. But I will certainly set out the time and do that. Big +1, of course.

Comment: I have to mention, that there are types of chunks called Virtual, for which there is no caching on disk. I did not demonstrate how to use them, and also there seems to be a bug there which I still have to fix, but for example infinite `Range` is built with those. They can be used any time when you can generate chunks purely by calling some function of the chunk index. In the implementation of `LazyTuples`, there is a branch that uses virtual chunks. They might be better suited for this case. I will have to revisit the bug there though.

Comment: Also, while using `DeleteFile@FileNames["*.mx", $StreamingCacheBase]` will indeed delete the chunks from disk, this will leave `Streaming` in an invalid state. The better way is to use something like `Scan[LazyListDestroy, LazyLists[]]`, which should (if the Streaming garbage collector works correctly, which I hope is true) then delete chunks from disk as a part of the lazy list destruction procedure.

Comment: @Leonid thanks. I remember I looked at Virtual chunks once, but something was different than I expected. I can't remember now what it was. I'll have second look at it.

Comment: @Leonid "The better way is to use something like Scan[LazyListDestroy, LazyLists[]]" thanks, I'll use it from now on.

Comment: Virtual chunks have some bug which, for instance, prevents my implementation of `LazyTuples` (Virtual chunk branch of it) to work correctly. I should really fix it, it is good to be reminded about it. As to chunk destruction, I'd also be grateful for reports in cases when some chunks aren't collected using `Scan[LazyListDestroy, LazyLists[]]` code.

Comment: One more tidbit is that if you want to destroy some intermediate `LazyList`s, generated in the process, you can use one of `LazyListBlock`, `LazyListBlockReturn`. The former destroys all `LazyList`s, created inside of it, while the latter keeps the one that is being returned, if it is the value of the code run inside of it, and otherwise works the same as `LazyListBlock`, destroying all the other `LazyList` objects, generated inside of it. There is also `LazyListBlockProtect`, which you can wrap around some `LazyList`s created inside `LazyListBlock`, to protect them from destruction.

Comment: In particular, you should be able to wrap you entire benchmark code in `LazyListBlock`, and then you shouldn't need any explicit chunk cleanup, since (if everything works correctly), all generated `LazyList`s will then be automatically destroyed.

Comment: @Leonid I suspected that best way to learn new Mathematica module is to post some code and let module author point out all mistakes ;)

Comment: I'd say you did an excellent job here, given that you had to dig a lot of things and there is no documentation. In any case, thanks a bunch for such a great non-trivial test of Streaming functionality! It is great to see this stuff being put to use.

Comment: @jkuczm:   Wholeheartedly agree with Leonid's comments. Well done, 100 of my rep on its way to you...

Comment: @ciao Thanks! I appreciate it.

Comment: 100 rep awarded, sorry the bounty did not garner many more votes. Symptomatic, I suppose... again, I appreciate the effort, well done.

Comment: @ciao Thanks once again. I hope people, who have similar problem concerning weak compositions, can find this posts regardless of votes.

Comment: @ciao. Have you heard of [Parkinson's law of triviality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parkinson%27s_law_of_triviality)? I think this is an analogous situation, in the sense that people are more likely to upvote things that they understand. And of course, I'll never understand this post, partially because I'll never have need of weak lazy compositions. Nonetheless, I upvoted after the bounty was posted, because I have a habit of upvoting posts that you post bounties on.