# Create a list of all possible multivariate monomials of a certain order

Tags: list-manipulation, polynomials, expression-construction

Given variables `x[i]` for `i=1,2,...,n` I would like to create a list of all possible multivariate monomials of order `m`. Most conveniently I'd like to have a function `monList[vars_,order_]` such that for example:

```
m=2;
myvar={x[1],x[2]};
monList[myvar,m]
```

> `{1, x[1], x[2], x[1]^2, x[1]x[2], x[2]^2}`

It should also work properly with `m>2` and/or more than two variables `x[i]`.
Is there a function in Mathematica that accomplishes the above? If not, can it be implemented efficiently? Thanks for any suggestion!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`FrobeniusSolve[]` is a very convenient function for this task:

```
monomialList[vars_List, m_Integer?NonNegative] := 
        Flatten[Map[Apply[Times, vars^#] &, 
                    Table[FrobeniusSolve[ConstantArray[1, Length[vars]], k],
                          {k, 0, m}], {2}]]
```

A demonstration:

```
monomialList[{x, y, z, w}, 3]
   {1, w, z, y, x, w^2, w z, z^2, w y, y z, y^2, w x, x z, x y, x^2, w^3, w^2 z,
    w z^2, z^3, w^2 y, w y z, y z^2, w y^2, y^2 z, y^3, w^2 x, w x z, x z^2, w x y,
    x y z, x y^2, w x^2, x^2 z, x^2 y, x^3}
```

A variation using `Inner[]`:

```
monomialList[vars_List, m_Integer?NonNegative] := 
      Flatten[Inner[#2^#1 &, #, vars, Times] & /@ 
              Table[FrobeniusSolve[ConstantArray[1, Length[vars]], k], {k, 0, m}]]
```

Comment: The function `FrobeniusSolve[]` is interesting indeed. Unfortunately, `timeAvg[monomialList[{x[1], x[2], x[3]}, 4]]` returns `0.015000` while my rather trivial implementation below has `timeAvg[monList[{x[1], x[2], x[3]}, 4]]` of `0.000825`.

Comment: Oh, nevermind! at `monomialList[{x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5]}, 30]` your function takes over and becomes two times faster than mine! Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

This is pretty fast.

```
allMonoms[n_, deg_, x_] := 
 List @@ Expand[(1 + Total[Array[x, n]])^deg] /. 
  j_Integer*monom : _ :> monom
```

Quick example:

```
allMonoms[3, 4, x]

(* Out[89]= {1, x[1], x[1]^2, x[1]^3, x[1]^4, x[2], x[1] x[2], 
 x[1]^2 x[2], x[1]^3 x[2], x[2]^2, x[1] x[2]^2, x[1]^2 x[2]^2, x[2]^3,
  x[1] x[2]^3, x[2]^4, x[3], x[1] x[3], x[1]^2 x[3], x[1]^3 x[3], 
 x[2] x[3], x[1] x[2] x[3], x[1]^2 x[2] x[3], x[2]^2 x[3], 
 x[1] x[2]^2 x[3], x[2]^3 x[3], x[3]^2, x[1] x[3]^2, x[1]^2 x[3]^2, 
 x[2] x[3]^2, x[1] x[2] x[3]^2, x[2]^2 x[3]^2, x[3]^3, x[1] x[3]^3, 
 x[2] x[3]^3, x[3]^4} *)
```

Here is a timing test.

```
Timing[mtab = Table[allMonoms[n, d, x], {n, 7}, {d, 14}];]

(* Out[88]= {1.974403, Null} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

To be constructive, here is my own attempt at creating this function:

```
monList[vars_, order_] := Module[{tmp, tmpsub},
  tmp = MonomialList[Sum[(vars /. List -> Plus)^i, {i, 0, order}] // Expand, vars];
  tmpsub = Table[vars[[i]] -> 1, {i, 1, Length[vars]}];
  tmp/(tmp /. tmpsub)
]
```

However, I suspect that the above will become very slow for large orders and when many variables are involved.

Answer (score 3):

Here's something very fast:

```
monoms = Function[{vars, degree}, 
  Times @@@ (vars^# & /@ 
     Flatten[Permutations /@ PadRight[#, {Length@#, Length[vars]}] &[
       Flatten[IntegerPartitions[#, Length[vars]] & /@ Range[0, degree], 
        1]], 1])]

monoms[{x, y, z}, 4]
(* {1, x, y, z, x^2, y^2, z^2, x y, x z, y z, x^3, y^3, z^3, x^2 y, 
 x^2 z, x y^2, x z^2, y^2 z, y z^2, x y z, x^4, y^4, z^4, x^3 y, 
 x^3 z, x y^3, x z^3, y^3 z, y z^3, x^2 y^2, x^2 z^2, y^2 z^2, 
 x^2 y z, x y^2 z, x y z^2} *)

monoms[{x,y,z,q,v},30];//Timing
(* {3.35402, Null} *)
```

The above code is quite fast, but not quite optimal. There's certainly room for improvement. At first I thought, that generating the list of exponents for the variables can be improved, because

```
explist = Function[{vars, degree}, 
  Flatten[Permutations /@ PadRight[#, {Length@#, Length[vars]}] &[
   Flatten[IntegerPartitions[#, Length[vars]] & /@ Range[0, degree], 1]], 1]]
```

generates a rectangular array of integers. Perhaps a compilable version, that creates a packed array could have been coded. This is however not the case, as this is already quite fast and takes a minor part of the total computation time. Also, the array would need to be unpacked in the end anyhow. However I can take advantage of the listability of `Power`:

```
monoms2 = 
 Function[{vars, degree}, 
  With[{explist = 
     Flatten[Permutations /@ PadRight[#, {Length@#, Length[vars]}] &[
        Flatten[IntegerPartitions[#, Length[vars]] & /@ 
          Range[0, degree], 1]], 1] // Transpose}, 
   Times @@@ Transpose[vars^explist]]]
```

`Timing` initially showed a 25% increase, but on further tests the speed-up is not so dramatic.

**Time for some benchmarking!** - *(timings differ, as I'm doing this on a different machine, than last night)*.

For the record, here's generating the list of exponents, and how it chokes on converting this to an array of symbols:

```
explist[{x, y, z, q, v}, 30]; // Timing
(* {0.0936006, Null} *)

explist[{x, y, z, q, v}, 30];
(* Null *)
Transpose[{x, y, z, q, v}^Transpose[%]]; // Timing
(* {0.624004, Null} *)

explist[{x, y, z, q, v}, 30];
(* Null *)
Transpose[{x, y, z, q, v}^Transpose[%]];
(* Null *)
Times @@@ %; // Timing
(* {0.764405, Null} *)
```

And here are the timings for all functions:

```
monoms[{x, y, z, q, v}, 30]; // RepeatedTiming
(* {1.91, Null} *)

monoms2[{x, y, z, q, v}, 30]; // RepeatedTiming
(* {1.81, Null} *) (* turns out, it isn't so much faster *)
```

Heeding the warning of @Kagaratsch I didn't risk running @Bob Hanlon's `monomialList` for such large input and tried a more modest

```
monomialList[{x, y, z, q}, 10]; // Timing
(* {8.06525, Null} *)
```

Kagaratsch's implementation is actually not too bad:

```
monList[{x, y, z, q, v}, 30]; // Timing
(* {9.90606, Null} *)
```

Daniel Lichtblau has a very smart approach, manipulating symbolic stuff right from the start. I'm somewhat surprised, that it's not faster than mine, but very close.

```
allMonoms[5, 30, x]; // RepeatedTiming
(* {2.153, Null} *)
```

J.M's first and second variations (without and with `Inner`), respectively:

```
monomialListJM[{x, y, z, q, v}, 30]; // RepeatedTiming
(* {5.60, Null} *)
monomialListJM2[{x, y, z, q, v}, 30]; // RepeatedTiming
(* {5.58, Null} *)
```

Now there's a to-do, benchmarking memory and timings vs. input size, but I'll leave that to the reader, at least for now.

**Addendum**

I realized, that this problem is similar to finding the entropy (and enumerating every distinct microstate) of `0` to `degree` bosons in a `Length[vars]`-state system. As was established, `explist` is rather fast, and the slow part is multiplying by the variables, `Transpose`ing, and `Apply`ing `Times` to every sublist. Apparently, this is linear in time with respect to the element count (at level 2) of the size of `explist`, so all that's left to find is the length of `explist[vars, degree]`. After realizing the similarity to bosons, this was easy:

```
Length[explist[vars, degree]] == 
  Divide[(1 + degree)*(degree + Length[vars])!,
    Length[vars]*(1 + degree)!*(Length[vars] - 1)!]
```

and the element count is of course `Length[vars]` times that. I then replace the factorials by Stirling's approximation and log-plot the element count vs. `degree` for `Length[vars] == 5`.

[image: complexity]

The timing of the slow part - transpose, apply, etc. is rougly 1 microsecond per element on the same machine, on which I did the benchmarking, so the above curve also represents the timing in microseconds for my method. I'm not sure, how this will translate to the other methods here, that will need some further investigation.

Comment: That reminds me… I first considered using `IntegerPartitions[]`, but the need to apply an extra `Permutations[]`, was why I settled on `FrobeniusSolve[]` instead.

Comment: @J.M. turns out, `Permutations` is actually quite a smart move, because generating the list of exponents for the variables is very fast. I'm editing right now, adding benchmarks and stuff.

Comment: @J.M. well, here's the updated post. I wonder, if you'd have a good idea, how to benchmark space and time complexity vs. input size without this taking an atrociously long time.

Comment: Here's a variation of your strategy: `monoms = Function[{vars, degree}, Inner[#2^#1 &, Flatten[Permutations /@ PadRight[Flatten[Table[IntegerPartitions[k, Length[vars]], {k, 0, degree}], 1], {Automatic, Length[vars]}], 1], vars, Times]]`. As for memory benchmarking, have you seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/78375)?

Comment: @J.M. pretty much the same timing. I understand, how to test memory consumption and timing, what's slightly tougher, is benchmarking how the speed and memory consumed change with changing length of `vars` (extremely rapid growth for timings, by the way, at a glance something like `Exp[Sqrt[x]]`), and the same rate for growing degree, but with a lower constant. Running a proper benchmark will be very time- and memory-consuming. Five datapoints (`Length[vars]==1 thru 5`) is simply not enough to determine the behavior accurately.

Comment: Well, `PartitionsP[]` (the function that gives the length of `IntegerPartitions[]`) is already a fast-growing function, and with the permutations you now have a combinatorial explosion. Hence the gobbling of memory for large numbers of variables.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative

```
monomialList[vars_?VectorQ, 
  order_Integer?
   Positive] := {1, 
    Outer[Times, Sequence @@ ConstantArray[vars, order]]} // Flatten // 
  Union

n = 3; (* number of variables *)

m = 3; (* ordert of monomial *)

myvar = Array[x, n]; (* define variables *)
```

Example

```
monomialList[myvar, m]

(*  {1, x[1]^3, x[1]^2 x[2], x[1] x[2]^2, x[2]^3, x[1]^2 x[3], 
 x[1] x[2] x[3], x[2]^2 x[3], x[1] x[3]^2, x[2] x[3]^2, x[3]^3}  *)
```

Comment: This one instantly crashed my laptop at `n=5` and `m=15`. Don't know what happened. Mouse and keyboard became unresponsive. Had to reset-restart.