# Why the performance of list of Timings depend on the order?

Tags: list-manipulation, timing

It seems that the result of list of `Timing`s and `AbsoluteTiming`s depends on the order, while `RepeatedTiming` is free from this problem. How to understand this behaviour of timing functions?

The related codes are as follows. (The original aim is to compare the performance of similar functions on different types of data.)

### Tested function

```
types = {"integer", "letter", "symbolLetter", "word", "symbolWord"}
functions = {complementVerbatim, Complement}
argnumber = 2;
(*`argnumber` specifies the number of arguments*)

complementVerbatim[list1_List, list2_List] := 
  DeleteCases[list1, Alternatives @@ Verbatim /@ list2];
```

### Sample space

Choose `portion` of the samples as test data and save them into downvalues of `data`.

```
size = 2 10^4;
portion = 0.6;

sampleSpace["integer"] = RandomInteger[2 size, size];
sampleSpace["letter"] = RandomChoice[Alphabet[], size];
sampleSpace["word"] = RandomWord[size];
sampleSpace["symbolLetter"] = ToExpression /@ sampleSpace["letter"];
sampleSpace["symbolWord"] = ToExpression /@ sampleSpace["word"];

Table[data[type, argnumber] = 
   Table[RandomSample[sampleSpace[type], portion size // Floor], {i, argnumber}],
  {type, types}];
```

### Timing

Now evaluate the functions on data with different order and timing functions.

```
Table[timing[Sequence @@ exception] := "/", {exception, exceptions}];

timing[function_, type_, argnumber, timingFunction_] :=
First@timingFunction[function @@ data[type, argnumber];]

timing[abs, fun] = 
  Outer[timing[#1, #2, argnumber, AbsoluteTiming] &, functions, types];
timing[abs, type] = 
  Outer[timing[#2, #1, argnumber, AbsoluteTiming] &, types, functions] // Transpose;

timing[re, fun] = 
  Outer[timing[#1, #2, argnumber, RepeatedTiming] &, functions, types];
timing[re, type] = 
  Outer[timing[#2, #1, argnumber, RepeatedTiming] &, types, functions] // Transpose;

timing[fun] = 
  Outer[timing[#1, #2, argnumber, Timing] &, functions, types];
timing[type] = 
  Outer[timing[#2, #1, argnumber, Timing] &, types, functions] // Transpose;

timingShow[x__] := SparseArray`SparseBlockMatrix[{
    {1, 1} -> {{""}},
    {1, 2} -> {types},
    {2, 1} -> List /@ functions,
    {2, 2} -> timing[x]
}] // TableForm
```

### Result

Interestingly the three timing functions give different results.

The results of `RepeatedTiming` don't depend on the order:

[image]

while the results of `Timing`s and `AbsoluteTiming`s do depend, and they are different from single runs like

```
timing[Complement, "integer", argnumber, Timing]
(*0.011819*)
(*comparing with 0.004266 in the table.*)
```

hence are untrustable.

[image]
[image]

Comment: There is a reason why `timeAvg[]` was invented and then `RepeatedTiming` was added to Mma.  `Timing` is said to be unreliable in a parallelized/hyperthreaded environment because not everything is counted the same on every system. `AbsoluteTiming` measures elapsed time according to the "wall clock" and depends on how busy your computer is.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I'm new here. For `timeAvg[]` do you mean this answer? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/22427/86893

Comment: Yep, and it appears in earlier posts, too. The earliest variant I know is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4168589) (or [better ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4199042)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your table does not show a systematic bias, just random variation. If you run again, then you will get different results. From the documentation:

- "`Timing` is accurate only down to a granularity of at least `$TimeUnit` seconds." See [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Timing.html).
- "`AbsoluteTiming` is always accurate down to a granularity of `$TimeUnit` seconds, but on many systems is much more accurate." See [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AbsoluteTiming.html).

I just evaluated `$TimeUnit` on my machine and got $\frac{1}{100}$, hence I should not expect timings of less than a few tens of milliseconds to be accurate when obtained using `Timing` or `AbsoluteTiming`. Therefore use `RepeatedTiming` if you are anywhere close to `$TimeUnit`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me the `$TimeUnit` issue! I haven't notice that before.

Comment: I set the `size` to 10^7, and indeed the timings above `$TimeUnit`  don't depend on the order of the list anymore. But the timings below `$TimeUnit` are probably not random, since I have run the code many times, and the results are stable.

Comment: Sure. If for your original `size` you expect there is a systematic difference between say `timing[fun]` versus `timing[type]`, and you wanted to really know, then you could run each many (say 100) times, store all the results, then draw a `Histogram` to compare. Or make a proper statistical analysis to see if the difference is statistically significant.