# Drop selection of columns from a ragged array

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning, list-manipulation

I have an application where I need to drop some arbitrary list of columns from a ragged array (where of course the shortest array rows have at least all the specified columns).

E.g., given a ragged list:

```
{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}, 
 {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}}
```

and a column selection of `{1, 3, 5}`, the resulting array after dropping these is

```
{2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {2, 4}, {2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9}, {2, 4, 6, 7, 8}
```

The closest I could find searching here was [How to use “Drop” function to drop matrix' rows and columns in an arbitrary way?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20228/how-to-use-drop-function-to-drop-matrix-rows-and-columns-in-an-arbitrary-way), but that has (nice) solutions for well-formed arrays, while I'm working with ragged arrays of (1000-100000) X (20-2000).

I've tried schemes using unique padding to the length of the longest row, operating, then dropping the padding and found that slow.

I'm currently using:

```
colDropper[array_, cols_] := Module[{s = Split[Sort@cols, #2 == #1 + 1 &]},
  Fold[Drop[#, {}, #2] &, array, (DeleteDuplicates /@ s[[All, {1, -1}]]) - 
     Most@Accumulate@Prepend[Length /@ s, 0]]]
```

which does the job and performs... OK, but there's got to be a way that combines elegance and speed (unfortunately, as with most data I work with, not machine-precision is the usual here so compiling seems out...)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a simple method that seems to be somewhat faster than yours on unpackable data:

```
colDrop[array_, drop_] :=
  Module[{m = array}, m[[All, drop]] = Sequence[]; m]
```

Test:

```
data = Range /@ RandomInteger[{15, 50}, 500000];
data = Map[FromCharacterCode, data + 37, {2}];

colDropper[data, {1, 3, 5, 8, 10, 11}] // Timing // First
colDrop[data, {1, 3, 5, 8, 10, 11}]    // Timing // First
```

> ```
> 1.217
>
> 0.733
> ```

Also worth consideration is a rather direct application of `Delete`:

```
colDrop2[array_, drop_] :=
  Outer[Delete, array, {List /@ drop}, 1]

colDrop2[data, {1, 3, 5, 8, 10, 11}] // Timing // First
```

> ```
> 0.952
> ```

---

#### Update

The timings above were performed in *Mathematica* 7.  In version 10.1.0 the picture is different:

```
colDropper[data, {1, 3, 5, 8, 10, 11}] // RepeatedTiming // First
colDrop[data, {1, 3, 5, 8, 10, 11}]    // RepeatedTiming // First
colDrop2[data, {1, 3, 5, 8, 10, 11}]   // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> ```
> 0.911
>
> 0.752
>
> 1.020
> ```

`colDrop` does manage to hold the edge but it is closer; `colDrop2` is actually slower.

Version 10 also brings a new method; operator forms:

```
Delete[List /@ {1, 3, 5, 8, 10, 11}] /@ data // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> ```
> 0.9402
> ```

That is slower than the original but faster than the non-operator-form version:

```
Delete[#, {{1}, {3}, {5}, {8}, {10}, {11}}] & /@ data // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> ```
> 1.032
> ```

Comment: Pretty cool. It didn't come to my mind that the 2D `All` spec would work, but in hindsight this is logical. +1.

Comment: Ok, this is clearly the winner. Deleting mine, since this one uses the same idea, but does it right.

Comment: @Leonid Thanks for the correction.  I have hope that you will find another method worthy of posting; you rarely fail. :-)

Comment: I doubt there is a simpler one in this case.

Comment: I should've made a test for unpacable data :( +1 :)

Comment: Yep, tried these (well, similar incarnations) early on. On my tests (100K X 50-200, unpacked), colDrop takes ~4X longer, colDrop2 ~5X longer with column drops of `{2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16` (the sensor data tends to get dropped in clumps). With packed arrays, these numbers about double. Puzzling, I'd guess your version of *Mathematica* might explain differing results. As always, thanks for reply and a big fat +1 for taking the time.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: It appears for my use case, the ugly OP method holds an edge (would be nice if some future MM had such a capability built-in, but unlikely since it's a somewhat strange construct). In any case accept for the nice answer and work done. Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: @rasher Thanks, but please don't feel obliged to Accept simply because of the effort, though thanks is appreciated.  I too wish for a future extension that handles this case natively.