# How to edit a list according to the other list?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

Gday guys. This problem troubles me, and I hope you can help me solve it.

Say I have two random lists

```
L1={{2},{5},{1},{0},{4},{7},{8}}
L2={2,5,1,0,4,7,8}
```

and also a list

```
L3={3,5}
```

the list L3 means I don't want the elements in L1 at row 3 and 5, and elements in L2 at column 3 and 5. So I would like the results to come up like

```
resultsL1={{2},{5},{0},{7},{8}}
resultsL2={2,5,0,7,8}
```

I know how to use Delete or Drop to get rid of the row/column one by one, but I want an automatic way to do this job because the elements in L3 can have different elements and become any number in my original code. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Also see: [(43785)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43785/121)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways but the one I like is the following:

If L1 and L2 have same length then:

```
index = Complement[Range[Length[L1]], L3];
L1[[index]]
(*{{2}, {5}, {0}, {7}, {8}}*)
L2[[index]]
(*{2, 5, 0, 7, 8}*)
```

Comment: Thank you Algohi. It works perfectly!

Comment: My pleasure :).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    Delete[L1, {#} & /@ L3]
Delete[L2, {#} & /@ L3]

(*  {{2}, {5}, {0}, {7}, {8}}  *)

(*   {2, 5, 0, 7, 8}          *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: Nice! Thanks Alexi!