# `Part` like `Delete`: How to delete list of columns or arbitrarily deeper levels

Tags: list-manipulation

On trying to write [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/108310/10397) I reached the frustrating realization that I didn't have an efficient way to delete a list of columns or deeper level components in a simple way as [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) gives.

Given

```
MatrixForm[m = Partition[Partition[Range[4 4 3], 3], 4]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I can [`Delete`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Delete.html) rows `{2,3}` by

```
Delete[m, List /@ {2, 3}] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But to delete the columns or deeper levels I would need to [`Transpose`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose.html) twice. For instance using something like this

```
rDelete[m_, row_, col_] := Delete[
  Transpose[
   Delete[
    Transpose[m]
    , List /@ col
    ]
   ], List /@ row
  ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

On the other hand to get a [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) at any level I can easily use

```
Part[m, All, {1, 4}, {2, 3}] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Unfortunately, `All` and `Span` are not available for `Delete`.

**Question:
How can we delete columns or whole higher levels elegantly and efficiently, as we do with `Part`?**

Comment: This removes the second "column" of `m`: `Drop[m, None, {2}, None]`. `Drop[m, None, None, {2}]` gives the complement of your `Part[]` example. You can judiciously combine this with `Map[]`/`MapAt[]` if you need to do several positions, since unlike `Delete[]`, `Drop[]` can only remove from either a single dimension or a range of dimensions.

Comment: @J.M.  I guess the problem with `Drop` is the fact that you need to `Map` over the list of indexes to delete, as you say.

Comment: Also: [(43785)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43785/121)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can actually use `Part` for that:

```
ClearAll[delete];
delete[expr_, specs___] :=
  Module[{copy = expr},
    copy[[specs]] = Sequence[];
    copy
  ];
```

So that for example

```
delete[m, All, All, 2]

(* 
   {
     {{1, 3}, {4, 6}, {7, 9}, {10, 12}}, 
     {{13, 15}, {16, 18}, {19, 21}, {22, 24}}, 
     {{25, 27}, {28, 30}, {31, 33}, {34, 36}}, 
     {{37, 39}, {40, 42}, {43, 45}, {46, 48}}
   }
*)
```

Note that this is not exactly equivalent to `Delete` in all cases, since sequence splicing is an evaluation-time effect, so the results will be different if you delete inside held expressions - in which case the method I suggested may not work.

Here is a version that would probably be free of the mentioned flaw, but will be slower:

```
ClearAll[deleteAlt];
deleteAlt[expr_, specs___] :=
  Module[{copy = Hold[expr], tag},
    copy[[1, specs]] = tag;
    ReleaseHold@Delete[copy, Position[copy, tag]]
  ];
```

You can test both on say, `Hold[Evaluate[m]]`, with the spec `1, All, All, 2`, to see the difference.

Comment: This opens for me a whole a new understanding of `Sequence`. Very clever! +1

Comment: The `Sequence[]` is replaceable with `Nothing` in version 10.2, I suppose. Speaking of which: `MapAt[Nothing, m, {All, All, 2}]`.

Comment: @J.M. I am aware of  `Nothing`, but haven't yet gained extensive experience with it, unlike with  `Sequence`. As to `MapAt`, this is a possibility, but it was known to have efficiency issues in the past, for large number of positions mapped. I didn't have the time to check it now, so I didn't go that way - for in-place assignments with `Part`, it has been known that it has excellent efficiency in all cases.

Comment: @rhermans Glad it helped.

Comment: It works well for a list at a single level. The output of using list at more than one level is not exactly what I had in mind, but this is already better than my own solution. Example  `delete[m, All, {2, 3}, {1, 3}]`

Comment: @rhermans I tested `delete[m, All, {2, 3}, {1, 3}]`, and the result looks logical to me: from all first-level elements (sub-matrices), delete columns `1` and `3` from rows `2` and `3`. The resulting first-level elements are, of course, no longer matrices (rectangular arrays). What result did you expect from this code?

Comment: I don't want to move the goalpost, I'm grateful for your answer and the code is unambiguous. What I was expecting (naively?) is deleted columns, rows and higher orders all across the array, like in my example with `rDelete`, where all the elements have the same length. But this already solves most of what I wanted nicely.

Comment: @rhermans This is then different semantics. Here is a version that works that way: `ClearAll[delete2];delete2[expr_, part_, rest___] :=Module[{copy = expr}, copy[[part]] = Sequence[];Map[delete2[#, rest] &, copy]]; delete2[expr_] := expr;`. But it won't be as efficient as the ones I posted before.

Answer (score 10):

You may use `ReplacePart` and `Nothing` with `Blank` (`_`) for `All`.

Delete second entry of all submatrices

```
ReplacePart[m, {_, _, 2} -> Nothing] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Delete last column

```
ReplacePart[m, {_, -1} -> Nothing] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

and so on.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, it does partially. How do you deal with list of columns to delete?

Comment: @rhermans `Alternatives` : `ReplacePart[m, {_, 2 | 3} -> Nothing] // MatrixForm`.