# Looking for a better way to delete an arbitrary list of rows from a matrix

Tags: list-manipulation

`Delete` is not suitable to delete the rows of a matrix, as illustrated below:

```
  SeedRandom[0];
; r = 100
; rows = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {r, 2}]
; toDrop = Select[Range[r], PrimeQ]
; reducedRows = Delete[rows, toDrop]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I know that I can always do something like

```
  toKeep = Complement[Range[r], toDrop]
; reducedRows = rows[[toKeep]]
```

...but this strikes me as inefficient, at least whenever `toKeep` is large (IOW, whenever `r` is much greater than `Length[toDrop]`).

Is there any other built-in that achieves what `Delete[rows, toDrop]` aspires to?

Comment: `toDrop = Transpose[{Select[Range[r], PrimeQ]}]`

Comment: Have you tried `Delete[rows, List /@ toDrop]`?

Comment: Despite acknowledgement of `Complement` I feel that this problem is already described in other questions: [(17002)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17002/121), [(20228)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20228/121),
[(43785)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43785/121),
[(108336)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/108336/121).  Note that the answers below largely duplicate methods already given in answer to these.  I shall probably mark this as a duplicate unless someone makes a compelling argument against that.

Comment: Also related (StackOverflow): [Efficient way to pick/delete a list of rows/columns in a matrix in Mathematica](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5300892/499167)

Comment: @J.M.: Would you kindly post your comment as an answer?

Comment: It's already incorporated in kglr's answer; please vote for his instead.

Comment: @J.M.: OK, will do.  Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make the to-be-dropped rows vanish:

```
rows[[toDrop]] = ##&[]
```

or as a function:

```
f = Module[{m = #, d = #2}, m[[d]] = ##&[]; m] &;

f[rows, toDrop]
```

**Some timings**

```
ClearAll[f0, f1, f2, f3, f4, f5]
f0 = ReplacePart[#, Transpose[{#2}] -> Nothing[]]&; (* ciao's answer *)
f1 = ReplacePart[#, Thread[#2 -> Sequence[]]] &; (* v9 version of ciao's answer*)
f2 = Module[{m = #, d = #2}, m[[d]] = ## &[]; m] &;
f3 = #[[Complement[Range@Length@#, #2]]] &; (* from george2079's deleted answer*)
f4 = Delete[#, Transpose[{#2}]] &; (* from ciao's comment *)
f5 = Delete[#, List /@ #2] &; (* from J.M.'s comment *)


SeedRandom[0];
r = 1000000;
rows = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {r, 2}];
toDrop = Select[Range[r], PrimeQ];
{HoldForm[#], First[AbsoluteTiming[#[rows, toDrop]]]} & /@ {f0, f1, f2, f3, f4, f5} // Grid
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Equal @@ (#[rows, toDrop] & /@ {f0, f1, f2, f3, f4, f5})
```

> True

Answer (score 10):

Probably the simplest way will be:

```
reducedRows = ReplacePart[rows, Transpose[{toDrop}] -> Nothing[]]
```

Comment: I believe you need to do `List /@ toDrop -> Nothing[]`.  (Cant verify with 10.1 though)

Comment: @george2079 - oops, copied wrong - fixed (Transpose faster than map List)

Comment: (+1) because I've learned `Nothing`.

Comment: I didn't know Nothing as well, I was using ##&[] instead. I'll do a find and replace in all my code !

Comment: I fixed the Transpose correction. Also you don't need Nothing[], Nothing only works.

Answer (score 2):

A solution that keeps instead of drops.

```
toKeep = Select[Range[r], PrimeQ /* Not];
reducedRows = rows[[toKeep]];
```

Hope this helps.