# Adding extra column to an existing table

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose I have following table-

```
 1   5   8
 2   6   9
 3   7   10
 0   0   0
```

Now, I want to add another column by exporting a data file. Suppose contents of that data file are-

```
 11
 12
 13
 54
```

I want to merge these two tables to look something like-

```
 1   5   8    11
 2   6   9    12
 3   7   10   13
```

I want to delete that row where elements of first table are all zero. I tried `Join` command but It is not working.

Comment: `Transpose` the table, `Append` the new row, `Transpose` back, and `Drop` the last row ?

Comment: I think this question was asked and answered many times before. I'm linking topics where you can find those answers. Let me know if you disagree. Also related: [20228](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20228/5478), [108336](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/108336/5478)

Comment: m1 = {{1, 5, 8}, {2, 6, 9}, {3, 7, 10}, {0, 0, 0}};
    m2 = {11, 12, 13, 54};
    Most@MapThread[Append, {m1, m2}]

Answer (score 2):

one way might be

```
 (mat = {{1, 5, 8}, {2, 6, 9}, {3, 7, 10}, {0, 0, 0}}) // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 mat = Insert[Transpose[mat], {11, 12, 13, 54}, -1];
 (mat = Transpose[mat]) // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
  (mat=DeleteCases[mat, {0, 0, 0, _}]) // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

```
a = Table[i + j*i, {i, 1, 4}, {j, 1, 3}];

2   3   4
4   6   8
6   9   12
8   12  16


b = Transpose@Join[Transpose@a, {{1, 1, 1, 1}}]

2   3   4   1
4   6   8   1
6   9   12  1
8   12  16  1
```