# Matrix manipulation

Tags: matrix

Thank you for looking and answering this question. I am trying to create a new matrix from an old one. Meaning, I have a original matrix that's 20x20. I want to keep the first five lines of the matrix, then from line 6-10 I want to take every other line, meaning line 7 and 9 would be deleted, but also column 7 and 9 need to be deleted. Then from line 11-20, I want to take every 3 lines, so the rows and columns need to be deleted accordingly.

Comment: Closely related: [(20228)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20228)

Answer (score 7):

I'll use this example matrix:

```
matrix = Table[i + j, {i, 20}, {j, 0, 19}]
```

Please take a look at it. You'll notice that the top row has the elements 1-20 and that the leftmost column as has those as well. Now let's create a list of the columns/rows that you want to keep:

```
keep = Join[Range[5], Range[6, 10, 2], Range[11, 20, 3]]
(* Out: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 11, 14, 17, 20} *)
```

Then:

```
matrix[[keep, keep]]
```

This results in the matrix below (visualized with `MatrixForm`):

[image: Final matrix]

Comment: After your last edit +1 `matrix[[keep, keep]]` is very elegant

Comment: Ditto. Never seen `Part` used like that before. +1.

Comment: @seismatica Have a look at this: [(20228)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20228) -- Pickett: +1 on a clean answer. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks!

Comment: thanks for the ideas, the problem is that the matrix is going to be growing, and I need a systematic way to only take every 10th row, therefore I will have to delete a lot more rows and columns then in this 20x20 example.

Comment: @user2558894 I don't see the problem; the same approach should work.

Answer (score 1):

producing some random data

```
data = RandomInteger[100, {20, 20}]
```

If I understood well, you mean

```
data[[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 11, 14, 17, 20}]] // Transpose // 
  Part[#, Range@20~Complement~{7, 9}] & // Transpose
```

Answer (score 1):

In other cases (few deletions) one could also consider `Delete`:

```
m = Partition[Range[400], 20];

del = {{7}, {9}, {12}, {13}, {15}, {16}, {18}, {19}};

m // Delete[del] // Transpose // Delete[del] // Transpose // MatrixForm
```

[image]