# List manipulation: Dropping first or last row or column of a matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

How do I drop the first/last row or first/last column from a matrix?  The general case is answered [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20228/how-to-use-drop-function-to-drop-matrix-rows-and-columns-in-an-arbitrary-way) but I am new to Mathematica and it the arbitrary case is unnecessarily complex.

Suppose I am dealing with a 4 by 4 square matrix such as

```
m = Array[Subscript[a, ##] &, {4, 4}]
```

and would like to delete the first and last rows as well as columns.

This may involve a simple application of the drop function I reckon. I would appreciate a very barebones example.

Comment: There are some nice tutorials about linear algebra in Mma. http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/MatricesAndLinearAlgebra.html Look under "Learning Resources". Delete[m, 1] removes the first row from a matrix m. Delete[m, -1] removes the final row. Transpose the matrix to do the same things to columns.

Comment: I have marked this question as a duplicate.  (See the link inserted at the top of your question.)  Please review it, and if you feel your question is *not* answered there edit this question to explain why.

Comment: Bare bones example. Given m = Array[a[#1, #2] &, {4, 4}] , dropping the first row, first column, last row, and last column from m can done with Drop[m, {1, 4, 3}, {1, 4, 3}] giving {{a[2, 2], a[2, 3]}, {a[3, 2], a[3, 3]}}.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard thanks so much for looking after these questions. I have edited this question slightly to ensure it is no longer a duplicate but asking for a barebones example instead.

Comment: If you specifically want to know how to drop first / last rows and columns, the general case linked by @Mr.Wizard is heavy going.  I suggest Most@m
Most /@ m
Rest@m
Rest /@ m  (I was surprised when Wolfram added Most and Rest to the language, because the general case was already available, but I find them very useful and much more readable.)

Comment: Yes, I agree it is pretty hard-going. Thank you so much for your suggestion @djp !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Okay, following the "bare bones" approach for dropping rows and columns here are a few ideas.

Starting matrix:

```
m = Array[Times, {5, 6}]
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccc}
>  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
>  2 & 4 & 6 & 8 & 10 \\
>  3 & 6 & 9 & 12 & 15 \\
>  4 & 8 & 12 & 16 & 20 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

### Part

When possible I use [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html):

1. Highly efficient
2. Can select (or drop) rows and columns at the same time
3. Common syntax that will be useful for [other operations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3077/121)

To "delete the last row and first column" we can use:

```
m[[;; -2, 2 ;;]]
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
>  4 & 6 & 8 & 10 \\
>  6 & 9 & 12 & 15 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

This uses [`Span`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Span.html).  The specification for `Part` is in the order of rows, then columns, as this is how *Mathematica* arrays are composed.  The first specification is:

```
;; -2
```

This is shorthand for `1 ;; -2` which means elements one through two from the end.

The second specification is:

```
2 ;;
```

This is shorthand for `2 ;; All` which means elements two through the end.

For an abstraction of `Part` to simultaneously delete arbitrary rows and columns see:

- [How to use "Drop" function to drop matrix' rows and columns in an arbitrary way?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20228/how-to-use-drop-function-to-drop-matrix-rows-and-columns-in-an-arbitrary-way)

### Drop

`Drop`, while not capable of deleting arbitrary rows (or with effort, columns) like `Delete`, can accept an interval parameter (as can `Part` by way of `Span`) to e.g. drop every other element, and it can operate on rows and columns simultaneously like `Part`.  An example of both:

```
Drop[m, None, {1, -1, 2}]
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  2 & 4 \\
>  4 & 8 \\
>  6 & 12 \\
>  8 & 16 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

For the question application "delete the last row and first column" it is very concise:

```
Drop[m, -1, 1]
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
>  4 & 6 & 8 & 10 \\
>  6 & 9 & 12 & 15 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

### Delete

You can also use [`Delete`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Delete.html) in many cases, however `Delete` does not support [`All`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/All.html) like `Part` does which makes it less efficient for column operations, as as one must either [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) the function or [`Transpose`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose.html) the array.

```
Delete[#, 1] & /@ Delete[m, -1]
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
>  4 & 6 & 8 & 10 \\
>  6 & 9 & 12 & 15 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

```
Delete[Delete[m, -1]\[Transpose], 1]\[Transpose]
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
>  4 & 6 & 8 & 10 \\
>  6 & 9 & 12 & 15 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

However unlike `Drop` it is not limited to starting, trailing, or evenly spaced elements and allow for e.g.:

```
Delete[m, {{1}, {3}}]
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccc}
>  2 & 4 & 6 & 8 & 10 \\
>  4 & 8 & 12 & 16 & 20 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

When you wish to work with columns it is easier and more efficient to use the `Part` abstraction referenced earlier.

Answer (score 5):

A barebones example for the desired cropping is:

```
m = Array[Subscript[a, ##] &, {4, 4}];
MatrixForm[m]
```

> $$\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,4} \\
>  a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & a_{2,3} & a_{2,4} \\
>  a_{3,1} & a_{3,2} & a_{3,3} & a_{3,4} \\
>  a_{4,1} & a_{4,2} & a_{4,3} & a_{4,4} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$$

```
ArrayPad[m, {{0, -1}, {-1, 0}}]
```

> $$\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  a_{1,2} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,4} \\
>  a_{2,2} & a_{2,3} & a_{2,4} \\
>  a_{3,2} & a_{3,3} & a_{3,4} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$$

Here, I use the fact that [`ArrayPad`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ArrayPad.html) permits zero or negative values of the padding, so one can use it to shrink matrices arbitrarily on all sides.

Also, slick way to do the cropping on all sides of a matrix is this:

```
ArrayPad[m, -1]
```

> $$\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  a_{2,2} & a_{2,3} \\
>  a_{3,2} & a_{3,3} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$$

Answer (score 5):

Seeing you asked about how to drop the first or last rows/columns, you can do that conveniently with **Most** and **Rest**:

```
Most@m (* drops last row *)
Most/@m (* drops last column *)
Rest@m (* drops first row *)
Rest/@m (* drops first column *)
```