# Inverse of ArrayPad operation, or removal of first column and first row of matrix

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation, padding

I have some large matrices, which I need to remove the first row and first column (both of which are full of zeroes). In this sense I need the inverse of "ArrayPad".

For example, consider the matrix:

```
A = {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 2, 3}, {0, 4, 5, 6} , {0, 7, 8, 9}}
A // MatrixForm
```

I would like an operation to reduce it to

```
Anew =  {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6} , {7, 8, 9}}
Anew // MatrixForm
```

I need general recipe for such operation for to go from (N+1) by (N+1) matrix to N by N matrix by removing the first column of zeroes and first row of zeroes.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: A[[2;;,2;;]]  15char

Comment: `f=Drop[#,1]&` drops the first element of a list.  `f=Drop[#,-1]&` drops the last. `f[A]` removes rows. `f/@A` removes columns.

Comment: This question is answered in: [(17002)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17002/121),
[(20228)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20228/121),
[(76109)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/76109/121)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Rest` is the built-in function for removing the first element from a list, so given

```
m = {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 2, 3}, {0, 4, 5, 6}, {0, 7, 8, 9}};
```

then

```
Rest[Rest /@ m]
```

produces

> `{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}`

as does

```
Rest /@ Rest[m]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
m0 =  {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
m1 = ArrayPad[m0, {{1,0},{1,0}}]
```

> {{0,0,0,0}, {0,1,2,3},{0,4,5,6},{0, 7,8,9}}

```
m2 = ArrayPad[m1, -{{1,0},{1, 0}}]
```

> {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}

Comment: Weird! Probably the closest fit to the description "inverse of ArrayPad" here.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `[[ ]]` notation, which is backed by `Part`. You just need to start from an index of 2. i.e.

```
A[[2 ;;, 2 ;;]]
```

For example, if we have a matrix `x` given by

```
x = Table[j + 4 i + 1, {i, 0, 3}, {j, 0, 3}];
x // MatrixForm
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Then the operation

```
x[[2 ;;, 2 ;;]]
```

gives

```
% // MatrixForm
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 6 & 7 & 8 \\
 10 & 11 & 12 \\
 14 & 15 & 16 \\
\end{array}
\right)$