# Summing along rows or columns of a matrix

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of rows in database such as

```
{{a,b,c}, {d,e,f},{g,h,i}}
```

I want to be able to add each row across and each column down (like a spreadsheet).
In other words be able to pick columns and rows and add down or across.
Could you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 26):

Use `Total` with the appropriate second argument to sum the matrix along rows/columns.

#### Sum along rows:

```
m = {{a,b,c}, {d,e,f},{g,h,i}};
Total[m, {1}]
(* {a + d + g, b + e + h, c + f + i} *)
```

By default, `Total[m]` (without a second argument) sums along the rows.

#### Sum along columns

```
Total[m, {2}]
(* {a + b + c, d + e + f, g + h + i} *)
```

Comment: I will never know what "along columns" and "along rows" mean. I would have guessed the opposite.

Comment: Thanks! The hard part of Mathematica is knowing the commands!

Comment: In the second case, a true mathematician would've transposed the matrix and exultantly said ...

Comment: I think you may have confused rows and columns. By default `Total` sum along the columns.

Comment: @MrAlpha I guess it depends on what one means by "along the columns". As with Rojo, I can never seem to remember what the right/current/popular interpretation is, but since this is binary, just flip it accordingly :)

Answer (score 7):

You could get both the row and column sums at once with a simple function:

```
rowColSum[m_?MatrixQ] := {Plus @@@ m, Plus @@@ Transpose@m}

m = ArrayReshape[Range@6, {2, 3}]
```

> {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}

```
rowColSum@m
```

> {{6, 15}, {5, 7, 9}}

If you were interested in getting spreadsheet-like output, you could do it this way:

```
tabulate[m_?MatrixQ] := Module[{rs, cs},
  rs = Plus @@@ m;
  cs = Append[Plus @@@ Transpose@m, ""];
  Append[MapThread[Append, {m, rs}], cs]]

tabulate@m // TableForm
```

[image]

#### Update

I would like to satisfy Mr.Wizard's request for color, but his specifications were rather vague. I hope the following will satisfy him.

```
colorPattern = (_RGBColor | _GrayLevel | _Hue);

wizardStyleTabulate[m_?MatrixQ,
                    dataColor : colorPattern : Black, 
                    sumColor : colorPattern : Blue] :=
Module[{data, rs, cs},
  data = Map[Style[#, dataColor] &, m, {-1}];
  rs = Style[#, sumColor] & /@ Plus @@@ m;
  cs = Style[#, sumColor] & /@ Append[Plus @@@ Transpose@m, ""];
  Append[MapThread[Append, {data, rs}], cs]]    

m // wizardStyleTabulate // TableForm
```

[image: default-styled-image]

```
wizardStyleTabulate[m, Red, Hue[0.55]] // TableForm
```

[image: styled-image]

Comment: Add colors to the output (so that the numerals are not all black) and you'll get my vote.

Comment: Absolutely satisfied.  Belated +1!

Answer (score 6):

```
 m = {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {g, h, i}};
```

**Update:** `Tr`

```
Tr /@ (m\[Transpose])       (* column sums *)
Tr[m, Plus, 1]              (* column sums *)
Tr/@m                       (* row sums    *)
Tr[m\[Transpose], Plus, 1]  (* row sums    *)
```

---

**Column sums**

```
Total@m 
Plus @@ m 
Fold[Plus, First@m, Rest@m]
ConstantArray[1, 3].m 
Flatten@ListConvolve[{ConstantArray[1, 3]}, Transpose@m]
(* {a+d+g, b+e+h, c+f+i} *)
```

**Row sums**

```
Total /@ m
Plus @@@ m
Fold[Plus, First@#, Rest@#] &[Transpose@m]
m.ConstantArray[1, 3]
Flatten@ListConvolve[{ConstantArray[1, 3]}, m]
(* {a+b+c, d+e+f, g+h+i} *)
```

Comment: How do you pick only one column or row?

Comment: @DavidKerr, `Total@m[[2]] (* sum of row 2 *)`,  `Total@m[[All, 2]] (* sum of column 2 *)`, and `Total@m[[All, {2, 3}]] (* sum of column 2 and sum of column 3*)` ...

Answer (score 4):

Here are undocumented internal functions for the tasks, which are efficient on numeric arrays.

Packed:

```
mat = RandomReal[1, {300000, 200}];                           (* rows >> columns *)
Statistics`Library`MatrixColumnSum[mat]; // RepeatedTiming
Total[mat]; // RepeatedTiming

Statistics`Library`MatrixRowSum[mat]; // RepeatedTiming
Total[mat, {2}]; // RepeatedTiming
(*
  {0.038, Null}
  {0.213, Null}

  {0.025, Null}
  {0.061, Null}
*)

mat = RandomReal[1, {300, 200000}];                           (* columns >> rows *)
Statistics`Library`MatrixColumnSum[mat]; // RepeatedTiming
Total[mat]; // RepeatedTiming

Statistics`Library`MatrixRowSum[mat]; // RepeatedTiming
Total[mat, {2}]; // RepeatedTiming
(*
  {0.029, Null}
  {0.132, Null}

  {0.0266, Null}
  {0.0287, Null}
*)
```

Unpacked:

```
mat = Developer`FromPackedArray@RandomReal[1, {30000, 200}];  (* rows >> columns *)
Statistics`Library`MatrixColumnSum[mat]; // RepeatedTiming
Total[mat]; // RepeatedTiming

Statistics`Library`MatrixRowSum[mat]; // RepeatedTiming
Total[mat, {2}]; // RepeatedTiming
(*
  {0.062, Null}
  {1.6, Null}     <-- For real???

  {0.047, Null}
  {0.649, Null}
*)

mat = Developer`FromPackedArray@RandomReal[1, {300, 20000}];  (* columns >> rows *)
Statistics`Library`MatrixColumnSum[mat]; // RepeatedTiming
Total[mat]; // RepeatedTiming

Statistics`Library`MatrixRowSum[mat]; // RepeatedTiming
Total[mat, {2}]; // RepeatedTiming
(*
  {0.065, Null}
  {0.079, Null}

  {0.0445, Null}
  {0.625, Null}
*)
```

Comment: Using dot product is also very efficient: `ConstantArray[1,Length[mat]].mat;//AbsoluteTiming

mat.ConstantArray[1,Length[mat[[1]]]];//AbsoluteTiming`

Answer (score 3):

Since V 12.2 we have `ArrayReduce`

From the documentation:

*"Array reduction, also called array aggregation, is used to compute functions such as Mean, Total or StandardDeviation along specific dimensions of an array."*

```
mat =
  {{a, b, c},
   {d, e, f},
   {g, h, i}};
```

**1. Apply a function along rows**

```
ArrayReduce[f, mat, 2]
```

gives

```
{f[{a, b, c}],
 f[{d, e, f}],
 f[{g, h, i}]}
```

This corresponds to

```
ArrayReduce[Total, mat, 2] == Total[mat, {2}]
```

(* True *)

and

```
f /@ mat == ArrayReduce[f, mat, 2]
```

(* True *)

**2. Apply a function along columns**

```
ArrayReduce[f, mat, 1]

{f[{a, d, g}], 
 f[{b, e, h}], 
 f[{c, f, i}]}
```

This replaces `Map` and `Transpose`:

```
ArrayReduce[f, mat, 1] == Map[f] @ Transpose[mat]
```

(* True *)

**3. AggregationLayer**

For deeply nested lists we have
[AggregationLayer](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AggregationLayer.html), for which I gave some examples here:

[Elegant operations on matrix rows and columns](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3069/elegant-operations-on-matrix-rows-and-columns/291888#291888)