# Convenient methods to sum select rows (or cols) of a matrix?

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation

What are some convenient methods to sum selected rows or columns in a matrix? This question [Summing along rows or columns of a matrix](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18540/summing-along-rows-or-columns-of-a-matrix) only addresses how to sun entire rows or columns ie, by level.

For example, suppose one wants to add columns 2 and 4 of:

```
M = Column@Table[RandomInteger[10], {3}, {4}];
```

Neither MapAt, nor ReplacePart appear useful in this regard.

Of course `#[[2]] + #[[4]] & /@ M` works for summing columns and `Transpose` can be used for rows, but that seems like a hack to specify using such syntax. Any better solutions?

Comment: Duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3069/5

Comment: @rm-rf Just a bureaucratic note ;) In this question the output is a single list. In the one you linked - the whole matrix. This is if I understood OP correctly.

Answer (score 3):

To add rows 1 and 3:

```
Total@M[[{1, 3}]]
```

To add columns 2 and 4:

```
Total /@ M[[All, {2, 4}]]
```

or

```
Total[M[[All, {2, 4}]], {2}] (* Thx to Mike's coment *)
```

This works with arbitrary number of specific rows and columns. I guess the main point here is being able to specify the specific columns and rows as a list and not as something spread out over different terms and sets of [[...]].

Comment: No need to Map: `Total[m[[All, {2, 4}]], {2}]`

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch True. I just liked the uniform look of it ;) I'll put it in.

Answer (score 2):

You can dimension matrix with `RandomInteger`.

```
m = RandomInteger[10, {3, 4}]
```

Adding second column to fourth.

```
m[[All, 2]] + m[[All, 4]]
```