# Summing over a range of columns of a table

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I  have a Table of dimension (49,702). I want to sum over the column values ranging from 1 to 115 and store it in another table of dimension (49,1). How can I go about doing that? TIA

```
DataPCorrected1 = 
 Table[1 + DataPCorrected[[j, i]], {j, 1, 49}, {i, 1, 115}];
```

> In short, At each row value from 1 to 49, the column values from 1 to 115 gets added and stored. The final result should be a list of dimension {49,1}

Comment: Please show the code you have tried and describe the difficulties you have encountered.

Comment: And explain what you mean by "sum over the column values ranging from 5 to 115".

Comment: Just did that. Please check. thanks. At each row value from 1 to 49, the column values from 1 to 115 gets added and stored. The final result should be a list of dimension {49,1}

Comment: Welcome to the community. I think this is what your looking for `Total[DataPCorrected[[All, 1 ;; 115]], {2}]`

Comment: Thanks, it worked @Ben Izd

Comment: Also, perhaps, `DataPCorrected[[All, 1 ;; 115]].ConstantArray[1,115]`?

Comment: Duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22624/convenient-methods-to-sum-select-rows-or-cols-of-a-matrix/22625#22625 -- Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18540/summing-along-rows-or-columns-of-a-matrix/18543#18543