# Create a 2d array with 1 on the border and 0 inside

Tags: list-manipulation

I am puzzled with the following. How can I create a, e.g., 10x10 array A[i,j]
where the border is filled with 1's and the rest of the elements are 0?

Thanks

Comment: `ConstantArray` + `ArrayPad`

Comment: This and more: [**21286**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21286/5478), if anyone finds a better duplicate, let me know and I can add it to the list on top.

Comment: ...or `BoxMatrix[]`.

Comment: @J.M. `BoxMatrix` creates a matrix that is (2r+1)x(2r+1). There is no way to select `r` such that the dimension of the matrix is 10x10.

Comment: @Kuba I voted to close this as "easily found in the documentation" because I believe that it has been sufficiently answered here, and that this question is more limited in scope than the proposed duplicate. I wrote an answer for easy reference should someone find this in the future.

Comment: @C.E., `1 - BoxMatrix[3, {10, 10}]` works for me.

Comment: @J.M. I see, I wasn't thinking clearly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kuba suggested

```
ArrayPad[ConstantArray[0, {8, 8}], 1, 1]
```

Similarly, you can do this:

```
CenterArray[ConstantArray[0, {8, 8}], {10, 10}, 1]
```

J.M. proposed the following:

```
1 - BoxMatrix[3, {10, 10}]
```

One may also use

```
SparseArray[{{1, _} -> 1, {_, 1} -> 1, {-1, _} -> 1, {_, -1} -> 1}, {10, 10}]
```

`Normal` can be used if an explicit (rather than a sparse) array is desired.