# How Do I Perform Simple Operations On The Elements of a Table?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have been using the function `HistogramList` to generate frequency tables off a data set. The code looks like this:

```
frequencytable=HistogramList[dataA,{-0.5, 6.5, 1},"PDF"][[2]]
```

with a numerical output of:

> 0.0152, 0.0937, 0.0234, 0.2969, 0.2500, 0.0781, 0.0312

Here is my question. I would like to add the three numbers at the right hand side to one another. Next, I would like to add the three numbers at the left hand side to one another. Last, I would like to subtract the sum of the three numbers on the left from the sum of the three numbers on the right. How do I do that?

Comment: If you want to to this in place you should see: [(3069)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3069/121)

Answer (score 4):

You should have a look at `Take` and `Total` in the documentation. Here's the code:

```
list = {0.0152, 0.0937, 0.0234, 0.2969, 0.2500, 0.0781, 0.0312};
Total@Take[list, -3] - Total@Take[list, 3]
```

> 0.227

Comment: "Total@Take" seems to work. But the answer I got was 0.0156625, not 0.227. (I verified the result on a pocket calculator) Am I missing something? @Anon

Comment: @JoelMayer There are plenty of people who got the same result as I. Perhaps we all misunderstood what it was you wanted to do.

Comment: @JoelMayer Is this not what you want to do: sum of last three digits minus the sum of the first three digits?

Comment: A thousand (1x10^3) pardons my lords and masters. I transcribed 0.234 when I should have transcribed 0.0234. @anon

Answer (score 4):

Just another way to do the same thing:

```
list = {0.0152, 0.0937, 0.0234, 0.2969, 0.2500, 0.0781, 0.0312};
Tr[#[[-3 ;;]] - #[[;; 3]]] &@list
```

> 0.227

Edit:

Just answering comments:

```
Total@{0.2500, 0.0781, 0.0312} - Total@{0.0152, 0.0937, 0.0234}
```

> 0.227

Comment: "Total@Take" seems to work. But the answer I got was 0.015625, not 0.227. (I verified the result on a pocket calculator). Am I missing something? @belisarius

Comment: @JoelMayer Probably a new pair of batteries :). see edit

Comment: A thousand (1x10^3) pardons my lords and masters. I transcribed 0.234 when I should have transcribed 0.0234. @belisarius

Comment: @JoelMayer Easier here than in a peer reviewed paper :)

Answer (score 4):

Okay, since this has turned into a fun-fest here's mine:

```
Range@12 /. {a:_ .. {3}, ___, z:_ .. {3}} :> +z - +a
```

> 27

Keen eyes may have spotted something unusual. ;^)  This uses my own Notation package syntax for `Repeated`; here is the InputForm of the LHS of the rule:

```
{a:_ .. {3}, ___, z:_ .. {3}} // InputForm
```

> ```
> {a:Repeated[_, {3}], ___, z:Repeated[_, {3}]}
> ```

Personally I just hate typing out `Repeated` now.  If anyone else is *crazy* enough to play by my rules ask me for the code or implement it yourself.

Comment: I think this is the first time I've seen `patt .. {n}` for the second argument of `Repeated`. Never knew about that and never would've thought a postfix operator would also serve as an infix one. +!

Comment: Oh wait a minute... _your own Notation package_. Rats! I thought this was an undocumented gem in the syntax :(

Comment: @rm-rf *Now* who's having the heart attack? :o)

Comment: It does look neat, but nowadays I mostly write code for the long term or one that someone else might use, so I've long abandoned any desire for custom notations and focus more on clarity of code (I mean, code written only with the default language syntax. I'll admit, this is much nicer if it were part of the syntax). I genuinely thought this was in the docs!

Comment: @rm-rf I fully understand (see: "crazy").  I do also wish this were real syntax.

Answer (score 4):

After the nonsense here is a serious answer inspired by Kuba's:

```
x = Range @ 12;

PadLeft[x, 6, x, 3].{1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1}
```

> 27

It's quite fast:

```
r = RandomInteger[999, {5000}];
Do[Tr@Take[r, -3] - Tr@Take[r, 3], {500000}] // Timing // First
Do[PadLeft[r, 6, r, 3].{1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1}, {500000}] // Timing // First
```

> 0.639
>
> 0.656

Of course the more direct `x[[{-1, -2, -3, 1, 2, 3}]].{1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1}` is better, but less fun IMHO.

```
Do[r[[{-1, -2, -3, 1, 2, 3}]].{1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1}, {500000}] // Timing // First
```

> 0.421

Answer (score 4):

```
data = {0.0152, 0.0937, 0.0234, 0.2969, 0.2500, 0.0781, 0.0312};
```

Somehow this seems too boring, but all the good answers seem taken:

```
 data[[-1]] + data[[-2]] + data[[-3]] - data[[1]] - data[[2]] - data[[3]]
```

Some find American baseball boring.  Well, at least we can speed up an "inning":

```
threeUPthreeDOWN = Compile[{{data, _Integer, 1}}, 
  data[[-1]] + data[[-2]] + data[[-3]] - data[[1]] - data[[2]] - data[[3]]
  ]
```

Then we don't have to wait long for it to be over:

```
r = RandomInteger[999, {5000}];
Do[threeUPthreeDOWN[r], {500000}] // Timing // First
(* 0.214847 *)
```

Compared to Mr.Wizard's less fun method:

```
Do[r[[{-1, -2, -3, 1, 2, 3}]].{1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1}, {500000}] // Timing // First
(* 0.604915 *)
```

Boring rules!  :)

---

Horses that know how to count know the following method as an order 3 farrier transform filter:

```
farrier3[data_List] := Module[{list, n, m, ker},
  list = If[EvenQ[n = Length@#], Insert[#, 0, 1 + n++/2], #] &@data;
  m = (n - 1)/2;
  ker = Sum[Sin[(m - k + 1) x], {k, 3}];
  1/(Pi I)
     Integrate[list . Table[Exp[I (k - m - 1) x] * ker, {k, n}], {x, -Pi, Pi}] // Re
  ]

farrier3[data]
(* 0.227 *)

farrier3[Range@12]
(* 27 *)
```

Clearly this is a lot more fun, but even I get tired of it after a while:

```
r = RandomInteger[999, {5000}];
farrier3[r] // Timing // First
```

Hmm...if it ever finishes, I'll update the time.  Ah...finally

```
(* 10371.737221 *)
```

Comment: That last timing has to be fake.  Please tell me it is fake. :-p  (+1)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard No, it's not fake.  I let it run while we were making dinner.  But I'm glad you didn't object that I didn't do 500,000 runs. :D

Answer (score 3):

```
rule =  {firstNumber_, secondNumber_, thirdNumber_, middleNumbers___, 
    antePenultimateNumber_, penultimateNumber_, lastNumber_} :> 
   Total[{antePenultimateNumber, penultimateNumber, lastNumber}] - 
    Total[{firstNumber, secondNumber, thirdNumber}];

list /. rule
```

> 0.227

Comment: What's the opposite of Code Golf?

Comment: +1 for taking your time to write _all_ that

Comment: I think you might've just given Mr.Wizard a heart attack! Perhaps you might want to consider making it `middleNumbers___` (`BlankNullSequence`) (or just `___`)

Comment: @cormullion [Code-Bowling](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/code-bowling/info), apparently.

Comment: @rm-rf No heart attack; it's actually a pretty simple method, it just has reeeeally long pattern names.  I think I'll post a Golf version.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard then I'd call this a strike! I was thinking of voting to close but since you all seem to enjoy yourselves so much...

Comment: @Yves I've always held that a question is what you make of it. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Ah. On reflection, though, I'm going for 'self-documenting code'... :)

Comment: @rm-rf good idea. I'll keep the name, which describes it more fully...

Comment: `rule` name does not fit, did you think about `sumofthefirstthreeandlastthreeelementsrule`?

Comment: @kuba no... :) But `joelsRule` would be even better - only he knows the true significance of the rule!

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so if we are having fun:

```
{-1, -1, -1, 0, 1, 1, 1}.list
```

> ```
> 0.227
> ```

@Mr.Wizard - I don't know how to do this neatly :)

```
SparseArray[{1, 2, 3, -3, -2, -1} -> {-1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1}, Length@list, 0].list
```

> ```
> 0.227
> ```

Comment: Add a second line where you generate the number of zeros based on the length of the `list` and you'll have my vote.

Comment: Go for `ListConvolve` and you shall have mine.

Comment: Actually I like that. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I'm glad you do :)

Comment: @Kuba I deleted it since it fails for lists shorter than 7 elements

Comment: @belisarius with assumption that first 3 and last 3 are not overlaping `list[[4;;-4]]` works :)

Comment: @YvesKlett I think I'm not going to get your upvote today :D

Comment: I like your first one very much.

Comment: @cormullion Thank you :) Your is quite fun and educational! I didn't know the word "antepenultimate" :)

Comment: Pity there wasn't a use for [preantepenultimate](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/preantepenultimate) !

Comment: @cormullion It will have its chance :) there's a lot [tag:list-manipulation] questions :)

Comment: just bluffing - you got it from the start anyway :-)

Comment: @Kuba `list.Join[-#, 0 Quiet@Check[list[[4 ;; -4]], {}], #] &@{1, 1, 1}`

Comment: @belisarius :) you should add this to your answer

Answer (score 3):

If you're late to a [list-manipulation](/questions/tagged/list-manipulation) party, you end up using a bazooka to kill a fly:

```
bazooka[list_] := ListCorrelate[{1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1}, list, {1, 1}][[-3]]
bazooka[Range@12]
(* 27 *)
```

Comment: Let's make this competitive: `bazooka2[list_] := ListCorrelate[{1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1}, list, {-3 - Length@list, 3}]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Hehe, I was too lazy to bother with the third argument. `bazooka3[list_] := 
 With[{p1 = # - 5, p2 = # - 2}, 
    SlotSequence[p1] - 2 SlotSequence[p2] & @@ 
     RotateLeft[list, 3]] &@ Length@list` Your move :D