# Sum of two functions, list processing

Tags: list-manipulation

I am creating some simple graphs of functions defined by ordered pairs.
Students are learning about "operations on functions",  in this case, adding functions.

If I have two functions defined by ordered pairs, how do I add them?
I know this must be a simple list processing thing,  I would appreciate any help.

I.E.

```
functiong = {{-5, -5}, {-3, -3}, {1, 1}, {2, 2},  {5, 5}};
functionf = {{-5, 4}, {-3, 2}, {1, 2}, {2, 5}, {5, 5}};
```

I want to have the sum....

```
sum = {{-5, -1}, {-3, -1}, {1, 3}, {2, 7}, {5, 10}};
```

Easy to do manually, but if I modify the lists to create new examples,  I'd like to have *Mathematica* "add" those lists for me....

**Edit**

Below, an example of the kind of question I see in the textbooks the students are using.  They are told that what they see is function $f$ (red)  and function $g$ (blue)  and asked to draw $(f+g)(x)$

[image]

My question is answered,  but now that the context is clear, I would of course welcome any further suggestions on ways to easily create similar  (and perhaps more interesting , but not harder!)  problems.

Comment: Can you post an example using symbols so one can see more easily what is being added to what? Something like : `functiong = {{k1, k2}, {k3, k4}};
functionf = {{c1, c2}, {c3, c4}};` what should the sum be?

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry I wasn't clear.  yes,  the "functions" are always simple, discrete domains.   They are often just simple piecewise functions on a limited domain,  just to see if the students realize that the result is as shown below, (input1,  output1 + output2)  and so on

Comment: Do the functions always have the same domain as shown or do you need to account for the possibility of regions without overlap?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way :

```
MapThread[{#1[[1]], #1[[2]] + #2[[2]]} &, {functiong, functionf}]
(* {{-5, -1}, {-3, -1}, {1, 3}, {2, 7}, {5, 10}} *)
```

Comment: I appreciated everyone's answers,  I learned a lot, and I appreciated all the input.  I found this answer the easiest to understand and use, but all the other answers had things that taught me more about using Mathematica.

Answer (score 9):

Besides standard approach like `MapThread` which appears to be slow for long lists, one should consider more efficient ones, these two ways should be the most efficient (because `Transpose` is the way to go, there were many posts demonstrating its efficiency):

```
Transpose[{ First @ #1, Total[Last /@ {#1, #2}]}]& @@( Transpose /@ 
{functionf, functiong})
```

or

```
Transpose[{ First @ #1, Plus @@ Last /@ {#1, #2}}]& @@ ( Transpose /@ 
{functionf, functiong})
```

> ```
> {{-5, -1}, {-3, -1}, {1, 3}, {2, 7}, {5, 10}}
> ```

The above can be also rewrittren more concisely using a shorthand `Esc tr Esc` or `\[Transpose]`:

[image]

**Edit**

Let's compare efficiency of the various methods, e.g.:

```
arg = RandomInteger[{-100, 100}, 10^6];
fg = Transpose[{arg, RandomInteger[{-100, 100}, 10^6]}];
ff = Transpose[{arg, RandomInteger[{-100, 100}, 10^6]}];

bgatessucks[g_, f_] := First[MapThread[{#1[[1]], #1[[2]] + #2[[2]]} &, {g, f}]
// AbsoluteTiming]

kuba[f_, g_] := First[+##/{2, 1} & @@@ GatherBy[f~Join~g, First] // AbsoluteTiming]

nasser[f_, g_] := First[ Transpose[{g[[All, 1]], g[[All, 2]] + f[[All, 2]]}]
// AbsoluteTiming]  

artes1[f_, g_] := First[Transpose[{First @ #1, Plus @@ Last /@ {#1, #2}}] & @@
(Transpose /@ {f, g}) // AbsoluteTiming]

artes2[f_, g_] := First[Transpose[{First @ #1, Total[ Last /@ {#1, #2}]}] & @@
(Transpose /@ {f, g}) // AbsoluteTiming]
```

Now

```
  bgatessucks[fg, ff]
  kuba[ff, fg]
  nasser[ff, fg]
  artes1[ff, fg]
  artes2[ff, fg]
```

> ```
> 4.671000
> 3.153000
> 0.175000
> 0.092000
> 0.063000
> ```

We can see that `Transpose` with `Total` is the fastest approach, i.e. `artes1`.  It is faster roughly `70` times for these lists.

Answer (score 5):

```
+##/{2, 1} & @@@ GatherBy[functionf~Join~functiong, First]
```

or for more functions: `set = {f1, f2, ...}`, also with different domains:

```
+##/{Length[{##}], 1} & @@@ GatherBy[Join@@set, First]
```

**Edit** reffering to your edit:

```
g = {{-5, -5}, {-3, -3}, {1, 1}, {2, 2}, {5, 5}};
f = {{-5, 4}, {-3, 2}, {1, 2}, {2, 5}, {5, 5}};
int = Interpolation[#, InterpolationOrder -> 1] &

Plot[{int[g][x], int[f][x], int[g][x] + int[f][x]}, {x, -5, 5}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

A linear algebra approach

```
c = functiong[[All, 1]];
d = functiong[[All, 2]] + functionf[[All, 2]];
Transpose[{c, d}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @Kuba, humm... everyone seems to be getting different result then when the first set is changed from identity. It would be easier if it was put in terms of symbols so one can see better that is being added to what. Your method gives different result to gatessucks as well. See: ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HkFCT.png)

Comment: You can't test my approach for symbols. The part with `GatherBy` will fail as it is looking for values for the same arguments. @b.gatessucks 's way will work with the assumption that first elements o each pair are the same for each 'function'

Answer (score 4):

1. Approach with compact notation

   ```
   functiong + functionf /. {x_, y_} -> {x/2, y}
   ```
2. Fast (the fastest?) approach

   ```
   res = fg + ff; res[[All, 1]] = fg[[All, 1]];
   ```

   Timings (2*10^7 elements):

   > my: 1.794889
   >
   > artes1: 1.893763
   >
   > artes2: 1.894489

Both can be easily generalized to any number of functions.

Edit: on different system timings can vary. In some cases my solution is faster, in some -- not.

Comment: I like it (+1) but I found `artes1` and `artes2` faster. More reliable for timing should be timeAvg function: `timeAvg = 
  Function[func, 
   Do[If[# > 0.3, Return[#/5^i]] & @@ 
     AbsoluteTiming@Do[func, {5^i}], {i, 0, 15}], HoldFirst];`.  Now `artes1[ff, fg]` yields `1.332000` while `ybeltukov[fg, ff]` yields `1.569000` for `ybeltukov[f_, g_] := 
 timeAvg[(res = fg + ff; res[[All, 1]] = fg[[All, 1]];)]`  for lists of `2 10^7` lengths.

Comment: @Artes It turns out it depend on the system. The timings above I get on Core 2 Quad. On Core i7 I get `my: 0.971060, artes1: 0.807833, artes2: 0.809121`. You too +1 :)

Answer (score 4):

I think this question is a duplicate of [Elegant operations on matrix rows and columns](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3069/121) unless functions do not share identical domains.  Nevertheless for the time being I'll join in the fun.  This is essentially the same are Artes's method but in my own style:

```
add = {#, #2 + #4}\[Transpose] & @@ Join[#\[Transpose], #2\[Transpose]] &;
```

Which displays as:

[image]

Test:

```
add[functionf, functiong]
```

> ```
> {{-5, -1}, {-3, -1}, {1, 3}, {2, 7}, {5, 10}}
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun:

```
{1, 0}.{functionf, functiong}.{{1, 1}, {0, 1}}
```