# Filling Stacked Graph v.10.1

Tags: version-10, visualization, filling

I used a code very similar to the code posted by Kuba
[stacked line graph with fragmented data](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47069/stacked-line-graph-with-fragmented-data)

```
TestData = {{{1, 23}, {4, 3}, {10, 34}, {12, 34}, {20, 5}}, {{5, 
     3}, {6, 3}, {7, 4}, {15, 12}, {21, 5}}};
Plot[Piecewise[{{Interpolation[#, x, 
         InterpolationOrder -> 0], #[[1, 1]] <= x <= #[[-1, 1]]}, {#[[
         1, 2]], x < #[[1, 1]]}, {#[[-1, 2]], x > #[[-1, 1]]}}] & /@ 
    TestData // Accumulate // Reverse, {x, 0, 25}, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, Frame -> True, 
 Filling -> {1 -> Axis, 2 -> {1}}, FillingStyle -> {Red, Blue}, 
 Evaluated -> True, PlotStyle -> Thick, Frame -> True, 
 BaseStyle -> {18, Bold}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Using v.9.0 I get the desired output:
[image: Output v.9.0]

If a execute the same code in v.10.1 the filling looks different.
[image: Output v.10.1]

What change between v.9 and v.10 is responsible for the different behaviour?
Couldn't find a way to get the same output as in v.9.0 until now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `Evaluate[...]` rather than `Evaluated -> True`

START EDIT:

```
Attributes[Plot]
```

> {HoldAll, Protected, ReadProtected}

Since `Plot` has the attribute `HoldAll` the first expression is initially interpretted as a single entity. To make the argument a list of two distinct entities it must be evaluated to override the `HoldAll` attribute. `Evaluated` is not a documented option for `Plot` and apparaently does not work in this case in version 10.1. Whereas, use of `Evaluate` is documented in the documentaton for `Plot`: `"- Plot has attribute HoldAll and evaluates f only after assigning specific numerical values to x. - In some cases, it may be more efficient to use Evaluate to evaluate f symbolically before specific numerical values are assigned to x."`

END EDIT.

```
$Version
```

> "10.1.0  for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 24, 2015)"

```
TestData = {{{1, 23}, {4, 3}, {10, 34}, {12, 34}, {20, 5}}, {{5, 3}, {6, 
     3}, {7, 4}, {15, 12}, {21, 5}}};
Plot[Evaluate[
  Piecewise[{{Interpolation[#, x, InterpolationOrder -> 0], #[[1, 1]] <= 
          x <= #[[-1, 1]]}, {#[[1, 2]], x < #[[1, 1]]}, {#[[-1, 2]], 
         x > #[[-1, 1]]}}] & /@ TestData // Accumulate // Reverse], {x, 0, 
  25}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, Frame -> True, Filling -> {1 -> Axis, 2 -> {1}}, 
 FillingStyle -> {Red, Blue}, PlotStyle -> Thick, Frame -> True, 
 BaseStyle -> {18, Bold}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Why is it needed at all?

Comment: @BlacKow - see edit above.

Comment: That's terribly disappointing as I have favored `Evaluated -> True` for years because it preserves localization of the plot variable.  We must wrap the entire thing in `Block[{x}, . . . ]` in this case now to handle it properly.  Nevertheless +1.