# How to combine two vectors into a matrix by columns?

Tags: list-manipulation, vector

I know it may sounds idiot, but I've been looking through the document, and couldn't find a way to combine two vectors say `{a, b}` and `{c, d}` into `{{a, c}, {b, d}}`.

Thanks all.

Comment: `Transpose[{{a,b},{c,d}}]`

Comment: OP wanted {{a,c},{b,d}} which is a concatenation by columns.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You are treating $A$ and $B$ as column vectors and combining them column to column, but if you just bracket the two vectors, you are combining them row to row. A final `Transpose` will do the trick.

```
A = {a, b};
B = {c, d};
NotYourResult = {A,B}
Result = Transpose[{A, B}]
```

where `NotYourResult` is assigned `{{a,b},{c,d}}` or
    $\left[ {\begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ c & d \\ \end{array} } \right]$,

and `Result` is assigned `{{a,c},{b,d}}` or 
    $\left[ {\begin{array}{cc} a & c \\ b & d \\ \end{array} } \right]$,

Answer (score 16):

`Thread` can be useful, too:

```
A = {a, b};
B = {c, d};

Thread[{A, B}]
```

> {{a, c}, {b, d}}

The canonical Q&A for this kind of stuff probably is [Elegant operations on matrix rows and columns](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3069/131).