# Add a column to a matrix as a function of the other columns

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, matrix

I was wondering if its possible to add a column to a matrix by a formula that uses all other columns, like this:

```
{a1,b1,c1,f(a1,b1,c1)}
{a2,b2,c2,f(a2,b2,c2)}
{a3,b3,c3,f(a3,b3,c3)}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at [Elegant operations on matrix rows and columns](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3069/elegant-operations-on-matrix-rows-and-columns).

Comment: Also `{##, f[##]}& @@@ M` will do.

Answer (score 5):

Since Kuba chose not to post his comment as an answer, and since Community♦ has bumped this question because of no positively voted answers, here is his method in an answer, with explanation.

You can use [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apply.html) at level one, shorthand `@@@`, to easily access parts of an expression via [`Slot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Slot.html) and [`SlotSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SlotSequence.html).  Example:

```
dat = Partition[Range @ 9, 3]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}
> ```

```
{##, f@##} & @@@ dat
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 3, f[1, 2, 3]}, {4, 5, 6, f[4, 5, 6]}, {7, 8, 9, f[7, 8, 9]}}
> ```

`##` represents the sequence of all arguments of the [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Function.html).

You could also use these:

```
MapThread[Append, {dat, f @@@ dat}]

Join[dat, List /@ f @@@ dat, 2]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
m = {
{a1,b1,c1},
{a2,b2,c2},
{a3,b3,c3}
};
ResourceFunction["AppendColumn"][m, f@@@m] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
A = {{a1, b1, c1}, {a2, b2, c2}, {a3, b3, c3}}
c = f @@@ A
Insert[A // Transpose, c, 4] // Transpose // MatrixForm
```

`A`, which is `{{a1, b1, c1}, {a2, b2, c2}, {a3, b3, c3}}`, is actually

```
List[List[a1, b1, c1], List[a2, b2, c2], List[a3, b3, c3]]
```

By replacing the inner `List`-s with your function using *apply* on level 1, a.k.a `@@@`.

Thus `c = f @@@ A`  would give

```
c = List[f[a1, b1, c1], f[a2, b2, c2], f[a3, b3, c3]]
```

which is

```
c = {f[a1, b1, c1], f[a2, b2, c2], f[a3, b3, c3]}
```

Next, you transpose the original matrix and attach this newly created row using `Insert`, then transpose the result to get your desired matrix.

***Edit:*** If you have a $3\times5$ matrix and you like to perform function f on the 2nd, 1st and 5th column, try this:

```
c = f @@@ A[[All, {2, 1, 5}]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! I'm having trouble applying the module, it just puts it in as text it seems.

Answer (score 1):

```
list = Partition[Range @ 9, 3];

Query[All, {Splice, Apply @ f }] @ list
```

gives the expected result:

```
{{1, 2, 3, f[1, 2, 3]},
 {4, 5, 6, f[4, 5, 6]},
 {7, 8, 9, f[7, 8, 9]}}
```