# Merging two lists by prepending elements

Tags: list-manipulation

Being a newcomer to *Mathematica*, I have the following question.

Given

```
x = Range@9~Partition~3;
```

and

```
y = {a, b, c};
```

I want to combine `x` and `y` so that

```
result = {{a, 1, 2, 3}, {b, 4, 5, 6}, {c, 7, 8, 9}};
```

I have written

```
MapPrepend[a_, b_] := Prepend[a[[#]], b[[#]]] & /@ Range@Length@b
```

which does the job, but I wonder if there are other, more functional solutions?

Probably this question has already been answered. In this case it would be very nice if you just would direct me to the links.

Comment: `Join[{y}, Transpose[x]] // Transpose`?

Comment: Please take a look here,  there is something for everyone: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3069/elegant-operations-on-matrix-rows-and-columns

Comment: @kguler - thanks, short and elegant (sometimes you don't see the wood for the trees). Should also be faster on large lists;)

Comment: `MapThread[Prepend, {x, y}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simply do `Flatten /@ Transpose[{y, x}]`.

Comment: also very nice, thank you. To not forget it I just added to my init.m a "MapFlatten".

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, in terms of speed there is probably not much to gain here. However, I guess this is fancy

```
Join[List /@ y, x, 2]
```

Comment: The shortest characterwise. Didn't know that "Join" accepts a level parameter.

Comment: @eldo copy this: `{y, ## & @@ x}\[Transpose]`

Comment: @Kuba I can't beat that :). My shortest: `{y, x /. _@z__ -> z}\[Transpose]`

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom nice syntax :) it's interesting to see others habits :)