# Setting a Row from a Matrix as Variable

Tags: list-manipulation, data

I'm not advanced in *Mathematica* but I'm trying to get better.

I have a big set of `Data` and I want to `Plot` the first row against the other ones.
I tried to set the `Rows` into a list and run a "do loop" over all `Rows`.

My Code :

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
Data = Import["file", "Table"];
Time = Table[1/60 i, {i, 0, 1430}];
Rows[k_] = Do[List[Transpose[{Time, Data[[All, k]]}]], {k, 1, 16}]
Toplot = Do[Transpose[{Time, Rows[k]}], {k, 1, 16}];
ListPlot[{Toplot}];
```

I would be grateful for some help and tips.

Comment: You should provide a sample of the `Data` :)

Comment: Have a look at `Part` and `Span`. You will most likely not need a loop at all. Useful: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3069/elegant-operations-on-matrix-rows-and-columns

Comment: as a fundamental issue your `Do` loops should be `Table`s. The posted answer is better of course.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should avoid using variables names with capital letters : these correspond to built-in functions.

Then, if I understood correctly, you want to plot the rows of your data versus time.
If so, the following code should work :

```
data = Import["file", "Table"];
time = Range[0, 143/6, 1/60];
ListPlot[Transpose[{time, #}] & /@ data]
```