# Column Operation - Subtract part of nested list from part of another nested list

Tags: list-manipulation, operators

I have two lists with x- and y-coordinates with different z-coordinates of the form

```
{{x0, y0, z0_1}, {x1, y1, z1_1}, ..., {xn, yn, zn_1}}
```

and

```
{{x0, y0, z0_2}, {x1, y1, z1_2}, ..., {xn, yn, zn_2}}.
```

I want to construct the list

> ```
> {{x0, y0, z0_1 - z0_2}, {x1, y1, z1_1 - z1_2}, ..., {xn, yn, zn_1 - zn_2}}
> ```

i.e. construct a list containing the difference of only the z-coordinates, for each x- and y-coordinate.

Is it possible to do this with a few simple commands, or should I construct a loop and create a new list from scratch?

Comment: Have a look at `Transpose` and `Differences`.

Comment: Thank you :) I didn't find a solution before another answer was given to me however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lis1 = {{x0, y0, z01}, {x1, y1, z11}, {xn, yn, zn1}};
lis2 = {{x0, y0, z02}, {x1, y1, z12}, {xn, yn, zn2}};
```

If you first define this function:

```
f[{x_, y_, z_}, {x_, y_, u_}] := {x, y, z - u}
```

You can then easily do:

```
f @@@ Transpose[{lis1, lis2}]
```

> ```
> {{x0, y0, z01 - z02}, {x1, y1, z11 - z12}, {xn, yn, zn1 - zn2}}
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much. That works perfectly! :)

Comment: @bjorn, you're welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Consider:

```
a = {{x0, y0, z0}, {x1, y1, z1}, {xn, yn, zn}};
b = {{x0, y0, Z0}, {x1, y1, Z1}, {xn, yn, Zn}};  (* note capital Z *)

c = a;
c[[All, 3]] -= b[[All, 3]];
c
```

> ```
> {{x0, y0, z0 - Z0}, {x1, y1, z1 - Z1}, {xn, yn, zn - Zn}}
> ```

See: [Elegant operations on matrix rows and columns](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3069/elegant-operations-on-matrix-rows-and-columns/3077#3077)

You can use a `Module` if you wish to make this a self-contained function.

Another option (looks better in a Notebook):

```
{#, #2, #3 - b[[All, 3]]}\[Transpose] & @@ (a\[Transpose])
```

Comment: Should the question be closed then as a duplicate?

Comment: @RunnyKine I guess this really should be closed so I'll convert my answer to CW and do it.

Comment: Thank you very much as well. It's nice having different solutions :)

And I'm sorry for not finding that the questions had already been answered, I tried to but was a bit unsure of what to search for exactly. Of course I don't oppose a close, but I suppose that the thread will still be viewable for future visitors?

Comment: @bjorn I always appreciate people searching before posting but I also know that finding existing Q&A's can be quite difficult.  I've spent 15-20 minutes looking for a single one without result before.  This question will remain for a time; it may or may not be deleted some months from now.  I am not sure how many people would find this question given its current title, but that may be only my own bias speaking.  (It seems like a column operation to me so I would phrase it as such but that is merely an opinion.)