# An intuitive way to form an augmented matrix

Tags: matrix

Given an $m\times n$ matrix $A$ and a $m\times 1$ vector $b$, what is the most "intuitive" way of forming the augmented matrix $[ A\ b]$? The most concise way that I know of is
`Flatten/@Transpose[{A,b}]`, but for beginners to Linear Algebra and/or *Mathematica*, this is hardly intuitive. In MATLAB, it is just `[A b]`.

Is there a built-in command that does this simply that I've missed?

Comment: Are you aware of this thread: [Elegant operations on matrix rows and columns](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3069/131)? Might be a duplicate at that...

Comment: I'm not necessarily asking "how to add a column", but rather, "How to add a column intuitively." I use Mathematica in my classroom and often row operations/Gaussian Elimination is taught before the transpose. So augmenting a matrix with a double transpose or with the `Flatten` command is confusing to students. MATLAB's method is much, much more intuitive. I want to know if there is a simple way of doing it. Given the links and other posts, it seems the answer is no.

Comment: If `b` is a vector (dimension=1) could do `Join[A, List /@ b, 2]`. If it is a 3x1 matrix then drop the `List/@` part.

Comment: The original question would be a bit more clear if A and b were defined via Mathematica constructs. Especially what is b.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the analogue of Matlab's implicit concatenation is `ArrayFlatten`, but it still needs to be called explicitly.

```
(aa = Table[a[i, j], {i, 3}, {j, 3}]) // MatrixForm
```

> $$\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  a(1,1) & a(1,2) & a(1,3) \\
>  a(2,1) & a(2,2) & a(2,3) \\
>  a(3,1) & a(3,2) & a(3,3) \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$$

```
(bb = Table[{b[i]}, {i, 3}]) // MatrixForm
```

> $$\left(
> \begin{array}{c}
>  b(1) \\
>  b(2) \\
>  b(3) \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$$

```
ArrayFlatten[{{aa, bb}}] // MatrixForm
```

> $$\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  a(1,1) & a(1,2) & a(1,3) & b(1) \\
>  a(2,1) & a(2,2) & a(2,3) & b(2) \\
>  a(3,1) & a(3,2) & a(3,3) & b(3) \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$$

---

To work with the usual form of vectors, I'd suggest the following:

```
row[v_] := {v}
col[v_] := {#} & /@ v
sca[x_] := {{x}}
```

Then if you have, for example,

```
aa = Array[a, {3, 4}] (* {{a[1, 1], a[1, 2], a[1, 3], a[1, 4]}, ...} *)
bb = Array[b, 3] (* {b[1], b[2], b[3]} *)
cc = Array[c, 4] (* {c[1], c[2], c[3], c[4]} *)
```

you can do

```
ArrayFlatten[{{aa, col[bb]}, {row[cc], sca[d]}}]
```

> $$\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccc}
>  a(1,1) & a(1,2) & a(1,3) & a(1,4) & b(1) \\
>  a(2,1) & a(2,2) & a(2,3) & a(2,4) & b(2) \\
>  a(3,1) & a(3,2) & a(3,3) & a(3,4) & b(3) \\
>  c(1) & c(2) & c(3) & c(4) & d \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$$

while still working with `aa`, `bb`, and `cc` as matrices and vectors.

Comment: This is much more straightforward in that one can "visualize" the construction via the `{{aa,bb}}` part. However, one has to be careful to construct the vector `bb` "correctly". The vector cannot simply be `bb={1,2,3}`, for instance, but rather `bb={{1},{2},{3}}.` Then again, this isn't bad, as it makes more sense to a beginner for a column vector to be written this way.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't play too well with the usual way vectors are represented in Mathematica; even row vectors have to be `{{1, 2, 3}}` instead of just `{1, 2, 3}` for this to work. So it's far from a perfect solution.

Comment: It might make sense for your students if you point out that Mathematica generally doesn't distinguish between row and column vectors (what would be `x'*A*x` in Matlab is just `x.a.x` in Mathematica). Only in the context of `ArrayFlatten` does it matter, so you could define functions `row[v_] := {v}` and `col[v_] := {#}& /@ v` (and `sca[x_] := {{x}}`) to put things into the right "shape" for it.

Comment: This seems to be one of the features of Mathematica that is both a "blessing and a curse." It is extremely powerful and convenient to write things like `x.A.x`. But then putting a column vector in the "right shape" as you mention to use for matrix augmenting then puts the vector in the "wrong shape" for things like `A.x`. I'll mark your answer as correct as it is the most intuitive I've seen, and perhaps the best considering Mathematica's limitations in this regard.

Comment: @GregH: Please see my edit for an example of what I have in mind.

Comment: `col[v_] := List /@ v` would also work…

Answer (score 1):

I would do the job with `Join`command.

```
am=Table[Alphabet[][[j+d(i-1)]],{i,1,3},{j,1,3}];
MatrixForm[am]
bm=Table[{Alphabet[][[i]]},{i,21,23}];
MatrixForm[bm]
cm=Transpose[Join[Transpose[am],Transpose[bm]]];
MatrixForm[cm]
```

[image]

Comment: This is way too long for being seen as "intuitive". (As described by OP.)

Comment: @AntonAntonov `cm=` is the part **GregH** needs. I dont think it is not intuitive. Just note that `Join` glues a martix at the bottom of the other. Using `Transpose` we can glue them side by side...