# Extracting columns from multidimensional list

Tags: list-manipulation

Perhaps a very easy question but I posted this on the Wolfram Community and didn't get any answer..

Suppose I have data like:

```
data = Table[{{Subscript[a, x, 1, 1], Subscript[a, x, 1, 2], 
    Subscript[a, x, 1, 3]}, {Subscript[b, x, 2, 1], Subscript[b, x, 2,
     2], Subscript[b, x, 2, 3]}}, {x, 1, 3}]
```

[image]

Now suppose I wan't to get from all rows the first item in the first list and the third item in the second list like:

[image]

It can be done by using:

```
{data[[All, 1, 1]], data[[All, 2, 3]]}\[Transpose]
```

or

```
{#[[1, 1]], #[[2, 3]]} & /@ data
```

But I'm wondering if there isn't an easier way by only using Part,Extract?
It seems that going through the documentation the option only apply to one column (or more) but not to subparts in these columns.

Any thoughts?

Comment: [this Q&A](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3069/7167) is helpful and may have what you seek.

Comment: `{#1[[1]], #2[[-1]]} & @@@ data`

Comment: `data /. {{f_, __}, {__, l_}} -> {f, l}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is any way to do it using just `Part` or `Extract`. With these functions you specify the elements you want at level 1, then at level 2, then level 3 etc. At each level you may specify a single element, a list of elements, `All` or a `Span`. There is no syntax for specifying different sub-parts for each of the elements selected at a certain level.

For an alternative, I suggest using the operator form of `Extract` along with `Map`:

```
Extract[{{1, 1}, {2, 3}}] /@ data
```

Comment: +1 good explanation. and also it is same of `Extract[{{1, 1}, {-1, -1}}] /@ data`

Answer (score 6):

My favorite being a slight variation of  @Lou's own solution

```
Transpose[{data[[;;, 1, 1]], data[[;;, -1, -1]]}]
```

you can also use

```
Transpose@Rest@Extract[data, {{}, {;; , 1, 1}, {;; , -1, -1}}]
(* version 9 only -- does not work in version 10 -- thanks: Simon Woods *)
```

or

```
ReplacePart[data, p_ :> {data[[p, 1, 1]], data[[p, -1, -1]]}]
```

or

```
{First@First@#, Last@Last@#} & /@ data
```

or

```
ClearAll[f];
f[{{a_, __}, {__, b_}}] := {a, b}
f /@ data
```

all give

[image]

Comment: What version are you using? Your second one does not work for me (I get a "Position specification ...  is not applicable" error)

Comment: @Simon I am using V 9.0.1 (Windows 8 64-bit).

Answer (score 4):

My try

```
{#1[[1]], #2[[-1]]} & @@@ data
```

or

```
data /. {{f_, __}, {__, l_}} -> {f, l}
```