# accessing elements of nested list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of the form:

```
toy = {{a, {b, c}}, {d, {e, f}}, {g, {h, j}}, {k, {m, n}}};
```

and would like to create the list

```
{{a, c}, {d, f}, {g, j}, {k, n}}
```

from toy.

The following code does it but I find this esthetically unsatisfactory because I don't like creating the two independent lists toy[[;; , 1]] and toy[[;; , 2, 2]] and combining them.

```
Transpose[{toy[[;; , 1]], toy[[;; , 2, 2]]}]
```

Is there a cleaner more direct way to do this?

Comment: For ex.`{#[[1]], #[[2, 2]]} & /@ toy` or `{#1, #2[[2]]} & @@@ toy`

Comment: `toy /. {x_, {y_, z_}} :> {x, z}`

Comment: Just for something different: `toy[[All, 2]] = toy[[All, 2, 2]]; toy`

Comment: Without destroying the toy `Transpose@{toy[[All,1]],toy[[All,2,2]]}`

Comment: @tchronis That method is already in the question as "unsatisfactory"

Comment: Incidentally I think something *very* close to this has been asked before, if not this exact transformation.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, this is close: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/63989/extracting-columns-from-multidimensional-list

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is this what you want:

```
Map[{#[[1]], #[[2, 2]]} &, toy]
```

Answer (score 4):

One should ban all those comments spammers one day... :)

To not duplicate them:

```
toy[[All , 2, 0]] = #2 &;
toy
```

> ```
> {{a, c}, {d, f}, {g, j}, {k, n}}
> ```

Keep in mind that this modifies `toy`.

Comment: +1 nice one :) How come you (and others) use ` ;; ` instead of `All`?

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch you mean why? 2 is less than 3 characters :) But may be obscuring sometimes and doesn't work for <V9 in every form. Still, I like it :)

Comment: @Mike Probably to save a character, but even as a terse fanatic I prefer `All`.  First because it is descriptive and ledible, and second because it is backward-compatible. (`;;` does not work in v7.)  It's only *one* more character so I vote for `All`.  I've even edited it into a few answers here and there.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard ok ok... :)

Comment: @Kuba Of course you have your own style and it doesn't have to agree with mine.  :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I don't! My notebooks are full of `;;` :)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe:

```
Extract[{{1}, {2, 2}}] /@ toy
```

Answer (score 3):

```
(Flatten /@ toy)[[;; , {1, 3}]]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
☺ = {#, #2 & @@ #2} & @@@ # &;
☺ @ toy
```

> {{a, c}, {d, f}, {g, j}, {k, n}}

Comment: Or, {#, Last@#2} & @@@ toy

Comment: @bbgodfrey, yes but then we can't say "look ma, no letters!"

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{a, {b, c}}, {d, {e, f}}, {g, {h, j}}, {k, {m, n}}};
```

Using `ReplaceAt` (new in 13.1)

```
ReplaceAt[list, {_, a_} :> a, {;; , 2}]
```

{{a, c}, {d, f}, {g, j}, {k, n}}

Answer (score 1):

Using `ReplaceList`:

```
list = {{a, {b, c}}, {d, {e, f}}, {g, {h, j}}, {k, {m, n}}};

ReplaceList[#, {s1_, {s2__}} :> Splice@{s1, First@s2}] & /@ list

(*{{a, c}, {d, f}, {g, j}, {k, n}}*)
```

Or using `Cases`:

```
Cases[#, {s1_, {s2__}} :> {s1, First@s2}] &@list

(*{{a, c}, {d, f}, {g, j}, {k, n}}*)
```

Or using `ReplaceAll`:

```
# /. {s2_, s3 : {__}} :> {s2, Last@s3} &@list

(*{{a, c}, {d, f}, {g, j}, {k, n}}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
toy = {{a, {b, c}}, {d, {e, f}}, {g, {h, j}}, {k, {m, n}}};

Cases[toy, {a_, {b_, c_}} :> {a, c}]
{First@#, Last@Last@#} & /@ toy
Flatten@*ReplacePart[{{2, 1}} -> Nothing] /@ toy
Flatten@*Delete[{2, 1}] /@ toy
#[[{1, -1}]] &@*MapAt[Splice, 2] /@ toy
{First@#, Last@#} & /@ MapAt[Splice, toy, {All, 2}]
Through[{First, Last}[#]] & /@ MapAt[Splice, toy, {All, 2}]
```

---

*Result:*

> {{a, c}, {d, f}, {g, j}, {k, n}}