# Replace parts of nested lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I have list of stock data as follows:

```
lis1= 
{{{1992/10/12, 126.946, AEX}, {1992/10/13, 127.85, AEX}},
 {{1992/10/12, 88.487, AFLI},{1992/10/13, 91.825, AFLI}}}
```

I would like to replace the closing prive (second entry in each nested list) with the corresponding value of the following list. Both lists have the same lengths.

```
lis2=
{{125.12,125.32},{91.34,91.88}}
```

Does anyone have a hint?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [(3069)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3069/121)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For in-place modification use assignment to [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html):

```
lis1[[All, All, 2]] = lis2;

lis1
```

> ```
> {{{83/5, 125.12, AEX}, {996/65, 125.32, AEX}},
>  {{83/5, 91.34, AFLI}, {996/65, 91.88,  AFLI}}}
> ```

If you do not want to modify `lis1` make a copy first and use the same syntax.

---

Automation of the copy operation:

```
(newPart[expr_, part___] = new_) ^:= Module[{x = expr}, x[[part]] = new; x]
```

(Syntax highlighting may complain but the definition still works.)

Usage example:

```
(* starting with original lis1 definition *)

newPart[lis1, All, All, 2] = lis2
```

> ```
> {{{83/5, 125.12, AEX}, {996/65, 125.32, AEX}},
>  {{83/5, 91.34, AFLI}, {996/65, 91.88, AFLI}}}
> ```

`lis1` remains unchanged:

```
lis1
```

> ```
> {{{83/5, 126.946, AEX}, {996/65, 127.85, AEX}},
>  {{83/5, 88.487, AFLI}, {996/65, 91.825, AFLI}}}
> ```

Comment: is there an elegant way to do that without making a copy?

Comment: @garej In [my opinion](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3077/121) making a copy is the best approach.  It is easy to write a utility function to automate this; I'll append that to my answer for your consideration.

Comment: thank you, I see. In my case I have a matrix, (re)generated by random process (in Dynamic setting). Is it fine to make a copy of it as it changes each time something else changes?

Comment: @garej In your position I would try it and see.  I *think* memory management and garbage collection should allow that to work.  The way you describe that however it sounds like you *could* use in-place modification.  I wonder what the need for a copy with every change is?