# Efficient method to set Matrix values based on position

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a matrix, a list of positions, and a vector.

I want a new matrix with the values of the vector inserted into the original matrix based upon the list of positions.

For example:

```
oldMatrix = {{a1, a2, a3, a4}, {b1, b2, b3, b4}, 
             {c1, c2, c3, c4}, {d1, d2, d3, d4}};

positions = {{1, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, 2}, {4, 1}}

newElements = {A1, B3, C2, D1}
```

Then I want the new matrix to be

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If I was working with a vector rather than a matrix this would be easy:

```
newVector                = oldVector
newVector[[{positions}]] = newElements
```

as vectors support a list when indexing.

This will not work with matrices.

I have searched and read with interest [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3069/elegant-operations-on-matrix-rows-and-columns) but it doesn't fit this problem.

The best I have been able to come up with is:

```
setMatrix[matrix_, positionsMatrix_, vector_] := Module[
  {
   vectorF,
   positionsVector,
   row,
   column
   },

  vectorF = Flatten[matrix];
  {row, column} = Dimensions[matrix];

  positionsVector = Map[(#[[1]] - 1)*row + #[[2]] &,
    positionsMatrix];

  vectorF[[positionsVector]] = vector;

  Partition[vectorF, row]
  ]
```

but I would hope there was a simpler, more elegant and efficient approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
oldMatrix = {{a1, a2, a3, a4}, {b1, b2, b3, b4}, {c1, c2, c3, 
    c4}, {d1, d2, d3, d4}};

positions = {{1, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, 2}, {4, 1}};

newElements = {A1, B3, C2, D1};

(newMatrix = 
   ReplacePart[oldMatrix, 
    Thread[positions -> newElements]]) // MatrixForm
```

[image]