# Add a vector to a list of vectors

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, vector

What is the syntax to add a vector `v1` to each vector in a list of vectors `v2`?

I know it has to be simple, but I really have searched and not found it.

```
v1 = {a, b, c}
v2 = {{d, e, f}, {g, h, i}, {j, k, l}}
```

i.e., sum them in a way to give:

> ```
> {{a + d, b + e,c + f}, {a + g, b + h, c + i}, {a + j, b + k, c + l}}
> ```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I recommend using [`Transpose`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose.html?q=Transpose) twice since it is more efficient than other approaches. Moreover `Plus`  has the [`Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html?q=Listable) attribute, thus one need not map `Plus` over a list (vector).

```
Transpose[v1 + Transpose[v2]]
```

> ```
> {{a + d, b + e, c + f}, {a + g, b + h, c + i}, {a + j, b + k, c + l}}
> ```

Having said that remember that one can rewrite it very concisely in the Front-End: `Esc tr Esc` :

[image]

Comment: Hah, clearly my knowledge of `Inner` isn't well enough entrenched yet. I failed to notice that my `Inner` effectively simplified to `Transpose @* Plus`!

Comment: @ciao Thanks, unfortunately someone unupvoted my answer (it was edited)  so I guess it is inadvisable to improve posts.

Comment: @Artes  Of course it _is_ advisable to improve posts!

Comment: In similar contexts ... While I use `Transpose` all the time - for intuitive clarity and readability, sometimes one can get faster performance using `Part` and `All` in its place ... just FYI `testData = Table[{{i, 2 i}, 3 i}, {i, 1000000}]; Print@Timing[ Length[ Last[ Transpose[testData]]]]; Print@Timing[ Length[ Part[ testData, All, 2]]]; Print@Timing[ Length[ testData[[ All, 2]]]];`

Answer (score 17):

To achieve what you need requires to distribute the sum over v2:

```
(v1 + # &) /@ v2
```

which is a short form of:

```
Map[ v1 + # &, v2 ]
```

Comment: This is a good one for my list of "expressions that help me understand mathematica syntax"! Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Alternative method using the magic that is `Inner`:

```
Inner[Plus, {a, b, c}, Transpose@{{d, e, f}, {g, h, i}, {j, k, l}}, List]
```

Answer (score 10):

Also:

```
Plus @@@ Thread[{v1, v2}, List, {2}]
```

Answer (score 6):

I couldn't resist adding this:

```
TranslationTransform[v1] /@ v2
```

Comment: More terse and universal version: `TranslationTransform[v1][v2]`.

Comment: This function is for that purpose by far the slowest solution ...

Answer (score 6):

Using `Outer` is also an efficient approach, in some cases faster than using `Transpose` twice, the undocumented function `` Statistics`Library`MatrixRowTranslate `` may be the fastest

```
v1 = RandomReal[1, 10^5];
v2 = RandomReal[1, {10^3, 10^5}];

r1 = Transpose[v1 + Transpose[v2]]; // RepeatedTiming
r2 = Outer[Plus, {v1}, v2, 1][[1]]; // RepeatedTiming
r3 = Block[{res=v2}, Statistics`Library`MatrixRowTranslate[res, v1]; res]; // RepeatedTiming

r1===r2===r3
```

Output

> {0.541983, Null}
> {0.446791, Null}
> {0.241258, Null}
> True

Related link:
[Improving Map Function on Lists](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/211398/improving-map-function-on-lists)

[Elegant operations on matrix rows and columns](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3069/elegant-operations-on-matrix-rows-and-columns/3085)

Answer (score 5):

In versions 13.1+ you can wrap `v1` with [`Threaded`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Threaded.html):

```
Threaded[v1] + v2
```

> ```
> {{a + d, b + e, c + f}, {a + g, b + h, c + i}, {a + j, b + k, c + l}}
> ```

Comment: Interesting new command!

Answer (score 4):

```
Total[Tuples[{{v1}, v2}], {2}]
```

> ```
>  {{a + d, b + e, c + f}, {a + g, b + h, c + i}, {a + j, b + k, c + l}}
> ```

```
Distribute[{{v1}, v2}, List, List, List, Plus]
```

> ```
>  {{a + d, b + e, c + f}, {a + g, b + h, c + i}, {a + j, b + k, c + l}}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

In versions 13.1+ you can use `ReplaceAt`:

```
ReplaceAt[{v2}, _ -> Map[#1 + v1 &], 0]

(*{{a + d, b + e, c + f}, {a + g, b + h, c + i}, {a + j, b + k, c + l}}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here was my first thought...

```
ConstantArray[v1, 3] + v2
```

or more generally

```
ConstantArray[v1, Length[v2]] + v2
```