# ListPlot problem

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have the following example:

```
x = {1, 2, 3, 4}
y = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 4, 5}, {3, 4, 5, 6}, {4, 5, 6, 7}}
```

Now I can plot:

```
ListPlot[{Transpose[{x, y[[1]]}], Transpose[{x, y[[2]]}], 
  Transpose[{x, y[[3]]}], Transpose[{x, y[[4]]}]}]
```

[image]

How can this be simplified?

Comment: Have you tried `Map` to avoid typing the same thing four times??

Comment: `Map[(Transpose[{x, #}]) &, y]` ?

Comment: Yes, or just `Transpose[{x,#}]& /@ y` if you find that more readable.

Comment: With your `x` use the default: `ListPlot[y]`

Comment: @Bob Hanson: For my analysis in general x is not a list of of consecutive integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to simplify generating the input these are simpler ways:

```
x = Range[4];
y = Partition[ Range[7], 4, 1];
```

then you can use `Inner`:

```
z = Inner[List, x, y, List];
```

and finally

```
ListPlot[z]
```

Instead of playing with `Partition` and `Range` you can generate the input of `ListPlot`  with `Table`:

```
z = Table[{i, i + k - 1}, {k, 4}, {i, 4}];
```

or even better with `Array`:

```
z = Array[{#2, #2 + #1 - 1} &, {4, 4}]
```

The simplest approach would make use of the Front - end shorthands for `Transpose` (`esc tr esc`)   (see e.g. [Add a vector to a list of vectors](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95033/add-a-vector-to-a-list-of-vectors/95038#95038)) and `Map` (`/@`)  e.g.

[image]