# Multiplying a list a vectors by the same matrix

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of 2 vectors: `x={{a,b},{x,y}}`, and a matrix 2 by 2 `A`.

I want the result to be `{A.{a,b},A.{x,y}}`.

I thought we could do `A.x`, but it doesn't work. Also, I've tried something with apply or applythread but no sucess...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How about `Transpose[A . Transpose[x]]`

Comment: Change `x={{a,b},{x,y}}` to `xx={{a,b},{x,y}}` and `A.#&/@xx` works.

Comment: A more general perspective can be seen comparing a suggestion by @CarlWoll with this answer [Add a vector to a list of vectors](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95033/add-a-vector-to-a-list-of-vectors/95038#95038). One can just change `Dot` or `Plus` to any two-argument action.

Comment: @Artes Thanks for the extra info which is very useful right now!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are working with large matrices, then matrix dot products are almost certainly the best approach if you are interested in speed. For example, suppose you have a 200 x 200 matrix, and 100 vectors:

```
A = RandomReal[1, {200, 200}];
v = RandomReal[1, {100, 200}];
```

Let's compare a few methods:

```
r1 = Transpose[A . Transpose[v]]; //AbsoluteTiming
r2 = A . #& /@ v; //AbsoluteTiming
r3 = Inner[Times, A, #]& /@ v; //AbsoluteTiming

r1 == r2 == r3
```

> {0.000335, Null}
>
> {0.007227, Null}
>
> {29.0056, Null}

True

Clearly, using [`Inner`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inner) instead of [`Dot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot) for large matrices is much slower. Now, for even larger matrices:

```
A = RandomReal[1, {2000, 2000}];
v = RandomReal[1, {100, 2000}];

r1 = Transpose[A . Transpose[v]]; //AbsoluteTiming
r2 = A . #& /@ v; //AbsoluteTiming

r1 == r2
```

> {0.007186, Null}
>
> {0.356008, Null}
>
> True

Matrix multiplication using [`Dot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot) is heavily optimized.

Comment: Thanks Carl! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
x = {{a, b}, {c, d}} ;
mat = RandomInteger[{1, 5}, {2, 2}];


Inner[Times, mat, #] & /@ x // Transpose
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Using `Fold`:

```
A = Array[Subscript[b, ##] &, {2, 2}];
X = {{a, b}, {x, y}};
Fold[Dot[#1, Transpose@#2] &, X, {A}] === {A . {a, b}, A . {x, y}}
(*True*)
```

To prevent matrix multiplication if the dimensions are not proper (as pointed out Syed), you can build your own dot product as follows:

```
MyDot[A_?MatrixQ, vecs_?MatrixQ] /; SameQ[Last@Dimensions[A], 
Mean@(Length[#] & /@ vecs)] := 
Fold[Dot[#1, Transpose@#2] &, vecs, {A}]
```

Test 1:

```
MyDot[A, X] === {A . {a, b}, A . {x, y}}
(*True*)
```

Test 2:

```
X2 = {{a, b, c}, {x, y}};
MyDot[A, X2]
(*MyDot[{{Subscript[b, 1, 1], Subscript[b, 1, 2]}, {Subscript[b, 2, 1], Subscript[b, 2, 2]}}, {{a, b, c}, {x, y}}]*)
```

Answer (score -1):

If m is a 2X2 matrix and v is a list of 2D vectors of length n
`Table[m.v[[i]],{i,1,n}]` is a list of the new vectors.

Comment: `n` cannot be arbitrary as it would prevent matrix multiplication if the dimensions are not proper.

Comment: you misinterpreted my answer. n is the number of vectors in the list .