# Subtracting a list from each sublist in a nested list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a nested list with 1-D sublists of equal length. I want to subtract another list from each of these sublists.

**Task:** Subtracting `B` from each element in `A` to get the result `C`.

```
A = {{5,3,5,7,2},{2,6,4,8,3}}

B = {1,2,1,2,1}

C = {{4,1,4,5,1},{1,4,3,6,2}}
```

I've used multiple tables to perform this. However, the code takes too long, especially for many nests (columns)*. Is there a faster way?

---

*In my case, I have many nests as it is time series data. Each nest represents a new column.

Comment: Yes! Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
c = Map[Subtract[#, B]&] @ A (* or *)

c =  # - B & /@ A
```

> {{4, 1, 4, 5, 1}, {1, 4, 3, 6, 2}}

Also

```
A - ConstantArray[B, Length @ A]
```

> {{4, 1, 4, 5, 1}, {1, 4, 3, 6, 2}}

**Note:** [`C`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/C.html) is a protected system symbol.

Answer (score 6):

In versions 13.1+, you can use `Threaded`:

```
A - Threaded[B]
```

> ```
> {{4, 1, 4, 5, 1}, {1, 4, 3, 6, 2}}
> ```

[`Threaded`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Threaded.html):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Using `Inner`:**

```
A = {{5, 3, 5, 7, 2}, {2, 6, 4, 8, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}
B = {1, 2, 1, 2, 1}

Inner[Subtract, A, B, List]
```

> {{4, 1, 4, 5, 1}, {1, 4, 3, 6, 2}, {0, 0, 2, 2, 4}}

Comment: (+1) Also `A-{B,B}`?

Comment: Works for the case in the OP. The hidden magic number is the number of times you have to write `B` though.

Comment: Maybe, but if `A` is large and speed is a consideration, `Inner` will [be slow](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/153117/106)? `Transpose[Transpose[A]-B]`, for example, should be faster?  (but +1 anyway!)

Answer (score 3):

If matrix `A` is large and speed is a consideration, another possibility is to use a double `Transpose`

(See [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/95038/106) by [Artes](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/184/artes) to the question [Add a vector to a list of vectors](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95033/add-a-vector-to-a-list-of-vectors/95038#95038))

```
A
B
Transpose[Transpose[A]-B]

(* 
{{5, 3, 5, 7, 2}, {2, 6, 4, 8, 3}}
{1, 2, 1, 2, 1}
{{4, 1, 4, 5, 1}, {1, 4, 3, 6, 2}}
*)
```

And

```
lstC={{5, 3, 5, 7, 2}, {2, 6, 4, 8, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1,10,100,1000,100000}};
lstC
B
Transpose[Transpose[lstC]-B]

(*
{{5, 3, 5, 7, 2}, {2, 6, 4, 8, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 10, 100, 1000, 100000}}
{1, 2, 1, 2, 1}
{{4, 1, 4, 5, 1}, {1, 4, 3, 6, 2}, {0, 0, 2, 2, 4}, {0, 8, 99, 998, 99999}}
*)
```

**Transpose Entry Shortcut**

Artes has also [pointed out](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/95038/106) that `Transpose` may be entered "very concisely in the Front-End" as `Esc tr Esc`

Answer (score 1):

Using `Nest` with the @kglr's idea:

```
Nest[Map[Subtract[#, B] &], A, 1]

(*{{4, 1, 4, 5, 1}, {1, 4, 3, 6, 2}}*)
```

Or using `FixedPoint` with the @kglr's idea:

```
FixedPoint[Map[Subtract[#, B] &], A, 1]

(*{{4, 1, 4, 5, 1}, {1, 4, 3, 6, 2}}*)
```

Or using `ReplaceAt` with the @kglr's idea:

```
ReplaceAt[{A}, _ -> Map[#1 - B &], 0]

(*{{4, 1, 4, 5, 1}, {1, 4, 3, 6, 2}}*)
```