# How can I multiply only a few columns of a table by some number in a compact way?

Tags: list-manipulation

Consider a table

```
tab = Table[{i,i^2,i^3,i^5,i^0.3,i^0.7},{i,0.2,3,0.1}];
```

I would like to multiply the 2rd and 5rd columns by some number. This is how I do it:

```
a = 2
{#[[1]],a*#[[2]],#[[3]],#[[4]],a*#[[5]],#[[6]]}&/@tab
```

However, such syntax becomes really annoying if the table would have many columns:

```
{...,a*#[[K]],...,a*#[[M]],...}&/@tab
```

where K,M are some numbers. How can I multiply the columns in a more compact way? I.e., what is an analog of ... in Mathematica?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The simplest method I can think off, is with `Query`:

```
Query[All, Thread[{2, 5} -> Function[a * #]]] @ tab
```

Comment: (+1, days ago!) It appears that in this case Query 'compiles' into a right-composition of the operator form of MapAt:  `Query[All, Thread[{2,5} -> Function[a * #]]]//Normal` (* **MapAt[a*#1 & , {All, 5}] /* MapAt[a*#1 & , {All, 2}]** *)

Answer (score 19):

Another option could be

```
a*tab[[All, {2, 5}]]
```

Which will multiply columns 2 and 5 by `a`. To replace the original matrix just do

```
tab[[All, {2, 5}]] = a*tab[[All, {2, 5}]];
```

Comment: also: `tab[[All, {2, 5}]] *= a`

Comment: easy for biginners

Answer (score 11):

Using the `Dot` product:

```
tab.DiagonalMatrix[{1,2,1,1,2,1}]
```

Or, if there are a lot of columns:

**Edit**

[Lucas Lang](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/36508/lukas-lang) suggested a neat modification, such as the following, to the original `SparseArray` answer (and thanks!):

```
tab.DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[Thread[{2,5}->2], {6},1]]
```

**Original answer**

```
tab.SparseArray[{{2,2}->2, {5,5}-> 2,Band[{1, 1}] -> 1}, {6,6}]
```

With `Inner`:

```
Inner[Times, tab, {1,2,1,1,2,1}, List]
```

In addition, if the table consists of only two columns (a table of {x,y} values, maybe) and if it is desired to multiply all y-values by 2:

```
table.{{1,0},{0,2}}
```

For example:

```
tab[[All,;;2]].{{1,0},{0,2}}
```

**Modify in place using [ApplyTo](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ApplyTo.html) (//=)**

(modify `tab`, not a copy)

```
tab[[All,{2,5}]]//= 2#&
```

or using the [new](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html) function syntax:

```
tab[[;;,{2,5}]]//=(x |-> 2 x)
```

**Edit 2: `ReplaceAt`**

Since v13.1,[`ReplaceAt`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAt.html) may be used:

```
result = ReplaceAt[tab,x_ :> 2 x, {All,{2,5}}];

result == tab.DiagonalMatrix[{1,2,1,1,2,1}]

(* True *)
```

**Edit 3:  `Threaded`**

As [kglr](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/125/kglr) has taught us (see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/283539/106) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/283560/106)), an even more convenient method is arguably with  [`Threaded`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Threaded.html)

```
want = tab.DiagonalMatrix[{1,2,1,1,2,1}];

tab Threaded[{1,2,1,1,2,1}] == want

tab Threaded[SparseArray[Thread[{2,5}->2],6,1]] == want

(* True *)
(* True *)
```

A further example:

```
myTable = Array[Subscript[a, Row[{##}]] &, {3, 6}];
myTable//TeXForm
```

$$ 
\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{14} & a_{15} & a_{16} \\
 a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24} & a_{25} & a_{26} \\
 a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} & a_{34} & a_{35} & a_{36} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

```
myTable Threaded[SparseArray[Thread[{2,5}->2],Dimensions@myTable[[2]],1]]
```

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 a_{11} & 2 a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{14} & 2 a_{15} & a_{16} \\
 a_{21} & 2 a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24} & 2 a_{25} & a_{26} \\
 a_{31} & 2 a_{32} & a_{33} & a_{34} & 2 a_{35} & a_{36} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

```
myTable Threaded[SparseArray[{2->2,3->10,6->100},Dimensions@myTable[[2]],1]]
```

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 a_{11} & 2 a_{12} & 10 a_{13} & a_{14} & a_{15} & 100 a_{16} \\
 a_{21} & 2 a_{22} & 10 a_{23} & a_{24} & a_{25} & 100 a_{26} \\
 a_{31} & 2 a_{32} & 10 a_{33} & a_{34} & a_{35} & 100 a_{36} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Comment: You could also use a 1D `SparseArray` with default value `1`, and then use `DiagonalMatrix` to convert it. That way you can avoid the 2D specifications and the need for `Band`

Answer (score 5):

```
a = 2; k = 2; m = 5;
```

**Using direct multiplication:**

```
v = ReplacePart[ConstantArray[1, Last@Dimensions@tab], 
  List /@ {k, m} -> a]
```

> {1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1}

```
v tab[[#]] & /@ Range[Length@tab] // TableForm
```

**Using `MapAt`:**

```
MapAt[Times[a #] &, tab, {All, #} & /@ {k, m}] // TableForm
```

**Using `SubsetMap`:**

```
SubsetMap[Times[a #] &, tab[[#]], {k, m}] & /@ 
  Range[Length@tab] // TableForm
```

Answer (score 1):

```
MapAt[a*#&,tab,{{All,2},{All,5}}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Building a `MultiplyByPosition` function:

```
MultiplyByPosition[array_?VectorQ, factor_, positions : {___Integer}] := 
ReplacePart[array, Thread[Rule[Nest[Map[List, #] &, positions, 2], 
Flatten[factor*Extract[array, Nest[Map[List, #] &, positions, 2]]]]]]

MultiplyByPosition[array_?TensorQ, factor_, positions : {___Integer}] := 
Map[MultiplyByPosition[#, factor, positions] &, array]
```

Testing `MultiplyByPosition`:

```
MultiplyByPosition[tab, a, {2, 5}]===Query[All, Thread[{2, 5} -> Function[a*#]]]@tab

(*True*)
```

Another way using `ReplaceAt` and `SubsetMap`:

```
Transpose@ReplaceAt[{Transpose@tab}, _ -> SubsetMap[a*# &, {2, 5}], 0]
```

[image]