# Can I use == to compare two list element wise?

Tags: list-manipulation, operators

I have the following lists `Y` and `EY` with actual and estimated outcomes.

```
Y = {-1., -1., 1., -1., -1., -1., 1., 1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., \
-1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., 1., 1., -1., -1., -1., -1., 1., -1., \
1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., 1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., \
-1., -1., -1., -1., 1., -1., -1., 1., 1., -1., 1., 1., 1., -1., 1., \
-1., 1., -1., -1., -1., -1., 1., -1., 1., -1., -1., -1., 1., -1., \
-1., -1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., -1., 1., -1., 1., -1., -1., 1., 1., \
-1., -1., 1., 1., -1., -1., 1., 1., 1., -1., -1., -1., 1., -1., 1., \
-1., -1., 1., 1., 1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., \
-1., -1., 1., -1., 1., 1., -1., 1., -1., 1., -1., -1., 1., -1., -1., \
-1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.}

EY = {-1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., 1., 1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., \
-1., -1., -1., -1., -1., 1., 1., 1., -1., -1., -1., -1., 1., -1., 1., \
-1., -1., -1., -1., -1., 1., 1., 1., -1., -1., -1., -1., 1., -1., 1., \
-1., 1., -1., 1., -1., -1., 1., -1., 1., 1., 1., -1., 1., -1., 1., \
1., -1., -1., -1., 1., 1., 1., 1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., 1., \
1., 1., 1., -1., -1., 1., -1., 1., 1., -1., 1., 1., -1., 1., 1., 1., \
-1., -1., 1., 1., 1., -1., -1., 1., 1., -1., 1., -1., -1., 1., 1., \
-1., -1., -1., 1., -1., -1., 1., 1., 1., -1., -1., -1., 1., -1., 1., \
1., -1., 1., -1., 1., -1., -1., 1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., 1., \
1., -1.}
```

I want to calculate the recall metric. To do so I intuitively try this (for the shake of simplicity it is not the actual recall formula, just its numerator to make the question easier to follow):

```
recall = (Count[Y == 1.0 && EY == 1.0, True])
0
```

But when I do this, I can get the actual count:

```
Count[Thread[Thread[Y == 1.0] && Thread[EY == 1.0]], True]
38
```

Why the first expression is not applying `==` to each element?

Comment: `==` is the short form for `Equal`. `Equal` does not have the attribute `Listable` as seen from `Attributes[Equal]`. To see what the attribute listable means compare the outputs from the following two examples:

Comment: `Array[a, 4]~Function[{a, b}, a == b]~Array[b, 4]`

Comment: `Array[a, 4]~Function[{a, b}, a == b, Listable]~Array[b, 4]`

Comment: I would discourage equality checking on floating-point numbers because it can be quite brittle in practice. From [the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Equal.html), "Approximate numbers with machine precision or higher are considered equal if they differ in at most their last seven binary digits (roughly their last two decimal digits)." So there is some room for numerical error, but not much. Better to round your numbers to the nearest integer before testing, or testing with a larger error range.

Answer (score 9):

You could create a listable version of Equal:

```
ClearAll[listEqual]
SetAttributes[listEqual, Listable]
listEqual[seq__] := Equal[seq]

listEqual[{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 4}]
(* Out: {True, True, False} *)
```

This could also be used inline with the same results:

```
{1, 2, 3} ~ listEqual ~ {1, 2, 4}
```

With that in hand:

```
Thread[Y ~ listEqual ~ 1.0 && EY ~ listEqual ~ 1.0];
Count[%, True]

(* Out: 38 *)
```

Comment: Sometimes I've done things like this `listEqual = Function[, Equal[##], Listable]`.

Answer (score 7):

Here is the way to fix origin code:

```
recall1 = Y // Map[EqualTo[1.0]]
recall2 = EY // Map[EqualTo[1.0]]
{recall1, recall2} // MapThread[And] // Count[True]
```

> 38

Answer (score 7):

Another simple solution could be:

```
Count[Transpose[{Y, EY}], {1., 1.}]

(* Out: 38 *)
```

Since we are matching patterns, applying `N` to data is recommended, if you're not sure they are `Real` or `Integer`.

Comment: Or `Counts[Transpose[{Y, EY}]]` to get all combinations as an [association](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html): `<|{-1., -1.} -> 74, {1., -1.} -> 6, {1., 1.} -> 38, {-1., 1.} -> 19|>`

Answer (score 7):

**(1)  Ramp and Dot**

How about using `Ramp` and the `Dot` product?

```
Ramp[Y].Ramp[EY]
(* 38. *)
```

(I have interpreted the question as @Ben Izd and @Syed have done)

**(2) MapThread**

```
Count[MapThread[##==1.0&,{Y,EY}],True]
(* 38 *)
```

(The above method is almost identical to that given [below](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/277835/106) by @lericr, **which was posted well before this answer**)

**(3) Thread**

From the documentation for [Thread](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread.html), under "possible issues", it is pointed out that "`Thread` evaluates the whole expression before threading" but that `MapThread` "takes the function and its arguments separately".

It is also pointed out that suppressing evaluation can make `Thread` behave like `MapThread`.

```
Thread[Unevaluated[##==1.0]]&[Y,EY]//Count[True]
(* 38 *)
```

**(4) Count**

```
Count[2.][Y+EY]
(* 38 *)
```

**(5) Inner**

```
Inner[##==1.&,Y,EY,Count[True]@*List]
(* 38 *)
```

This is likely to be much slower than the `Dot` product method as "Matrix multiplication using `Dot` is heavily optimized" (see [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/153117/106) by Carl Woll)

There is also:

```
 Inner[Times, Ramp@Y, Ramp@EY]
 (* 38. *)
```

Answer (score 6):

This expression,

```
Y == 1.0 && EY == 1.0
```

Is applying And to two expressions that aren't True/False. Look at what you get if you evaluate `Y == 1.0`. And is a logical operator, so it won't resolve if the the values aren't True/False (in general).

You might try something like this:

```
Count[MapThread[#1 == #2 == 1.0 &, {Y, EY}], True]
```

Or this:

```
Count[Pick[Y, EY, 1.], 1.]
```

Or maybe even this:

```
Tally[Pick[Y, EY, 1.]]
```

Comment: == is not Listable, so `Y==1.0` just keep the form.

Answer (score 4):

As @Roman pointed out, the data are floats and a float-appropriate solution should be used (unless it is guaranteed that the data are integer floats, but this is not a condition stated in the problem).

```
Total[1 - Unitize[Threshold@Abs[ey - 1] + Threshold@Abs[y - 1]]]
(*  38  *)
```

From a comment by the OP:

> The intended calculation is the numerator of the Recall metric, which focuses on how many positives the system detects out of the total number of actual positives...

Then use (if I interpreted the implication on the data correctly):

```
Total[UnitStep[EY] UnitStep[Y]]
(*  38  *)
```

Answer (score 3):

**Using `Position`:**

```
Position[Y, 1.0] ⋂ Position[EY, 1.0] // Length
```

---

Other variants:

```
Thread[(# == 1.0 & /@ Y) && (# == 1.0 & /@ EY)] // Count[True]

Count[AllTrue[#, EqualTo[1.0]] & /@ Transpose[{Y, EY}], True]
```

---

Result

> 38