# Add list of vectors to list of vectors recursively

Tags: list-manipulation, recursion, trees

This question relates to [Add a vector to a list of vectors](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95033/add-a-vector-to-a-list-of-vectors) whereas here I want to add list of vectors to list of vectors recursively.
Given:

```
m = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {-1, 0}, {0, -1}}
k = m
```

Adding each vector of m to each vector of k is done by

```
k = Transpose[# + Transpose[m]] & /@ k
```

resulting in

```
     {{{2, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 0}, {1, -1}}, {{1, 1}, {0, 2}, {-1, 1}, {0,0}}, {{0, 0}, {-1, 1}, {-2, 0}, {-1, -1}}, {{1, -1}, {0,0}, {-1, -1}, {0, -2}}}
```

This is my new k and should go back into my code, so I can add the vectors `m` to each element of this new k. The new result starts with {{{{3,0},{2,1},{1,0),{2,-1}}...  I tried

```
Table[k = (Transpose[# + Transpose[m]] & /@ k), {i, 2}]
```

But it does not work and then I get too confused. Any idea for this tree-like structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with `Nest` and `Outer`. If you need intermediate results, you would use `NestList`:

```
n = 1; (*number of recursions*)
m = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {-1, 0}, {0, -1}};
Nest[Flatten[Outer[Plus, #, m, 1], 1] &, m, n]
```

[image]

An for n=2:

[image]