# Recursive addition of vector list to last elements of vector lists

Tags: list-manipulation, map

This question refers to an extension of [Add list of vectors to list of vectors recursively](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/243758/add-list-of-vectors-to-list-of-vectors-recursively) . I tried hard to complete the problem but now I got stuck. I have vectors

```
lis0 = {u, v}
m = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {-1, 0}, {0, -1}};
```

Adding each component of `m` to `lis0` gives me

```
lis1={{{u, v}, {1 + u, v}}, {{u, v}, {u, 1 + v}}, {{u, v}, {-1 + u, v}}, {{u, v}, {u, -1 + v}}}
```

Now I want to add each vector of `m` to each last component of `lis1` resulting in 16 sublists

```
lis2={{{{u, v}, {1 + u, v}, {2 + u, v}}, {{u, v}, {1 + u, v}, {1 + u, 1 + v}},{{u, v}, {1 + u, v}, {u, v}}...
```

So now I want to continue adding `m` to each last element in `lis2` and so on. Lists will grow exponentially in size. Here is my code so far:

```
lis1 = {u, v} + # & /@ m;
lis1 = List[lis0, #] & /@ lis1

x2 = Map[Function[z, z + # & /@ m], Last /@ lis1]
```

here `x2` is part of next `lis2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems a case for recursive programming. Call `n` then number of additions:

```
n = 2;
add[dat_] := Module[{},
  If [Length[Flatten[dat]] >= 8 n + 1, Return[dat]];
  Switch[dat
   , {{u, v}, ___}, add[ Append[dat, Last[dat] + #] & /@ m ]
   , {__}, add /@ dat
   ] ]
res = add[{{u, v}}]
```

[image]

**Explanation**:

1. First check if we already reached the end (recursion stop).
2. If we have {{u,v},...}, we need to create 4 new lists, each with an element of m added to the original list.
3. If the structure of data is not {{u,v},..} we need to dig deeper, that is we need to apply `add` to the sub lists.

Comment: Wow! Great! I yet don't understand your code.It will give me a long time to chew. Thanks for your effort!

Comment: Hi, I added an explanation to the answer.