# How to add a vector list to a multiple dimension list of vectors

Tags: list-manipulation, vector

This problem is related to [Add a vector to a list of vectors](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95033/add-a-vector-to-a-list-of-vectors).
Given:

```
v1 = {{1,0},{0,1},{-1,0},{0,-1}}
v2 = {{{u, v}, {1 + u, v}}, {{u, v}, {u, 1 + v}}, {{u, v}, {-1 + u, v}}, {{u,v}, {u, -1 + v}}};
```

I want to add each part of `v1` to all last parts of subvectors of `v2`, so I would get a list with 4 x 4 parts starting with

```
{{{{u, v}, {1 + u, v},{2 + u, v}}, {{u, v}, {1 + u, v},{1 + u, 1 + v}}... }...{{{...   }}}}
```

Comment: The rules of this operation are unclear to me: can you explain?

Comment: why not `Map[v1 + # &]@v2`?

Comment: Oop just saw what you posted after I had written my answer @kglr, but chances are OP wants something more intricate & the solution may not work in a general use case.

Comment: Ah I see now the solutions listed at the linked post work with OP’s example too. Did you check those? What was wrong with them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add a vector to a list of vectors](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95033/add-a-vector-to-a-list-of-vectors)

Comment: Well, yes, but I try to rephrase my question better. I'll be back.

Comment: Ah, I will try to come up with a solution to your real requirements you have edited in recently. This stands to be a completely different question than before, just fyi. To clarify, you are to change the dimensions completely of v2 when you add in v1?

Comment: Updated with new answer.

Comment: Yes, you are that I change the dimesnion of v1. I wanted to keep the question simple and thought I could do the rest by myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrapping the current solution into a function can easily be done:

```
v3[v1_,v2_]:=Table[{#[[ ;; ]]~Join~#[[{-1}]]} & /@ v2// #[[j]] & // Table[{#[[;; -2]]~Join~{v1[[i]] + #[[-1]]}} & @@ #, {i, Length@v1}] &, {j, Length@v2}] // Flatten[#, 1] & /@ # &
```

And you would apply it like so:

```
v3[v1new,#]&/@v3[v1new,v2new];
%//Dimensions
```

> ```
> {4,4,4,4,2}
> ```

To apply it yet again:

```
v3[v1new,#]&/@#&/@(v3[v1new,#]&/@v3[v1new,v2new]);
%//Dimensions
```

> ```
> {4,4,4,4,5,2}
> ```

And again:

```
v3[v1new,#]&/@#&/@#&/@(v3[v1new,#]&/@#&/@(v3[v1new,#]&/@v3[v1new,v2new]));
%//Dimensions
```

> ```
> {4,4,4,4,4,6,2}
> ```

Given the new definitions:

```
v1new = {{1,0},{0,1},{-1,0},{0,-1}};
v2new = {{{u, v}, {1 + u, v}}, {{u, v}, {u, 1 + v}}, {{u, v}, {-1 + u, v}}, {{u,v}, {u, -1 + v}}};
```

This can likely be cleaned up, and I’ll consider how a bit later, but this *seems* do what you want:

```
Table[{#[[ ;; ]]~Join~#[[{-1}]]} & /@ v2new // #[[j]] & // Table[{#[[;; -2]]~Join~{v1new[[i]] + #[[-1]]}} & @@ #, {i, Length@v1new}] &, {j, Length@v2new}] // Flatten[#, 1] & /@ # &
```

> ```
> {{{{u, v}, {1 + u, v}, {2 + u, v}}, {{u, v}, {1 + u, v}, {1 + u, 1 + v}}, {{u, v}, {1 + u, v}, {u, v}}, {{u, v}, {1 + u, v}, {1 + u, -1 + v}}}, {{{u, v}, {u, 1 + v}, {1 + u, 1 + v}}, {{u, v}, {u, 1 + v}, {u, 2 + v}}, {{u, v}, {u, 1 + v}, {-1 + u, 1 + v}}, {{u, v}, {u, 1 + v}, {u, v}}}, {{{u, v}, {-1 + u, v}, {u, v}}, {{u, v}, {-1 + u, v}, {-1 + u, 1 + v}}, {{u, v}, {-1 + u, v}, {-2 + u, v}}, {{u, v}, {-1 + u, v}, {-1 + u, -1 + v}}}, {{{u, v}, {u, -1 + v}, {1 + u, -1 + v}}, {{u, v}, {u, -1 + v}, {u, v}}, {{u, v}, {u, -1 + v}, {-1 + u, -1 + v}}, {{u, v}, {u, -1 + v}, {u, -2 + v}}}}
> ```

Old answer with the initial definitions given:

```
v1 = {a, b};
v2 = {{{d, e}, {{g, h}, {r, s}}}, {j, k}};
```

This seems to do what you want:

```
v1+#&/@v2
```

> ```
> {{{a+d,a+e},{{b+g,b+h},{b+r,b+s}}},{a+j,b+k}}
> ```

Comment: Yes, that's the right solution. Great! But I will need some time to analyze it. But I also look for a solution which enables me to to reiterate it. That is, I want to use your solution and set it as v2new and apply v1new again and again.Later I will try to put bounderies on all values. But that would be the next next after I understood all the other parts.

Comment: @user57467 this can easily be wrapped up into a function, but just so I understand, if you apply the same operation again & again, won’t you continue to increase the dimensions again & again? What is your expected result?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Dimensions will increase exponentially. But later I want to put restraints after each step. I will delete negative values and also values greater than a certain value.  This will limit the amount of memory but not not the depth of dimension.

Comment: @user57467 please see the updates, I think this is what you are going for? If not, please, let me know what is not as intended?

Comment: Yes! Great! Though I still do not understand your code completely, how would you reiterate? So what would be the general solution for n dimensions without writing a new command for each step? If it makes easier for you to check results just set u=0 and v=0.

Comment: I think that’s a bit outside the scope of this question...I show how to reiterate the application of the function. I believe that finding a general solution should either be up to you, or if you have some failings, another question may be asked...it almost seems as though that would be a question best left for mathematics SE, rather than here.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your effort! I will keep struggling.

Comment: @user57467 to be clear, if you want your new question to be answered, you should ask a new question. I think that your question here has been answered...